# Quais são as definições de método, função e procedimento?

Tags: funções, terminologia, método, procedure

Eu sempre achei que as definições fossem essas, mas parece que estou errado:

- **funções:** todo procedimento que retorna algo
- **métodos:** todo procedimento que não retorna nada
- **procedimento:** seria a base de classificação dos anteriores, algo que executa instruções, seja com intuito ou não de retornar

Gostaria de saber se essas definições são as corretas, e se não forem, ou se forem parcialmente, em que contextos ocorreriam essas variações.

Obviamente, só me interessam definições que existem no mundo da programação... no máximo indo um pouco pro lado da matemática.

Comment: Não votei para fechar mas essa pergunta parece baseada em opinões, algumas linguagues fazem como `pascal` fazem diferenciação em entre função(retorna algo) e procedimento(que não retorna nada), outras tanto faz e algumas entendem que a ultima instrução de uma função/procedimento é o retorno. Geralmente método está associado a orientação a objeto.

Comment: Baseadas em opiniões de quem? Dos criadores das linguagens... por mim pode ser, são essas que eu quero: as definições oficiais.

Comment: Ainda que essas definições variem de linguagem para linguagem, isso não significa que sejam opiniões.

Comment: Não é baseada em opiniões. Os conceitos existem e são devidamente postulados.

Comment: Estive pesquisando um pouco, e acabei encontrando mais um termo: *subprocedimento*. Eu bem que me lembro que no VB6 tinha `SUB`/`END SUB`, deve ser isso.

Comment: `Sub` é o equivalente de `Procedure`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- **Procedimento**: Parte de um programa ou classe que não retorna um valor (da definição de Delphi/Pascal). No Visual Basic/VB.NET, também é conhecimento como `Subroutine` (Subrotina, ou simplesmente `Sub`);
- **Função**: Parte de um programa ou classe que retorna um valor (da definição de Delphi/Pascal/Visual Basic/Visual Basic .NET);
- **Método**: Procedimento ou função pertencente a uma classe (várias linguagens de programação definem desta forma, por exemplo, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java), etc.).

Há uma questão no [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20909/method-vs-function-vs-procedure) em que isso é largamente debatido, mas o consensual é isso.

Comment: Eu entendi a resposta mas ficou engraçado. Procedimento e função são métodos e método é um procedimento ou função.

Comment: É mesmo. Deixa eu ver se melhoro isso.

Comment: Mas no VB o `Sub` não tem retorno. Então o `Sub` acho que se encaixaria com a definição de procedimento. No VB lembro que tem `Function` e `Sub`.

Comment: Editei de novo. Se eu lembrar de mais algum caso, vou melhorando a resposta, mas acho que é isso aí.

Answer (score 19):

A [definição de *método* da wikipédia em Inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29) diz que é um *procedimento* associado a um objeto, podendo também ser chamado de ***função membro***. Métodos estáticos seriam os associados a uma classe.

Muitas vezes os termos *função*, *método*, *procedimento*, *rotina* e *subrotina* são usados de forma intercambiável para se referir à mesma coisa, mas existem algumas nuances.

**Não vejo diferença entre *procedimento*, *rotina* e *subrotina***. São sinônimos de uma sequência de instruções específica de um programa, que pode ser invocada a partir de outros locais.

Já uma ***função*** remete a algo que retorna um valor, de forma análoga à matemática. Seria um conjunto de instruções que retorna um valor ao final. Uma função é um procedimento, mas com esse detalhe do retorno a mais.

Um ***método*** pode ser um *procedimento* ou *função*, mas associado a um objeto ou classe. Por isso pode ser chamado de "função membro".

### Exemplos práticos

Procedimentos são usados em linguagens como SQL (T-SQL, PL/SQL, etc.) para rotinas que não retornam valor. Já funções são usadas para rotinas que retornam valores. O mesmo vale para o Visual Basic.

Várias linguagens que possuem funções de primeira classe, como Javascript, possuem a declaração de funções com a palavra reservada `function`.

Já linguagens orientada a objetos como Java ou C# sempre usam o termo *método* para se referir aos procedimentos associados a classes.

Em PHP, que é orientada a objetos e funcional, o termo *função* é usado para se referir às rotinas chamadas diretamente no código, enquanto o termo *método* é reservado para a parte de orientação a objetos, que nada mais são do que funções dentro de classes. O PHP não faz diferença entre função que retorna valor ou não.

### Conclusão

Embora não tenha citado referências fortes de autores, julgo que o conteúdo da Wikipédia está coerente e as definições fazem sentido de forma geral em todas as plataformas que conheço.

Comment: No javascript então, um método seria uma função que está associada a uma de suas propriedades?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo No JavaScript, "método" é uma função que pertence a um objeto (como propriedade).

Answer (score 3):

Para se conceituar função, metodo e procedimento, se deve levar em consideração a base da programação que é o estudo do algorítimo:

Em algorítimo as funções (functions), também conhecidas como  sub-rotinas, sempre retornam algum valor. Um dos grandes benefícios é não precisar copiar o código todas as vezes que precisar executar aquela operação, além de deixar a leitura do código mais intuitiva. Por exemplo: Vc pode criar uma função pra calcular a raiz quadrada e retornar um valor. Sempre que precisar, a mesma função será chamada e não precisará recriar o calculo várias vezes no seu código. Vc criar apenas uma vez.

Os procedimentos (procedures) diferem das funções apenas por não retornarem resultado. Exemplo: para ler o valor digitado por um usuário nós utilizamos o procedimento LEIA e para mostrar um texto na tela nós utilizamos o procedimento ESCREVA. O primeiro apenas guarda o texto e o segundo apenas imprime na tela, não retornando valores para serem usados.

E o método, é uma função ou um procedimento?

Um método pode ser tanto uma função quanto um procedimento. Chamamos uma função ou procedimento de método na programação orientada a objetos quando estes estão associados a um objeto ou uma classe. Método é o nome que se dá a funções e procedimentos em linguagens orientadas a objetos, apenas por uma questão conceitual destas linguagens. No fundo, acabam sendo a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3):

O resumo simples é que você precisa entender bem o que é uma **função** porque é ela que você usa o tempo todo e é uma rotina estanque com um algoritmo que executa algum processamento, possivelmente em dados recebidos como parâmetros e dando um resultado que é retornado para quem a chamou.

Então é um desvio do fluxo normal da execução do código que se comunica com o resto do código através de algumas variáveis. Em geral ela tem um nome, mas há casos que isto pode não acontecer, pelo menos estritamente falando.

O **procedimento** é uma função que não retorna um valor e costuma existir como mecanismo separado apenas em algumas linguagens. A maioria das linguagens tem um procedimento como uma função normal, porém que retorna nada (pode ser um nulo ou algo um pouco diferente disto ou ser nada mesmo, não tem um valor).

O **método** é uma função com um parâmetro extra, geralmente chamado de `this` ou `self`. Algumas linguagens precisam ter esse parâmetro explicitamente e em outras a linguagem entende implicitamente. Então essa função pode ser chamada com notação de objeto, ou seja, o primeiro [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) vai antes do nome da função e não como argumento normal, portanto ele sempre estaria associado a um objeto que é passado para a função no parâmetro extra. O termo costuma ser usado na orientação a objeto para funções de uma classe.

Rotina é um termo genérico para indicar tudo isso, em geral sobre o algoritmo em si e menos sobre os contratos que a função e assemelhados têm.

Nem sempre essas nomenclaturas são usadas de forma adequada, até mesmo em documentações.

Já respondi isso em diversas respostas com mais detalhes:

- [Função e método são a mesma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212265/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) (a melhor)
- [Quando de fato preciso usar o operador this no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154186/101)
- [Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176543/101)
- [O que é programação procedural e não procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101)
- [O que caracteriza a programação imperativa e funcional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101)
- [Toda função anônima é uma closure?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/453782/101)
- [Quem é quem no uso de funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163079/101)
- [O que acontece quando chamamos uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101)
- [Como uma classe é organizada na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101)

Answer (score 1):

**Método**

É a responsabilidade uma classe. Em engenharia de software, quando se faz as responsabilidade de uma classe em um diagrama de classes, aqueles são os métodos.

**Procedimento**

É um pedaço de código (sub-rotina) sem valor de retorno.

**Função**

É um pedaço de código (sub-rotina) com valor de retorno.