# Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?

Tags: parâmetros, terminologia, argumento

Sempre utilizei os termos "parâmetro" e "argumento" como se fossem sinônimos: aquilo que é passado para uma função e/ou que a função recebe como entrada. Da mesma forma, tenho lido um e outro termo, em inglês e português, ora sendo usado um ora outro, mas não consegui perceber nenhum critério na escolha entre um e outro.

Há diferença entre eles? Ou são sinônimos mesmo? Já cheguei a pensar que "parâmetro" era o único termo correto (pois é usado na matemática) e que "argumento" era algum erro de tradução, mas depois percebi que não é o caso (em inglês também temos "*parameter*" e "*argument*"). Qual a forma correta de se usar esses termos?

Comment: Grande pergunta, sempre tenho a mesma dúvida. Não mais :)

Comment: O parâmetro é a exigência que a função empresa para o valor a ser passado como argumento (que  pode ser válido ou não) :)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[Parâmetro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) é a variável que irá receber um valor em uma função (ou método) enquanto que um argumento é o valor (que pode originar de uma variável ou expressão) que você passa para a função (ou método).

Você não passa parâmetros, você **passa argumentos**. Você recebe argumentos também, mas recebe **em parâmetros**. Você **parametriza** sua função com informações que virão posteriormente. Você **argumenta** com o que deseja executar uma função devidamente parametrizada.

Pode haver menos os mais argumentos para cada parâmetro já que existem parâmetros que são opcionais e outros que podem ser listas variáveis de dados. Portanto não há uma relação de um para um e a distinção entre eles é importante.

Frequentemente é confundido por todos e eu mesmo admito que intercambio os termos erroneamente, mas para uma boa comunicação é importante todos saberem o correto.

Achei uma [pergunta no SO com algumas respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters) sobre o assunto.

#### Exemplo

```
void Func1(int i, bool flag = true) { //declarou dois parâmetros
    // execução
}

void Func2(params int[] lista) { //declarou um parâmetro
    //execução
}

void Func3(bool x, bool y) {
    int z = 0;
    Func1(1); //chamou com 1 argumento
    Func1(z, x && y); //chamou com dois argumentos vindos de variável e expressão respectivamente
    Func2(1, 2, 3); //chamou com 3 argumentos
    Func1(flag : false, i : 2); //argumentos nomeados
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ParametersXArguments.cs).

Lembrando que todos os parâmetros são nomeados. Pelo menos é assim na maioria das linguagens. O nome da variável é o nome do parâmetro.

Em linguagens dinâmicas a falta de relação **direta** entre parâmetros e argumentos fica ainda mais evidente.

Veja um detalhe importante sobre como pegar argumentos no primeiro comentário do mgibsonbr abaixo. Existem outras linguagens que possuem recurso semelhante. É possível acessar os argumentos sem saber exatamente quais são os parâmetros.

Comment: Faz sentido: JavaScript por exemplo expõe a lista de valores usados na chamada através da variável `arguments` - que pode ter tamanho maior ou menor que o número de parâmetros declarados. E em linguagens que aceitam parâmetros opcionais e/ou parâmetros *default*, não importa como a função foi chamada, o seu corpo sempre tem acesso a uma lista fixa de variáveis (ainda que com valores nulos). Nunca tinha pensado dessa forma...

Comment: @mgibsonbr é, você tem acesso desta forma à lista de *argumentos* e não de parâmetros declarados. Em tese poderia ter acesso ao parâmetros também, mas em geral a utilidade seria limitada. Não sei em JS (provavelmente dá pela filosofia da linguagem), mas em Java e C# você consegue obter a lista de parâmetros por *reflection* (isto você sabe :) )

Comment: Isso é desnecessário em JavaScript porque não existe sobrecarga de funções, nem tipos estáticos, e qualquer função pode ser chamada com qualquer número de, aham, argumentos (já estou me acostumando... :P). O máximo que você consegue é obter o número de parâmetros formais, através da propriedade `length` ([fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4833399/520779)).

Comment: Em JavaScript o único jeito de conseguir a lista de parâmetros é obter o código-fonte da função com `toString()` e parseá-los da própria declaração (não funciona com funções *built-in*). Mas eu nunca precisei disso... @mgibsonbr

Comment: Não sei se é besteira o que estou falando: Mas então por que no `python` declaramos def `fn(**kwargs)` ao invés de `def fn(**kwparams)`????

Comment: Porque a variável `kwargs` é um parâmetro, mas o conteúdo dela é uma lista de argumentos. O nome das variáveis devem dizer o que tem nelas, não o que elas são no código.

Comment: Não tenho tanta autoridade no assunto porque não vi tantos debates sobre os termos (então se tiver referência e como refutar, estou de braços abertos), mas nos meus estudos acadêmicos eu aprendi que os valores passados na chamada da função (que aqui está sendo chamado de "argumentos") são conhecidos como os parâmetros reais e os que são definidos no cabeçalho da função/procedimento são os parâmetros formais.

Comment: Eu sei que o pessoal abstrai a ideia de parâmetros reais como "argumentos", isso é válido, assim como o pessoal abstrai a ideia de parâmetros formais somente falando que são parâmetros... eu não vejo problema nisso, mas eu discordo no fato de dizer que "Você não passa parâmetros"... porque argumentos são parâmetros reais.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura pode ser mesmo, pode ser que seja usado em âmbito acadêmico, talvez em âmbito específico, ou em outro âmbito. Nenhum local que pesquisei fala sobre isso. O que obviamente só quer dizer isso mesmo. De maneira nenhuma estou dizendo que está errado, pelo contrário, faz muito sentido, ainda que eu não goste dessa definição. Talvez possa dar uma resposta. Se tiver alguma referência que fala sobre isso ajudaria um pouco, mas nada que seja obrigatório. Eu acredito em você. Eu acho seu ultimo comentário contraditório, diz que aceita, mas não aceita... :) Se aceitar é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 57):

A função define o parâmetro, e o código de chamada passa o argumento a esse parâmetro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por analogia, podemos considerar o parâmetro como um espaço de estacionamento e o argumento como um automóvel.

Portanto ...

- **Parâmetros**

  - São definidos na declaração (ou assinatura) da função/método;
  - Os parâmetros de uma função recebem os argumentos;
  - O nome de cada parâmetro serve como uma variável local dentro da função;
  - Uma boa mnemónica é pensar que um **P**arâmetro é como um **P**laceholder para um **P**otencial valor.
- **Argumentos**

  - Representam os valores/variáveis atuais passadas para os parâmetros da função, quando é invocada;
  - Cada argumento corresponde a um parâmetro (na mesma posição);
  - Uma boa mnemónica é pensar que um **A**rgumento é o valor **A**tual.

Comment: Essas analogias são muito boas para explicar o assunto.

Comment: Show! Com a ilustração ficou melhor ainda.

Answer (score 45):

Um **parâmetro** é a *variável* que declaras na signature da função. Um **argumento** é o *valor* que passas á variável quando chamas a função. Mas esta distinção é puramente *convencional*.

Answer (score 21):

**[Parâmetros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9kewt1b3.aspx)**

Parâmetro representa um valor que o procedimento espera que você passe quando você chamá-lo. A declaração do procedimento define os seus parâmetros.

**Argumentos**

Um argumento representa o valor que você passa para um parâmetro de procedimento, quando você chama o procedimento. O código de chamada fornece os argumentos quando chama o procedimento.

Answer (score 14):

A maioria dos programadores utiliza estes termos sem distinção de significado. Na prática, falar o termo errado ou certo não fará o código funcionar ou não, isso dependerá de você, mas sempre é bom saber e entender as diferenças.

Imagine um parâmetro como **uma variável que pode ser recebida por uma função ou um método**. Para entender melhor veja esse exemplo em JavaScript:

```
function somar(param1, param2) {
   return param1 + param2;
};
```

Essa função irá sempre receber dois parâmetros (param1 e param2). Além disso a sua saída sempre dependerá necessariamente da entrada. Portanto, com essa pequena explicação já podemos concluir que o parâmetro sempre estará vinculado a sua entrada.

As regras para como os parâmetros são passados para as funções são determinados pela linguagem de programação, por exemplo, essas regras pode especificar a ordem dos parâmetros, se serão passados da esquerda para direita, ou o contrário. Além disso **as regras podem definir se os parâmetros serão passados por referência ou valor**.

*Observação: Os parâmetros podem ser de qualquer tipo, um array, um inteiro, uma String, ou outro tipo de dado (claro que isso varia nas linguagens de programação).*

Por um outro lado temos o argumento, que seria o valor passado (pode ser mais que um) a função na hora de sua chamada. Veja:

```
let valor1 = 10;
let valor2 = 20;

let valorSoma = somar(valor1, valor2);
```

Durante a execução do código acima, as variáveis "valor1" e "valor2" são **inicializadas e passadas, como argumentos** para a função `somar()`. Dentro da mesma, os parâmetros são avaliados e os argumentos '10' e '20' são obtidos. Estes valores são somados, o resultado é retornado e atribuído à variável "valorSoma ". **É importante notar que variáveis não são parâmetros e nem argumentos.**

Acredito que só com a explicação acima é possível entender a lógica e diferença parâmetros e argumentos, mas vamos ver de maneiras mais simples o que cada um pode significar.

Já ouvi definições (e que não deixam de ser verdade) de que um argumento poderia ser a instância de parâmetro, não literalmente, mas é uma analogia interessante.

Outro modo de identificar (para não esquecer mais) a diferença de cada um:

- Parâmetro -> Algo que receberá os valores quando chamar a função.
- Argumento -> Valor/objeto ou qualquer coisa que colocar dentro da chamada da função.

**Referências:**

- [Pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)
- [Diferença entre parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A2metro_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29#Par.C3.A2metro_e_Argumento)
- [Definição de parâmetro (em inglês)](https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-parameters-958124)

Answer (score 1):

Em resumo:

Parâmetro pode ser entendido como uma variável(local), um lugar, um recipiente, etc.

Por outro lado, o Argumento é o valor "atual" do Parâmetro.

EXEMPLO:

(X + Y)  EM QUE "X" E "Y" SÃO PARÂMETROS QUE RECEBERÃO OS ARGUMENTOS (1 + 2) OU (5 + 50) ETC.

Answer (score -2):

Por exemplo:

```py
def multiplicar(x, y): # Parâmetros
    return x * y

multiplicar(4, 3) # Argumentos
```