# Ler os elementos de uma struct em outra função

Tags: c, c++, funções, struct, parâmetros

Preciso acessar dados da `struct` em minha função `CalcN`, como devo proceder?

```
    int main(){

    int calcn();

    struct user1{

    string Nome;
    int Dnx;
    int Nxhu;

};

struct user1 x;

x.Dnx = 4;
x.Nxhu = 3;

int ResultadoEZ = calcn();

cout << "Resultado =  " << ResultadoEZ << endl;

}

    int calcn(){

        int Resultado;

        srand ( time (0) ) ;

        //Resultado = // x.Dnx + (rand() % 4); Dados da Struct 

        return Resultado;

    }
```

Comment: O ideal é sempre postar assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Facilita pra gente testar e achar o problema. Você não sabe isar parâmetros em funções?

Comment: só 1 minuto, vou corrigir

Comment: eu programo em Java, comecei com c++ ontem. xD

Comment: Não ajudou muito, o código que está aí não compila e é diferente do anterior que eu já tinha começado responder.

Comment: pronto, já corrigi, vou fazer umas alterações pra ficar de melhor entendimento

Comment: acho que agora deu pra entender mais ou menos né :P

é que estou programando um jogo de rpg, e preciso pegar os parâmetros de um personagem do jogador que esta no meu main e passar para outra função.

Estava tendo problemas no meu projeto em Java com este tipo de programa e resolvi passar pra c++, e agora estou na correria e nos estudos.

Comment: Pra ser bem sincero, se você estava tendo dificuldade em uma linguagem que você conhece, vai ter mais ainda em uma linguagem que não conhece e é uma das mais difíceis de dominar.

Comment: o jogo roda normalmente em Java, eu só to passando pra c++ por conta do compilador :P , e eu preciso do c++ pra algumas outras coisas também que o Java não me possibilita.
eu conheço as dificuldades do c/c++, estou com tempo livre para estudos, estou gostando bastante ate agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>O AP mudou a pergunta e colocou outro exemplo mas a base do que está feita aqui serve para a mesma coisa.</sup>
Você precisa passar o objeto com esta estrutura através de [parâmetro de função](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)).

[Leia como as funções funcionam em C++](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Então você precisa colocar um parâmetro para a função receber estes dados.

```
int CalcJnxU(User1 x) {
    int Resultado;
    srand(time(0));
    Resultado = x.hNX2 + (rand() % 4);
    return Resultado;
}
```

E depois vai chamar a função passando o dado como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32450/101).

```
User1 x;
x.Nome = "nome1"; //talvez essa variável nome1 exista em outro contexto, aí poderia mantê-la
x.NxZ = 20;
x.hNX2 = 2;
x.kJXU = 2;
CalcJnxU(x);
```

Note que o `x` da função está com o mesmo nome mas não precisaria estar. Poderia colocar o nome de variável que quiser no parâmetro. Então você está passando o valor que está em `x` no `Main()` para o `x` da função `CalcJnxU()` que são variáveis independentes, com alocações de memória diferentes. O dado será copiado de uma variável para a outra (tem como evitar essa cópia neste caso, mas não vamos complicar).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cZIzPh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eprxhqos-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/PassStruct.cpp).

Note como meu código sempre fica bem mais fácil de ler independente do que ele faz.

Depois você vai ter que aprender coisas mais avançadas. Da maneira como está codificado pode haver pequenas ineficiências. Claro que você não precisa e nem pode se preocupar com isso enquanto está aprendendo o básico. Também será útil aprender `typedef` mas deixa para depois.