# Passando vetor para funções

Tags: c, array, funções

Como faço para passar um vetor para uma função?
Algo que, em Lua, seria assim:

```
vector = {"V", "e", "t", "o", "r"}
function getVector(vector, pos)
    return vector[pos]
end
print(getVector(vector, 1))
Output: "V"
```

Tentei assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char vector[5] = {"V", "e", "t", "o", "r"};
    char getVector(char vector[], int pos) {
        return vector[pos];
    }
    printf("%c", getVector(vector, 0));
}
```

Os erros:

```
G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    In function 'main':
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] excess elements in char array initializer
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] (near initialization for 'vector')
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] excess elements in char array initializer
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] (near initialization for 'vector')
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] excess elements in char array initializer
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] (near initialization for 'vector')
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] excess elements in char array initializer
3   5   G:\PROJETOS\C\test.c    [Error] (near initialization for 'vector')
```

Comment: Deu algo errado no seu código? Da forma como está, ele deveria funcionar...

Comment: Sim, editei a perguta, estão la os erros.

Comment: hehe olhei com tanto foco pra função em si, que não prestei atenção ao código em volta... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas:

- O `Main()` precisa retornar um `int`. Alguns compiladores aceitam diferente disto mas é fora do padrão, aprenda fazer tudo no padrão.
- Uma função não pode estar dentro da outra. E a função chamada precisa estar declarada antes do seu uso. A definição dela pode estar depois mas é mais prático fazer antes (junto da declaração, assim não precisa colocar o cabeçalho dela duas vezes) em casos simples assim.
- Você declarou o vetor como tipo `char` mas colocou *strings* dentro dele como elementos. Há uma diferença entre aspas simples e dupla. O literal de caractere é com aspas simples.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getVector(char vector[], int pos) {
    return vector[pos];
}

int main() {
    char vector[5] = {'V', 'e', 't', 'o', 'r'};
    printf("%c", getVector(vector, 0));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fHy5vX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yvsjeimz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayParameter.c).

Comment: Resolvido. Ótima resposta.

Comment: @GabrielSales Você pode votar em tudo o que você achar útil no *site*, mesmo em coisas que não foi você que perguntou. A aceitação que você só pode escolher uma resposta de uma pergunta sua. A critério é seu mas não sei se você sabe disto. A resposta do mgibsonbr é boa também, é muito parecida com a minha. Apesar de não estar tão pronta quanto a minha acho que você deveria votar na dele também.

Comment: `int main()` também não é recomendado em C, pois representa uma lista variável de parâmetros, diferente do C++, onde a assinatura estaria correta. `int main(void)` seria o correto em C.

Comment: Primeiro tem um erro de terminologia aí: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32450/101. Segundo isto não tem relevância prática. Desta forma não há nenhum parâmetro declarado, portanto nada será usado. Pode vir vários argumentos. Mas como não tem parâmetros, não importa. Importaria se fosse outra função porque aí uma chamada com argumentos passaria pela compilação. Mas o `main()` não é chamado pelo código e sim pelo sistema operacional.

Comment: Erro de terminologia? Estou me referindo a parâmetros, não argumentos, argumentos ocorrem na chamada, não na declaração, e a isto que você está se referindo?

Comment: A relevância é a titulo de seguir o padrão, assim como você mesmo busca recomendar.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692152/1000282

Comment: Não tem uma lista de parâmetros aí, para você colocar uma lista de parâmetros tem que usar *varargs* (`...`). Sem parâmetro você não pode acessar nada, portanto não há problema. Teria um problema na chamada que poderia passar argumentos e compilaria, o que não aconteceria neste caso. Tanto que foi colocado a obrigatoriedade **somente** no C99 (um padrão não adota por todos compiladores *mainstream*). Nem o C++ quis fazer isto por não fazer o menor sentido. E mesmo os compiladores C99 não costumam gerar nem *warning* quando não tem o `void` neste caso de tão absurdo que é a recomendação.

Comment: Padrões servem para duas coisas: para garantir que compila em todos compiladores. Todos que eu conheço compilam assim mesmo quando C99 está ligado; para evitar erros por descuido. Neste caso nada causará problema. Então seguir o padrão por seguir, s/ **nenhuma** vantagem é bobagem, por isso os compiladores também não se importam com isto. Não é porque está no padrão que está certo. Você tem que dizer explicitamente que quer isto no compilador.

Comment: O C++ não faz isto porque não tem relação alguma com [protótipos K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#Compliance_detectability). C tem uma história à parte neste ponto que torna `int main()` em C ser algo totalmente diferente de `int main()` em C++, por motivos históricos. K&R não é encorajado em código atual, a não ser por motivo de compatibilidade maluco, ou base de código muito antiga, e.g., o código fonte do editor Vim.

Comment: Enfim, o uso de `int main()` reforça o uso de `int foo()` em C, quando o certo seria `int foo(void)`. O uso de `foo(42)` poderia passar sem notar e funcionar, ao passo que com a prática de `int foo(void)` isto nunca aconteceria pois geraria erro de compilação. Pra mim, já é motivo suficiente pra adotar a prática.

Answer (score 6):

Em C não se pode passar vetores por valor, apenas por referência (i.e. você precisa passar um ponteiro pro vetor, e não o vetor em si). Entretanto, a sintaxe do C permite que você defina sua função dessa forma:

```
char getVector(char vector[], int pos) {
```

E o compilador garante que o vetor automaticamente decaia a um ponteiro. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774473/520779).

Entretanto, o mesmo não é verdade para vetores multidimensionais:

```
char vector[5][2] = {"V", "e", "t", "o", "r"};

char getVector(char vector[][], int pos, int pos2) { // Não funciona

char getVector(char vector[][2], int pos, int pos2) { // Funciona

char getVector(char **vector, int pos, int pos2) { // Funciona
```

[Fonte](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html). [Fonte](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc2.html).

Quanto a seus erros de compilação:

- Em C há diferença entre uma string e um caractere único: strings são delimitadas por aspas duplas, e caracteres por aspas simples. De modo que sua inicialização do vetor deveria ser:

  ```
  char vector[5] = {'V', 'e', 't', 'o', 'r'};
  ```
- Não se pode criar funções dentro de outras funções em C. Passe seu `getVector` para fora da função `main`.

Comment: Eu votei mas não entendi o primeiro parágrafo. O vetor é uma referência implícita. Nesse ponto específico funciona igual ao Java. Você declara que o parâmetro é vetor  mas o argumento você passa normal porque ele já é um ponteiro opaco como no Java (embora os detalhes internos sejam diferentes).

Comment: @bigown Eu confesso que não entendo muito bem sobre vetores em C (aprendi sozinho antes da faculdade, depois nunca mais usei). Eu sabia que se podia passar structs por valor, e assumi que o mesmo se aplicava a arrays, mas na resposta linkada vi que não é o caso. Tentei responder com base no que li lá, mas posso não ter me expressado muito bem...

Answer (score 5):

As outras respostas já resolvem seu problema, mas gostaria de colaborar.

Em Lua não há diferença entre `"V"`, `'V'` e `[[V]]`, como você ler [aqui](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial). Todas tratadas como strings. Mas, em C aspas simples e aspas duplas tem significados diferentes.

Em C e C++, a aspas simples são utilizadas para um único caractere e as aspas duplas para strings. No caso das strings, o compilador inclui um caractere `null` ou `'\0'`, para identificar o fim da string.

Então, isso:

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
```

Equivale a isso, com o `'\0'` no final:

```
char str2[] = { 'H','e','l','l','o','\0' };
```

Exemplo: [ideone](http://ideone.com/R5jli9)