# Retornar uma função

Tags: php, funções

Criei uma função `teste()` que deve ser preenchida com o `While` e retornar os dados. Por que quando chamo minha função `teste()` dentro da função `PageLoad_Arquivo()` a mesma não carrega?

```
function teste(){

    $resultadowhile = "<table class='table table-hover'><thead><tr><th>Cod.</th><Data</th><th>Última Atualização</th><th>Unidade</th><th>Departamento</th><th>Arquivo</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $resultadowhile .= "<tr>" . 
            '<td>s<a href="cadastro_arquivo.php?id=' . $row['id_arquivo'] . '">' . $row['id_arquivo'] . '</a></td>' . 
            '<td>' . formatarDataBRASIL($row['txt_data']) . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_unidade'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_departamento'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_arquivo'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['flag_status'] . '</td>' . 
        "</tr>";
    }
    $resultadowhile .= "</table>";

}

function PageLoad_Arquivo(){

    $result = mysql_query("
    select a.id_arquivo, a.txt_arquivo, a.txt_data, a.txt_caminho, d.id_departamento, d.txt_departamento, u.id_unidade, u.txt_unidade, a.flag_status from tb_arquivo a
    left join tb_departamento d on a.id_departamento = d.id_departamento
    left join tb_unidade u on a.id_unidade = u.id_unidade
    ORDER BY a.txt_data DESC
    ") or die(mysql_error());

    $relacao = "style='display:block'";
    $cadastro = "style='display:none'";
    $resultadowhile = "";

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        teste();
        renderForm('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $relacao, $cadastro, $resultadowhile);
    }else{
        $resultadowhile = "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\">Sem resultados.</div>";
        renderForm('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $relacao, $cadastro, $resultadowhile);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ela carrega sim, mas você está achando que uma função entra dentro de outra como um `include`, e não é assim. Uma variável não comunica de uma função para outra. Você tem tem que passar o valor dela para a variável ou retornar o valor para quem chamou. Assim:

```
function teste($resultadowhile) {
    $resultadowhile .= "<table class='table table-hover'><thead><tr><th>Cod.</th><Data</th><th>Última Atualização</th><th>Unidade</th><th>Departamento</th><th>Arquivo</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $resultadowhile .= "<tr>" . 
            '<td>s<a href="cadastro_arquivo.php?id=' . $row['id_arquivo'] . '">' . $row['id_arquivo'] . '</a></td>' . 
            '<td>' . formatarDataBRASIL($row['txt_data']) . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_unidade'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_departamento'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['txt_arquivo'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $row['flag_status'] . '</td>' . 
        "</tr>";
    }
    $resultadowhile .= "</table>";
    return $resultadowhile;
}

function PageLoad_Arquivo() {
    $result = mysql_query("
    select a.id_arquivo, a.txt_arquivo, a.txt_data, a.txt_caminho, d.id_departamento, d.txt_departamento, u.id_unidade, u.txt_unidade, a.flag_status from tb_arquivo a
    left join tb_departamento d on a.id_departamento = d.id_departamento
    left join tb_unidade u on a.id_unidade = u.id_unidade
    ORDER BY a.txt_data DESC
    ") or die(mysql_error());
    $relacao = "style='display:block'";
    $cadastro = "style='display:none'";
    $resultadowhile = "";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $resultadowhile = teste($resultadowhile);
        renderForm('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $relacao, $cadastro, $resultadowhile);
    }else{
        $resultadowhile = "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\">Sem resultados.</div>";
        renderForm('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $relacao, $cadastro, $resultadowhile);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/BuildTemplate.php).

Note que apesar de nas duas funções existir uma variável com nome `$resultadowhile` elas são variáveis completamente diferentes e que por acaso tem o mesmo valor. Só porque o valor da variável existente na função `PageLoad_Arquivo()` foi passada para a variável na função `teste()`. Você pode passar qualquer valor de qualquer variável como nome que for como parâmetro. Pode passar um literal. Claro que idealmente neste caso deve ser algo do tipo *string*, caso contrário poderá não ter o resultado desejado.

Chamando `teste($resultadowhile)` você está passando o valor desta variável como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Declarando a função como `function teste($resultadowhile)` você está recendo uma parâmetro chamado `$resultadowhile`. Este parâmetro é uma variável local da função `teste()`, ela só existe dentro desta função.

Então para que você possa passar o valor manipulado da variável para a função que a chamou você precisa retorná-la através do comando `return` conforme visto na última linha da função modificada que eu postei.

Este retorno precisa ser guardado em uma variável e pode ser a mesma `$resultadowhile` que foi passada como argumento.

Claro que é possível não passar argumento algum se for do seu desejo mas a função ficaria menos flexível e complicaria usar em outras situações que você já tivesse um texto HTML inicial. E o uso da função é justamente poder reusar em diversas situações diferentes. Então você poderia retirar o parâmetro e apenas retornar o valor da variável se não quiser esta flexibilidade conforme mostrado da resposta do Oeslei.

Existe uma outra forma de passar o valor da variável através de referências mas neste caso não é necessário e é um tópico um pouco avançado.

Answer (score 8):

O problema não é que sua função não rode. Ela apenas não faz nada a não ser montar a string da tabela e fim da história. Você precisa retornar a string para poder receber o valor.

```
function teste() {
    // ...
    return $resultadowhile;
}

// ...
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $resultadowhile = teste();
```

---

***EDIT***

COmplementando, o mesmo vale para a sua variável `$result` que é utilizada na função `teste`. Esta variável não existe. Você precisa passá-la como parâmetro.

```
function teste($result) {
    // ...
}

// ...
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $resultadowhile = teste($result);
```

Comment: Tks... Estava tentando fazer como vc indicou e estava dando erro... na verdade eu estava fazendo diferente da sua recomendação, agora funfou.