# Referência de argumentos pode ser prejudicial?

Tags: php

Por padrão, argumentos de uma função são passados pelo valor (ou seja, se o valor do parâmetro dentro da função for alterado, ele não é alterado fora da função). Para permitir que uma função modifique seus argumentos, eles devem ser passados por *referência*.

Para ter um argumento para uma função sempre passados por referência, adicionamos um `E` comercial (`&`) para o argumento desejado na função da função, como no exemplo:

```
<?php
function something(&$string)
{
    $string .= 'B';
}

$variavel = 'A';

something($variavel );
echo $variavel;//Irá mostrar "AB"
```

Eu raramente uso referencias nos argumentos de funções PHP (para não dizer nunca), pois nunca vi necessidade realmente ou vantagem.

Porém me lembrei que li certa vez que o uso de referencia não é "bom" (não me lembro aonde li), porém noto que algumas vezes ele é usado, gostaria de saber se o uso de  referencias em argumentos implica em algum problema ou perda de performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Prejudicial, diria que sim

Atualmente eu diria que sim, pode ser prejudicial dada a forma [como todo o processo se desenrola desde a versão 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

A partir da versão 5.3.0, se a chamada da função tiver o `&`, é emitido um *warning* com:

> call-time pass-by-reference

A partir da versão 5.4.0, o erro em cima foi removido, e obtemos o *fatal error*.

Ora, isto quer dizer que já não podemos sinalizar no código, na chamada de uma função, que determinado valor está a ser passado como referência, estando a leitura do código a ser dificultada. Para sabermos, precisamos de aceder "fisicamente" à função e observar os argumentos da mesma.

Prejudicial sem dúvida porque o controlo está agora restrito, dando origem a uma maior probabilidade de erros e/ou enganos por parte do programador, em particular em projetos onde são diversos os envolvidos.

## Vantagens

A única vantagem que alguma vez vi na passagem de valores por referência foi o fato de termos um *fallback* no caso de algo correr mal bem mais à frente no código.

Ou o sentido inverso, ter variáveis de controlo que vão sendo manipuladas dentro de funções "mais dentro" do nosso código, sem termos que andar com as mesmas para a frente e para trás, com `return` em todo o lado:

```
$super = 1;

function umControloQualquer(&$super) {

    (int)((int)true==1)+2 ? $super++ : $super=0;
}

umControloQualquer($super);

// 5000 linhas e 20 ficheiros depois...

if ($super>=2)
    echo $super;
else
    echo "Alguma coisa correu mal porque o BuBu deveria ser nível II neste momento!";
```

<sup>Simulação de variável de controlo passada por referencia para uma função que vai alterar a mesma consoante uma verificação. O exemplo é simplicista, mas espelha um caso prático.</sup>

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/nOqmmj).

Comment: Boa Zuul, acho que entendi o uso "errado" não é no `function foo(&$a){}` é no `echo foo(&a);` por exemplo ou seja `function foo(&$a)` não vai emitir erro, mas echo `echo foo(&$a)` vai, me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Grato :) +1, posso lançar uma edição? Para deixar isto mais claro :)

Answer (score 5):

Se existe o recurso é porque existe uma razão para seu uso. Salvo existir algo complementar que o torne obsoleto.

Provavelmente a recomendação de não usar é para tentar otimizações. Isso pode ser considerado otimização prematura, principalmente porque o PHP já faz otimização de passar o argumento por referência quando isso é útil mesmo que não tenha nenhuma menção a passar por referência. Claro que se a semântica esperada não é a passagem por referência, a otimização trata de usar a técnica de [*copy-on-write*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Então uma tentativa de otimizar passando algo por referência pode até atrapalhar esta otimização.

Nem vou repetir o que sempre falo que micro-otimizar PHP não costuma ser a coisa mais produtiva.

Embora raro, pode haver o problema de começar ter referências p/ referências e perder o controle se for usado em exagero.

Mas se a intenção realmente é passar por referência, se tem um bom motivo para usar isso, aí não tem problema. E de fato, raramente ela é necessária. Quase sempre quando alguém pensa em usar uma referência, provavelmente está pensando na performance ou não achou uma forma melhor de fazer o mesmo, então o uso é errado.

Quase sempre que a intenção é passar por referência, deveria fazer isso com um tipo que naturalmente é passado com esta semântica.

Mas para tudo existe motivo para usar ou não usar. Como tudo, use se **realmente** souber o que está fazendo, se entende todas implicações. E não use se não souber porque está usando. Nem todo mundo entende o que acontece com os dados quando usa uma referência. Não é tão complicado, mas é fácil esquecer que está manipulando uma referência e isto tem consequências em toda escrita realizada naquela variável.

---

Eu entendi o uso da referência no [argumento que é diferente do parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Mas depois da resposta do Zuul eu prestei mais atenção ao exemplo e vi algo diferente.

## Tem problema sim.

Uma coisa é você dizer que quer passar um argumento por referência, conforme o título da pergunta, outra coisa é pedir no parâmetro que o argumento seja recebido por referência implicitamente. Ou seja, quem chama não sabe que está passando por referência algo que deveria ser passado por valor em condições normais.

Mas que raio de linguagem permite isto? PHP, claro. E os mantenedores da linguagem se superaram. Eu não sabia mas as versões mais novas tornaram o problema ainda pior.

Obrigar que o chamador use uma referência não é tão ruim assim. Pense bem. Se o chamador está **explicitamente** passando por referência, ele mostra que sabe que esta semântica está sendo usada, que mal pode causar? No máximo, o que eu citei, o programador não saber direito o que isto significa.

Então uma possibilidade de melhoria na linguagem seria obrigar a chamada usar a referência no argumento quando o parâmetro foi anotado para ser recebido por referência.

Mas o que ela fez? Proibiu fazer :D Isto... é... in-crí-vel!

Aí as versões novas tornou a referência impraticável para quem gosta de código organizado, expressivo, de código que indique sua intenção e não dê margem à interpretação errada. Como a passagem por referência agora é obrigatoriamente implícita use-a se quiser criar confusão.

Isto seria o "certo":

```
<?php
function something(&$string) {
    $string .= 'B';
}
$variavel = 'A';
something(&$variavel); //<============ Note aqui
echo $variavel; //Irá mostrar "AB"
```

Mas isto não compila. O certo era isto ser obrigatório. Assim a "assinatura" da chamada bate com a assinatura da definição da função. Ou seja, ambas possuem a referência.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NsYFIt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qdqvqekf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/ReferenceParameter.php).

Não estou dizendo que programadores cuidadosos não possam programar usando referências implícitas sem causar problemas. Mas programadores cuidadosos programam em C, em Assembly :) O que eu quero dizer é que PHP não deveria ser uma linguagem onde você tem que ter este tipo de preocupação. Na verdade esta especificamente, nem C tem. Em C você tem que ser explícito.

Claro que não estou falando do tipos que são conhecidos por serem por referência, aí como é de conhecimento de todo programador fica mais fácil entender.

Concluindo, tem problema de legibilidade, sim, mas não quer dizer que não deve ser usada em hipótese alguma. Eu realmente evitaria e quando fosse preciso usar, eu documentaria de forma ostensiva.

Comment: Obrigado, como sempre com uma grande resposta, só não entendi a necessidade do comentário *Se existe o recurso é porque existe uma razão para seu uso.*, em nenhum momento indaguei por que dele **existir**.

Comment: Claro, é porque eu gosto de colocar uma informação mais completa para que todos entendam. Foi uma introdução para chegar na conclusão do último parágrafo. De uma certa forma questiono quem diz que não é para usar, em geral essas regras geram mais confusão que ajudam porque elas não explicam. No seu caso você questiona e não afirma, mas você já deve saber que as respostas são melhores quando respondem para todos e não só para quem perguntou. Comecei querendo quebrar o mito, pq eu tb já li gente dizendo p/ ñ usar e ponto.

Comment: Entendi, concordo, realmente era bem comum (hoje não vejo mais isto), talvez fosse algo de confusão mesmo por parte deles (famosa fofoca). +1, por enquanto vou aguardar, se não tiver resposta mais completa então irei marcar a sua. Grato

Comment: Eu atualizei porque me prendi ao título da pergunta mas olhando o todo, o que o Zuul escreveu faz mais sentido. Me confundi por causa da terminologia. Poucas linguagens deixam a referência ser implícita quando o parâmetro deveria ser por valor, mas PHP se superou proibindo ser explícito.

Comment: Se entendi a situação é apenas no chamar `echo foo(&$a)` e não na declaração `function foo(&$a)`, ou seja o código que citei não tem problema "algum" (não que seja realmente algo útil), portanto a restrição só se no momento do uso. Talvez fornecer um exemplo para as pessoas não se confundirem seria interessante, afinal "chamador" nem sempre é claro.

Comment: Depende do que você chama "Problema". Olhando ali pertinho, você está vendo o que está acontecendo. Mas pense que você não tem acesso à função fácil assim. Você chama `something($variavel);`, você espera que `$variável` que tem semântica de valor seja alterada lá dentro? Lembre-se, sem ver a função? Não acha que é um problema não ficar claro que será alterada? Não é um problemão, mas é um probleminha. Mas se você espera que isto aconteça nesta função, você está bem informado disto, não é problema. Não é a referência que é problema, é ela ser implícita.

Comment: O problema de fornecer um exemplo que seria mais correto é que não funciona mais em versões recentes do PHP :) O PHP fez essa besteira, agora não dá mais para usar do jeito "certo".

Comment: A função é meramente ilustrativa, o exemplo seria para entender o que "proibido" no PHP nas novas versões, usar no caso `declarar função=Ok`, usar no `tempo chamada=Proibido`, pois as vezes exemplos ficam mais claros para entender as diferentes situações.

Comment: O PHP nunca fez do jeito que você diz ser o mais certo, @bigown. Até o 5.2 ele permitia passar qualquer coisa por referência mesmo que a assinatura da função não dissesse isso. Aí você tinha o problema inverso: as funções geravam efeitos colaterais sem que pretendessem fazer isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, eu sei. Mas pelo menos nesse sentido que estou falando, você explicitamente dizer que vai passar por referência não é tão grave, apesar de potencialmente problemático também. Pelo menos está explícito. Ruim é não deixar ser explícito. Claro que pode dar totô se passar por referência algo que não deveria, mas pelo menos você sabe onde está se metendo. O ideal, é claro, é as assinaturas baterem como eu coloquei na última edição.

Comment: @bfavaretto seu comentário valeria uma resposta, tão simples, porém esclarecedor, os efeitos colaterais que você citou é o motivo de tudo :)

Answer (score 2):

Está resposta apenas se faz complementar;

### Resumindo

Os *boatos* sobre o uso das referencias `&$variavel` se referiam apenas quando você chama as funções e não quando as declara, ou seja:

Isto é permitido e válido (além de útil):

```
function foo(&$a) {
   $a = 'b';
   return true;
}
```

Isto não é mais permitido e emite erros desde o php5.3:

```
$a = 'a';
var_dump(foo(&$a));
```

### O problema

O "problema" de usar referencia *não* se refere ao uso na **declaração** das funções, tal como:

```
function foo(&$a) {
   $a = array();
}

$test = array();
foo($test);
print_r($test);
```

Mas sim no momento de chamar uma função e usar a referencia, tal como:

```
...
foo(&$test);//Chamando a função
print_r($test);
```

Ou seja, a partir do momento da chamada (*call-time pass-by-reference*), em outras palavras, no momento da declaração "não" há problema.

### Quando usar

Como citado já, o uso de referencias em argumentos de funções não são tão úteis, porém uma situação que pode se fazer útil seria semelhante ao da função `bool exec($comando, $saida);`, por exemplo:

```
function foo($a, &$b) {
    $b = array();
    if ($a === 'A') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Muitas funções nativas do PHP fazem uso disto, como: `rsort`, `sort`, `exec`, `array_walk`, `preg_match_all`, etc.

Outra situação que podemos usar é no uso da função `array_walk`, por exemplo:

```
function foo(&$item, $key){//Usando referencia em item
   if($key === 'c'){
        $item = 'Tchau';
   }
}

$arr = array('a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => 'Oi');

array_walk($arr, 'foo');
print_r($arr);
```

A saída vai ser algo como:

```
array(
    [a] => '1',
    [b] => '2',
    [c] => 'Tchau'
)
```

### Somos obrigados a usar isto?

No momento de criarmos/declaramos uma função não precisamos disto (a não ser que queira), pode-se usar outras maneiras para retornar o valor, como um simples `return ...;`. Se quiser retornar dois dados diferentes podemos usar um array associativo como por exemplo:

```
function foo($a) {
   ...
   return array(
       'status' => $x, //Retorna boolean
       'message' => $y //Retorna string
   );
}
```