# Objetos copiados ficam em endereços diferentes?

Tags: php, memória, objetos

Quando eu tenho por exemplo:

```php
$abc = new ZZZ();

$mno = $abc;
```

O objeto `$mno` é o mesmo que `$abc`? Ou seja, possuem "endereços de memória" iguais? Como eu faço pra poder imprimir esse "endereço de memória"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro vamos entender ass definições corretas. Nem `$abc`, nem `$mno` são objetos, são [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

As variáveis podem armazenar objetos, ou referências para objetos. Se elas armazenarem objetos obviamente os objetos são diferentes porque são duas variáveis diferente , e se leu e definição do que é uma variável, sabe que são dois endereços de memória completamente diferentes.

Se na variável tem armazenado uma referência, e se usou um `new` certamente tem uma referência, então, é possível que essa referência seja armazenada em duas variáveis diferentes, e se é a mesma referência ela aponta para o mesmo objeto.

No caso quando fez `$mno = $abc` você pegou a referência que estava armazenada em `$abc` e atribuiu para `$mno`, portanto as duas variáveis tem o mesmo valor nesse momento, e concluímos também que é a mesma referência apontando para o mesmo objeto. Inclusive podemos concluir ser o mesmo objeto por só teve uma instrução de criação do objeto.

Não há nada na API padrão do PHP que diga confiavelmente qual é o endereço de um objeto.

Estranhamente (ou não, afinal PHP é cheio dessas coisas inconsistentes) se você adota uma referência a algo que já é uma referência, a linguagem desconsidera essa referência e não tem dupla indireção. Abaixo tem outras esquisitices. Por isso só use a referência se não tiver outro jeito, e sempre tem.

Pode ajudar:

- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [Qual a vantagem dos objetos em PHP serem passados por referências por padrão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405919/101)
- [Referência de argumentos pode ser prejudicial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57741/101)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ficou mais claro. Mas e se trocarmos a segunda linha por $mno = &$abc? Quais seriam as diferenças? Fiquei fazendo alguns testes com essa nova linha e mesmo assim, parecem referenciar para o mesmo objeto. Por isso então que não entendi a diferença

Comment: Pra esse caso muda nada, você já tem um referência.

Comment: Hmm interessante. Aprendendo um pouco mais sobre PHP, obrigado pela ajuda