# Como acessar variáveis presentes em diferentes funções?

Tags: python, variáveis, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

Qual a melhor maneira de acessar uma variável que foi criada em uma função? Por exemplo:

```
def Luggage():
    mala = []
    take = raw_input("O que você deseja levar na sua viagem?")
    mala.append(take)
```

Caso eu quisesse acessar e utilizar a lista `mala` em uma outra função, como deveria proceder? Nesse caso, seria mais interessante utilizar funções criadas dentro de classes?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Tudo o que você coloca dentro de uma função é local a esta função, você não pode usar em outros lugares. Existem algumas soluções.

A primeira é retornar o valor - mas não a variável - que deseja, e aí quem chamar a função pode "capturar" esse valor e fazer o que desejar.

Ou deve criar uma variável em outro local que possa ser usada dentro da função. Nesse caso pode haver duas alternativas. Alguns tipos de variáveis podem ter seu valor passado para a função como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) e a função atualiza o parâmetro recebido, quando a função voltar, a variável que tinha este valor antes da chamada terá o valor colocado dentro da função.

O mais comum nesses casos é criar uma classe que contenha variáveis que estão presentes na classe, aí todas funções dentro da classe terão acesso a estas variáveis da classe, então qualquer alteração nela dentro de uma função refletirá para todas as outras.

Para exemplos muito simples, e só nestes casos, é possível declarar a variável fora da função e ela será acessada por todas funções. Isso é o equivalente ao que se faz com classes. Mas com classes você tem um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) definido e não causa confusão. Em um código muito simples que não será usado em um sistema complexo, ou seja, em um código de *script* mesmo, até dá para usar sem maiores confusões, mas em outras situações não deve usar esta forma.

Esses dois conceitos de uso de variáveis fora da função são mais avançados e acho que não deve tentar agora que ainda não domina o funcionamento básico de funções. Por enquanto só coloque um retorno:

```
def Luggage():
    mala = []
    take = raw_input("O que você deseja levar na sua viagem?")
    mala.append(take)
    return mala
```

Chamando:

```
x = Luggage()
print(x)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NgKoRF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cnemoknd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/VariableInFunction.py).

Comment: Entendo. Mas retornando o valor, posso acessá-lo dentro de uma outra função? Por exemplo: `def Hotel(): if shampoo in mala: print "Tomar banho"`

Comment: Você pode passá-la como parâmetro para esta função. Os dados precisam ser comunicados entre as funções. A não ser que faça uso da classe. Mas não ache que criar uma classe é solução para tudo. Antes de cogitar criar uma classe, entenda bem tudo sobre isto, a maioria das pessoas, principalmente quando estão começando abusam de classes para resolver um problema que deveria ser resolvido de outra forma. O `print()` é uma função é o dado foi usado dentro dela. Você não viu, mas ele foi usado, porque ele foi passado como parâmetro.

Comment: @bigown ele poderia definir a variável como global, por exemplo `global mala`?

Comment: Assim daria para acessar ela em todo lugar do código

Comment: Sim, mas eu não vou ensinar essa gambiarra :D Tá bom, eu vou colocar, com ressalva :)

Comment: tabem poderia usar um decorador com a funcao **Luggage**

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão é utilizar definição de variável global:

```
def Luggage():
    global mala
    mala = []
    take = "O que voce deseja levar na sua viagem?"
    mala.append(take)
    take = "----teste------"
    mala.append(take)
    return mala

Luggage()

for i in mala:
    print (i)
```