# Como funciona um método que pode receber vários parâmetros?

Tags: c#, parâmetros, método

Segundo a documentação do C#:

> O método `String.Format` é responsável por converter o valor de
> objetos em cadeias de caracteres com base nos formatos especificados e
> os insere em outra cadeia de caracteres.

Contudo, tenho uma duvida em relação aos parâmetros que são passados para ele, este método parece aceitar uma quantidade ilimitada de parâmetros, posso passar quantos parâmetros eu desejar, veja o exemplo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string numeros = string.Format("Numeros: {0}, {1}, {2}.", "Um", "Dois", "Tres");
        string nomes = string.Format("Nomes: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}.", "Joao", "Maria", "Junior", "Carvalho", "Leticia", "Silva");

        Console.WriteLine(nomes);
        Console.WriteLine(numeros);
    }
}
```

No exemplo o método foi invocado com **quatro** parâmetros, sendo o primeiro a *string* que será formatada e os outros os valores que serão inseridos na *string*, em seguida ele foi invocado com **sete** parâmetros.

As minhas duvidas são:

1. Como esse método foi definido para ter este comportamento de aceitar
   vários parâmetros?
2. A quantidade de parâmetros que eu posso passar para ele é ilimitada?
3. É possível escrever métodos como este que pode aceitar uma
   quantidade indefinida de parâmetros, se sim, como fazer?
4. E como eu posso chamar esta prática?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode olhar o [código fonte dele](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Manipulation.cs,508) para ver. Esse mecanismo é um **[parâmetro com quantidade variável de argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)**.

A quantidade é virtualmente ilimitada e pode ser usado em qualquer método que quiser, desde que seja o último parâmetro:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void UseParams(params int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) Write(list[i] + " ");
        WriteLine();
    }
}

UseParams(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PSnPib). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYJtMl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Params.cs).

Retirado da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

A palavra-chave `params` é que determina que este parâmetro funcionará assim.

Dá pra ver que no fundo é um único parâmetro do tipo *array* de alguma coisa (algum tipo). Muitas vezes usa-se um `Object[]` para aceitar qualquer coisa mesmo. Então, embora a sintaxe da chamada do método passe vários argumentos, eles são encapsulados todos nesse *array*.

Há uma proposta para o C# 8 ou mais pra frente aceitar que o parâmetro seja um enumerável qualquer e não só um *array*.

Há um mecanismo de [argumentos opcionais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que pode ser confundido com esse mecanismo em algumas situações. Lembrando que a quantidade de parâmetros sempre é definida nos dois casos. Tanto um quanto outro evitam fazer muito *overloding* de métodos, o que no caso do *varargs* seria quase impraticável.

Parece que nunca pensaram em ter uma forma de limitar a quantidade de argumentos que pode passar para este parâmetro. Se precisa disso o jeito é fazer sobrecarga mesmo.

Comment: Parece que também é possível usar `...` ou estou enganado?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é possível em C#, o que é uma pena, mas tb ñ faz tanta diferença assim.

Answer (score 8):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996429/1518921) você deve usar o modificador `params`, desta maneira:

```
public static int AddUp(params int[] values)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

A chamada ficou assim:

```
AddUp(4, 5, 6);
```

Um método com strings e `return` ficaria assim:

```
public static string MeuMetodo(params string[] values)
{
    return String.Join(" ", values);
}
```

E pra usar ficaria assim:

```
MeuMetodo("Olá", "Mundo", "!");
```

Você também pode usar o modificador `params` após um determinado parâmetro em um método, por exemplo você quer obrigar que o primeiro parâmetro seja uma string e os demais sejam `int` determinado por você:

```
public static string MeuMetodo(string primeiro, params int[] values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(primeiro);
    Console.WriteLine(values);
    return String.Join(" ", values);
}
```

IDEONE: https://ideone.com/kgTLx1