# Sobrecarga de métodos (double e float)

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, sobrecarga

Tendo 2 métodos com mesmo nome, porém os tipos são diferentes (`double` e `float`), a quantidade de parâmetro é a mesma, qual dos métodos o Java vai reconhecer primeiro e por quê?

Comment: Java não é como linguagens fracamente tipadas (i.e.: Javascript), na qual você pode passar o que quiser (literalmente) para uma função. Você não vai conseguir passar um `float` para uma função esperando um `double` e vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende de qual valor for usado na sua chamada. Se o valor for um `float` ou qualquer outro que seja automaticamente convertido para `float`, será o o método que recebe `float`, se o tipo do [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) da chamada do método for um `double`, chamará o método cujo parâmetro é um `double`.

Não existe isso de qual será chamado primeiro. Salvo a pergunta partir de uma premissa errada.

```
class Classe {
     void metodo(float x) {
        System.out.printf("Float %f\n", x);
    }
     void metodo(double x) {
        System.out.printf("Double %f\n", x);
    }
}
 
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Classe classe = new Classe();
        classe.metodo(1);
        classe.metodo(1.0);
        classe.metodo(1.0f);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oddWfH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kupjfjaj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Overload.java).

Comment: Já ia perguntar se, ao inves de double e float, fosse float e Float(classe wrapper) como a jvm iria entender, mas lembrei que, apesar de existir o unboxing entre os tipo primitivo e class wrapper, são tipos diferentes e vai prevalecer a mesma premissa que você citou na pergunta... Ou estou errado?

Comment: Está certo, no fundo o valor interno do tipo encaixotado será do tipo primitivo, ainda que sua caixa seja, claro, outro tipo.

Comment: Sim, ignora o "chamar primeiro", quis dizer "qual dos métodos ele chama", a minha dúvida é na leitura do valor, se quando lê 1.0 o java vai reconhecer como float ou como double, já que os dois são de tipos bem similares