# Aparece "+ 3 overloads" no Visual Studio - O que seria isso?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Em algumas funções aparece tal quantidade de *overloads*, isso quer dizer que quanto maior esse número, mais lenta é?

Obs: Usei *tag* C++ e C# por que foi onde vi esses tais de *overloads* nessas linguagens. Uso Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Em C não tem *overloads* (tinha isso ma pergunta original). Só em C++ e C#.

Isso é a sobrecarga de métodos ou funções. Grosso modo ela consiste em ter uma [função com o mesmo nome, mas com parâmetros de tipos diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Não vou entrar em detalhes porque já tem [resposta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131023/101), lá mostra o funcionamento interno.

Embora o critério de resolução de qual método usar seja diferente, C++ trabalha essencialmente da mesma forma que C#, ou Java, por exemplo. Grande parte das linguagens estaticamente tipadas modernas possuem algo assim.

Isso não afeta em nada a performance negativamente. Pelo contrário, uma das alternativas mais usadas (resolver, provavelmente com `if` ou `switch`, o que o método deve fazer de fato, já que existem caminhos alternativos de execução) afetaria a performance por delegar a decisão para o tempo de execução.

Outra forma seria usar nomes diferentes para funções semelhantes, como o C faz. O que pode afetar a legibilidade (algumas pessoas discordam), mas não a performance.

O que o IDE mostra é que você tem alternativas de escolha de qual assinatura usar (sem o *overload* não dá para fazer isto). No caso específico existem 4 métodos diferentes que podem ser aplicados ali. Se ele tiver vários parâmetros, conforme for colocando novos [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) na chamada, vai afunilando e diminuindo, até que não vai mais mostrar essa dica porque você já tem uma assinatura única e não há confusão com outros. Ao final sempre terá que reduzir a ambiguidade a zero.

[Exemplo prático com 2 sobrecarga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128247/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, traduzindo no google parece ser algo bem diferente, mas eu entendi! Por exemplo o argumento 0 da função str.find pode ser tanto um caractere char como uma string :D

Comment: Não, isto está incorreto.

Comment: Oush, é não? Não é quando determinada função aceita mais argumentos e até mesmo diferentes tipos de argumentos?

Comment: São funções completamente diferentes, não é a mesma.

Answer (score 17):

## Por que *overloads* não têm custo de desempenho?

Complementando [a resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137186/132), o compilador ou máquina virtual é capaz de resolver os *overloads* estaticamente, identificando unicamente os métodos não apenas por seu nome, mas sim pelo seu nome e pelos tipos dos parâmetros. É como se os métodos `metodo(String)`, `metodo(int)` e `metodo(String, int)` não se chamassem apenas `metodo`, e sim `metodo_String`, `metodo_int` e `metodo_String_int`, o que faz com que cada um deles tenha uma identificação diferente. E por causa disso, não há peso em questão de desempenho em relação a isso.

## E os *overrides*?

Quanto aos *overrides*, o funcionamento é diferente, o método chamado depende da classe da instância, que é uma informação que só estará presente em tempo de execução.

Uma forma simples de implementar um *override* seria que métodos virtuais (ou seja, métodos que possam ser sobrescritos), fossem implementados internamente com um `if` ou `switch` que olhasse para o tipo do `this` chamando o método concreto adequado, o que teria algum peso razoável em termos de desempenho. Ocorre que não é essa a forma como o *override* é implementado.

Na verdade, os *overrides* são resolvidos por meio de ponteiros de função e [*vtables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Cada *vtable* é uma tabela que cada classe concreta tem contendo ponteiros de funções para os métodos implementados naquela classe. Assim sendo, ao chamar um método, o que ocorre internamente é que uma referência à classe é obtida a partir da referência à classe que cada instância tem, e dessa referência à classe (que contém o início da *vtable* em um *offset* de memória fixo), o ponteiro de função referente ao método a ser invocado é obtido, sendo-lhe passado a referência à instância como um parâmetro, juntamente com os demais parâmetros. E antes que alguém pergunte, sim, isso significa que o compilador ou máquina virtual adiciona um parâmetro oculto que se torna a referência `this` em cada método não-estático.

Quanto ao desempenho, há um custo mínimo associado sim na invocação de métodos não-estáticos, que consiste em uma operação de indireção e uma soma de inteiros, e é feita ao desreferenciar-se o ponteiro para a instância, ler um inteiro do local de memória obtido (que é o endereço da classe, que sempre será a primeira informação disponível na área de memória alocada para cada objeto) e somar a esse endereço, o *offset* do método dentro da *vtable*, obtendo-se então o ponteiro para o método correspondente. Isso contrasta com o caso de métodos estáticos, em que o ponteiro para o método já é conhecido de antemão. Referências a métodos de interfaces podem precisar de mais uma ou duas instruções de máquina para serem resolvidas, vez que a localização do método na *vtable* vai ser um pouco mais complicada.

Por outro lado, pessoas que projetam compiladores e máquinas virtuais tentam otimizar este custo de desempenho, de forma que chamadas de métodos virtuais que puderem ser determinadas estaticamente (por exemplo, quando o tipo da instância é uma classe concreta para a qual não há subclasses) podem ser simplificadas eliminando-se a necessidade de buscar o método na *vtable* em tempo de execução ao fazer-se isso em tempo de compilação, eliminando-se também o custo associado. Além disso, outros tipos de otimizações mais complexas com compilação *just-in-time* são possíveis para eliminar-se estes custos em vários casos.

Comment: Opa! Tem muita coisa ai que não faz parte da resposta mas muito obrigado!