# "Transportar" variáveis entre funções, aparece caractere estranho no lugar?

Tags: c, string, funções

Na função `main` quando imprimo um `char`, ele aparece um código estranho parecendo um hexa:

Mas quando imprimo o mesmo `char` em outra função ela aparece normal.

```
char tempA[100] = "1111";


int main () {

    strcpy(tempA , "11");
    printf("\n\n  )  ====>  tempTestA = %s \n\n", tempA);   // aqui NAO funciona, EXIBINDO APENAS CARACTERES estranhos..

  outraFuncao(tempA);

}

int outraFuncao(tempA)
{

    printf("\n\n  )  ====>  tempTestB = %s \n\n", tempA);   // aqui NAO funciona, EXIBINDO APENAS CARACTERES estranhos..


    strcpy(tempmais , "11");
    printf("\n\n  )  ====>  tempTestB = %s \n\n", tempmais);   // aqui funciona bem..

//restante da funcao...

}
```

E se eu chamo a função `outraFuncao()` com algum parâmetro, ele também mostra nos valores, apenas caracteres estranhos.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Aparentemente o título não bate com o problema apresentado. Qual problema você quer resolver?

Comment: E se eu chamo a função "outraFuncao()" com algum parâmetro, ele também mostra nos valores, apenas caracteres estranhos.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: O ideal é colocar um código real que está usando. A pergunta está extremamente confusa e só piorou com esse comentário.

Comment: mas esse eh o codigo real...

Comment: `eu chamo a função "outraFuncao()" com algum parâmetro` sua frase, o código não faz isso. Se é o código real, o comentário não faz sentido.

Comment: desculpe o mau jeito, acho que nao estou conseguindo fazer a pergunta...  mas editei o post, espero estar mais claro..

Comment: Na verdade só ficou pior, porque o código não bate com a afirmação, o corpo não bate com o título que faria sentido se o resto do texto batesse com a última afirmação. De qualquer forma respondi o que pede o título, reorganizando o código para lhe mostrar o jeito certo de fazer e consertando o problema de impressão. Pode ser que tenha algum outro problema, mas o código não mostra isso. Ainda assim o código da minha resposta é a solução completa.

Comment: Achei curioso que o código tem diversos erros a as respostas que só corrigem um deles tem mais votos que a minha que corrige todos erros.

Comment: pois eh...  estou confuso .. . demais...

Comment: Ola @bigown, (editei o post)  e fiz as correcoes que voce sugeriu!  mas o probema persiste...  qunado chamo outraFuncao(tempA);  e imprimo para a tela .. os erros continuam.. pode me dar um toque?

Comment: Você não fez tudo o que eu falei. Você viu que o meu está funcionando? Clicou lá no **ideone** para ver? De qualquer forma você não pode ficar modificando a pergunta. Pergunta feita, pergunta respondida. Se tem outro problema outra pergunta deve ser feita. Mas antes de fazer outra precisa seguir o que eu disse, você está fazendo outra coisa, não vai funciona mesmo. Pra falar a verdade só um compilador ruim vai compilar esse código. Você corrigiu o que as outras respostas disseram, a minha resolve todos os problemas. Eu provei isso.

Comment: ok, deixa eu rever! com certeza fiz besteira por aqui! valeu pela paciencia! esto aprendendo e com uma avalanche de informacao!!  rrsrs  !

Comment: valeu!!!  percebi o que estava fazendo de errado!!!!  valeuuu!!   nossa... como estudar cansa!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se transporta variáveis de uma função para outra. Apenas se copia valores de uma função para outra. E alguns desses valores dão acesso à algum objeto disponível na memória.

Você [precisa aprender sobre parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Você já usa argumentos em funções prontas que são esse valores que são passados na chamada das funções. Agora vai criar suas funções para receber esses valores, são os parâmetros.

O que fez é uso de variável global. Apesar de funcionar em alguns casos não é o jeito correto de fazer. Só deve usar essa forma quando dominar completamente todo o funcionamento de uma aplicação (o que muitos programadores nunca chegam nesse ponto, ainda mais em C).

Na verdade isso é uma simplificação. O ideal seria estudar mais profundamente o assunto.

Há um outro problema na impressão. Ela está mandando imprimir um caractere. Parece que quer imprimir uma *string*. Então teria que usar `%s`.

Funcionar não é o mesmo de estar certo.

```
void outraFuncao(char *temp) { //recebe 1 ponteiro p/ o objeto que é uma sequência de chars
    strcpy(temp, "11");
    printf("tempTest = %s\n", temp);
}

int main() {
    char tempA[100] = "1111";
    outraFuncao(tempA); //passa o ponteiro do array
    printf("tempTest = %s\n", tempA); //o objeto foi modificado, já que passou um ponteiro
    strcpy(tempA, "22"); //mudou o valor
    printf("tempTest = %s\n", tempA); //imprimiu a string
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fa3KYe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tpcllqtx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Parameter.c).

Answer (score 3):

Mude "%c" para "%s". Este é o erro. Mesmo no caso que está aparentemente funcionando, é por acaso...

Answer (score 3):

%c é utilizado para char único, como você tem char[100] deve usar %s