# O que é um parâmetro de saída?

Tags: funções, parâmetros, independente-de-linguagem, ciência-da-computação

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
appendFooter(s);
```

Analisando a assinatura da função, temos o seguinte:

```
public void appendFooter(StringBuffer report)
```

O parâmetro `s` é considerado na função acima como sendo um parâmetro de saída. Por quê?

O que é um parâmetro de saída?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou tentar responder o mais correto possível, mas sem saber a linguagem a resposta pode não ser verdadeira, ainda que eu esteja confiante que isso vale para a quase todos os casos.

```
appendFooter(s);
appendFooter(StringBuffer report)
```

`s` [seria um argumento e damos o nome de parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para `report`.

É possível dizer que o parâmetro, no caso `report` é de saída tanto quanto é de entrada.

## Parâmetro de entrada

```
void metodo(int x) {
    print x;
}
```

Esse é um caso onde o parâmetro é de entrada. Qualquer coisa que seja enviada para esse método vai em única direção, o objeto *entra* no método.

## Parâmetro de entrada e saída

```
void metodo(array x) {
    x[0] = 1;
}
```

Nesse caso o objeto é um tipo por referência, então ele envia para o método apenas uma forma de ponteiro que dá acesso ao objeto. Qualquer alteração ao objeto se refletirá no argumento. Então é possível transferir um valor para o argumento através do parâmetro.

Ele vai em duas direções, entra um valor no método e pode sair um valor desse método.

No exemplo o elemento 0 do *array* passará ter o valor 1 mesmo quando o método encerrar. É uma forma de retornar um valor pelo próprio parâmetro.

Se o argumento não for uma variável, esse retorno não poderá ser aproveitado para nada depois, portando haverá a saída, mas ele será descartada.

É possível em algumas linguagens impedir que haja a saída em tipos por referência, algo assim:

```
void metodo(const array x) {
    x[0] = 1;
}
```

Nesse caso qualquer alteração em `x` não será refletida no argumento, portanto não há saída.

## Parâmetro de saída

```
void metodo(out int x) {
    x = 1;
}
```

Algumas linguagens possuem parâmetro puramente de saída. Nessa forma o argumento precisa ser uma variável obrigatoriamente para receber o valor que o método envia para ela. Não é possível enviar um valor para o método, portanto se a variável tiver um valor, ele não será enviado como parâmetro de entrada. Ele tem apenas uma direção, a saída.

Nesse exemplo `x` terá o valor 1 ao final do método e quem chamou o método receberá esse valor, algo assim:

```
var int a;
metodo(a);
print a; //imprimirá 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/OutParameter.cs).

Esse é um recurso útil para ter vários retornos no método, já que o normal é que ele só retorne um valor. Algumas linguagens possuem recurso para retornar múltiplos valores, o que dispensa ter um parâmetro exclusivo de saída.

## Conclusão

Eu imagino que o tipo `StringBuffer` seja um tipo por referência, então `report` é um parâmetro de entrada e saída.

Answer (score 8):

Um parâmetro de saída não cria um novo local de armazenamento, ao invés  disso, ele representa o mesmo local de armazenamento como a variável dada como argumento na invocação de método.

Parâmetros de saída são usados em métodos que retornam vários valores.

Comment: Então seria o mesmo que passar um parâmetro por referência, é isso?

Comment: Creio que sim, com a diferença que  por referência a variável tem de ser inicializada... Salvo engano...

Comment: Nem todos os parâmetros de saída são necessariamente por referência, mas é a implementação mais comum nas linguagens que são usadas na prática. Dependendo também da linguagem, é possível passar um parâmetro por referência, mas forçá-lo a ser imutável.