# Declaração de variáveis antes da função main() e depois da função main() em C

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis

Qual a diferença entre declarar uma variável qualquer (nesse caso `number`) antes da função `main()`?

```
int number = 0;

int main() {
    printf(" The number is %d\n", number);
    return (0);
}
```

e depois dela.

```
int main() {
    int number = 0;
    printf(" The number is %d\n", number);
    return(0);
}
```

Até então eu estava fazendo os exercícios de um livro sempre declarando as variáveis dentro da função `main`, mas vi agora em outro livro variáveis sendo declaradas antes.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

```
int number = 0;

int main() {
    printf(" The number is %d\n", number);
    return (0);
}
```

Aqui `number` é uma variável global. Ela tem [tempo de vida por toda aplicação e visibilidade, escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) dentro de todo o arquivo onde ela foi declarada, sendo que eventualmente ela pode ser declarada para ser incluída e acessada externamente a este arquivo, o que é pior ainda.

Isto torna o código menos legível e dificulta a manutenção. Variáveis devem ser declaradas o mais próximo possível de onde ela será necessária, deve ter o menor escopo e tempo de vida possível para economizar memória da pilha ou geral e para evitar que algo seja feito com ela inadvertidamente.

A variável ficará em uma área estática da memória e o acesso concorrente a ela será problemático.

```
int main() {
    int number = 0;
    printf(" The number is %d\n", number);
    return (0);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/EscopeVariable.c).

Aqui `number` é uma variável local que só existirá na [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) por um curto período de tempo (durante a execução da função) e não pode ser acessada fora da função.

É mais fácil acompanhar seu estado porque ela não pode ser modificada em outros pontos da aplicação. Imagine como é difícil depurar algo que pode ter seu estado alterado em vários pontos.

Na verdade as variáveis deveriam ter o escopo até menor, sempre que possível. É comum vermos em C programadores declarando todas variáveis no começo da função. Isto até era necessário no começo e tem muito exemplo assim. Mas o correto é declarar no menor escopo possível. Se tem um bloco de código e a variável ficará só dentro dele, declare ali dentro, não deixe a variável em escopo da função toda. Na verdade mesmo que não posso usar um escopo menor tem serventia declarar a variável só quando for usada mesmo, o código fica mais legível. Só não fica mais do que evitar uma variável desnecessária para o algoritmo.

Eu vejo programadores iniciantes criando variável global para não ter que passar as variáveis locais como [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para outras funções. Essencialmente é sempre um erro fazer isto. Em aplicações bem escritas podemos dizer que nunca precisamos de variáveis globais (ainda que nunca seja um exagero).

Claro que em exemplos simples assim parecem que não faz diferença, e neste não faz mesmo, mas acostume-se fazer do melhor jeito, em aplicações mais complexas é importantíssimo ter organização do código e diminuir a superfície onde pode ocorrer problemas.

Comment: Pois é, depende do foco do assunto. Em programação competitiva, os códigos são pra lá de horríveis comparando com códigos que seguem a engenharia de software. Mas isso é porque em maratonas o foco é o algoritmo e não o código.

Answer (score 3):

Não é antes ou depois, mas sim fora ou dentro do escopo da função. Fora do escopo de um função elas são chamadas de variáveis globais e são acessíveis por todas as funções do projeto.  Dentro de uma função são chamadas de variáveis locais e são acessíveis apenas à função onde ela está declarada. Por motivos de segurança procure sempre declarar as variáveis dentro de uma função e quando precisar dela em outra função passe-a por parâmetro.

Comment: Segurança não é a motivação para variáveis locais. O problema é que variáveis globais contribuem para o estado do programa a todo momento. Quanto menos estado você tem em mente quando avalia um pedaço de código (para procurar a causa de um bug, por exemplo), mais fácil e rápido fica para raciocinar sobre aquele pedaço.