# Boas práticas em declaração de variáveis em um for

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, declaração-de-variável, resharper

Ultimamente tenho feito uso do Resharper e tenho gostado da experiência em usá-lo, mas algo tem me intrigado. Em alguns momentos ele sugere que certas variáveis sejam declaradas dentro de alguns escopos, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var a = 0;    
for(var i = 0; i<=3; i++){
    a = ObterValor(); //método que retorna um inteiro qualquer;
    //... alguma operação usando a
}
```

No Resharper ele sugere que a variável `a` seja criada dentro do escopo do `for`:

```
for(var i = 0; i<=3; i++){
   var a = ObterValor(); //método que retorna um inteiro qualquer;
   //...alguma operação usando a
}
```

Porém, pelo menos para mim, parece meio estranho criar uma variável dentro de um escopo como o citado acima, uma vez que pela prática e aprendizado sempre fui orientado a criar as varáveis antes de qualquer operação. Então, para um código legível e respeitando boas práticas, seria recomendável seguir essa sugestão que o Resharper traz?

Comment: alguns podem achar que o `Resharper` torna o usuário preguiçoso e algumas vezes ele pode sugerir algo errado também, tudo leva a crer que o uso da variável `a` não teria talvez lógica em usar, tudo depende de um contexto maior e tudo depende se a variável `a` será ou não utilizado fora do `for`. Importante é manter padrão no seu código na declaração de variável  na sua disponibilidade e não depende de `plugins` para desenvolver seu código, pois, muitas vezes não será útil. Tem empresas que abominam o uso do `Resharper`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Boas práticas

Então posso dizer que ou você não entendeu o que falaram sobre a declaração de variáveis, ou te ensinaram errado, e isso ocorre muito.

Realmente vejo muita coisa que fazia sentido nos anos 60 ou 70 serem repetidas até hoje como se fossem verdades. As pessoas aprendem por receita de bolo. Ou seja, elas aprendem boas práticas e não aprendem como realmente algo funciona e porque fazer aquilo. Aprender **o porquê** é mais importante que aprender **o que**.

Há décadas havia menos de um milésimo de processamento que temos hoje e menos de um milionésimo da memória. Os compiladores precisavam ser simples. Eles evitavam trabalho difícil e obrigavam o programador ajudá-lo. Isso deixou de existir, mas o que era obrigatório virou lenda.

De fato nunca foi ideal fazer isto. É mais legível declarar a variável o mais perto possível do seu uso. Fica mais fácil acompanhar o que está fazendo.

## Menor superfície

Quanto menor o escopo, menos estrago pode fazer quando algo der errado. Quanto menos o tempo de vida, menos memória ocupa, mesmo que seja apenas um espaço da pilha.

Se uma variável não está sendo usada fora de um bloco não tem porquê ela ser declarada fora dele, não há ganho algum em fazer isso. Mesmo que fosse uma boa prática, ela deveria ser justificada, nem isso alguém consegue fazer.

Mesmo porque, respeitar boas práticas nunca deve ser o objetivo de um código. Ele funcionar corretamente, atendendo os requisitos e ser legível e fácil de dar manutenção é que deve ocorrer sempre.

[Respondi algo sobre isto em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170384/101).

## Tecnicamente pior

Note que absurdo você ter que declarar uma variável, gastar tempo para atribuir um valor para ela e pouco depois ter que atribuir outro valor e aquele primeiro ser descartado. Um `int` é simples, mas tem tipo que atribuir um valor custa bem caro. Toda vez que vejo alguém atribuindo um valor que nunca é usado eu tenho vontade de chorar.

Mesmo que não precise desta performance toda, até porque o ganho não é grande, evitar algo totalmente desnecessário não é otimizar apenas, é simplificar.

Lembrando que declarar uma variável sempre tem uma atribuição, pelo menos em C#, mesmo que implícita. Por sorte, ou azar, dependendo do ponto de vista, tipos por referência declarados, mas não atribuídos explicitamente, tem um custo bem baixo porque só tem que zerar a referência, mas não é zero, é semelhante a atribuir um inteiro.

> sempre fui orientado a criar as varáveis antes de qualquer operação

Isso é verdade, não dá para usar a variável antes de declarar :) Mas não precisa ser bem antes, pode ser logo antes.

O Resharper está muito certo nesta.

## Diferença semântica

Note que há uma diferença semântica nesses seus códigos. O primeiro cria uma variável e vai mudando o seu valor. Pode ter algum caso que queira fazer isto, mas não parece ser este caso. O segundo cria várias variáveis, uma por interação do laço. Sim, cada passagem gerará uma `a` diferente da outra.

Mas não pense que isso tem custo a mais ou ocupa mais memória, porque ela também é encerrada no fim do laço, então ela é criada de novo, em cima de onde estava a outra. Não há um custo em fazer isto, além do que teria em atribuir um valor.

Pode parecer que dá na mesma. Em geral dá mesmo, mas pelo fato de ter uma outra identidade pode ser que dê diferença real perceptível se a variável for capturada por uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101), por exemplo.

Se no laço tivesse a criação de *closures* guardadas em uma lista para posterior execução, os valores seriam diferentes. A primeira capturará a mesma variável única, portanto o valor será igual em todas as instâncias de *closures*. No segundo código, cada *closure* teria um valor diferente já que está capturando uma nova variável a cada passagem. Isso é muito importante. Acredito que nesse caso o Resharper não daria essa indicação.

Este código mostra isso:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var acoes = new List<Func<int>>();
        var a = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            a = i;
            acoes.Add(() => a * 2);
        }
        foreach (var acao in acoes) WriteLine(acao());
        acoes = new List<Func<int>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int b = i;
            acoes.Add(() => b * 2);
        }
        foreach (var acao in acoes) WriteLine(acao());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**.](https://ideone.com/HJtGu9) E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EiiYJK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/VariableInLoop.cs).

Até o C# 4 havia um *bug* no compilador e mesmo o segundo funcionava errado, igual ao primeiro.

Comment: Me ensinaram errado... e quem ensinou tinha convicção de que a sua maneira estava correta e por creditar confiança na pessoa sem usei da forma *primária*. Depois de um tempo que comecei a perceber a outra forma de declaração...

Answer (score 6):

Só pra deixar claro: não existe nenhum benefício em termos de *perfomance* nisso.

A intenção do Resharper é deixar o código mais limpo e organizado. Logo, mover a variável para escopo mais interno traz vantagens neste sentido

- Legibilidade do código. O código fica mais fácil de entender dessa maneira, se você só vai usar a variável dentro do `for`, declare-a dentro for;
- Facilidade de refatorar o código. Manter a declaração mais perto do uso faz com que seja mais simples de ser fazer uma refatoração.