# Reinicializar uma variável, ou recriá-la?

Tags: .net, vb.net, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Em termos de performance, o que é mais preferível? Existem outras diferenças entre os dois modos, a não ser performance?

**Reinicializar uma variável múltiplas vezes?**

```
Private Sub Metodo()
    Dim MeuTipo As Tipo

    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        MeuTipo = New Tipo
        MeuTipo.FacaAlgumaCoisa()
    Next
End Sub
```

Ou **recriá-la múltiplas vezes?**

```
Private Sub Metodo()    
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        Dim MeuTipo As New Tipo
        MeuTipo.FacaAlgumaCoisa()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: As duas formas são ruins, porque `MeuTipo` poderia ser instanciado uma vez fora do `for` e dentro dele chamar `FacaAlgumaCoisa()`! as duas formas criam instâncias desnecessárias a cada interação.

Comment: Entendo. E qual é a desvantagem de se ter instâncias desnecessárias a cada iteração?

Comment: Olha nesse caso especifico do exemplo do código apresentado, não há primeiramente a necessidade de ter um objeto a cada interação já visto que um Objeto da classe `MeuTipo` fornece o método `FacaAlgumaCoisa()` que é o que você precisa chamar em cada interação da estrutura de repetição. A você pode até me perguntar mais existe em algum momento que posso utilizar. Sim, tem um exemplo que me lembro agora é quando precisamos criar uma Lista de Objetos por Exemplo de MeuTipo, o primeiro código seu com um ajustes daria para empregar isso. No contexto não é necessário só utiliza memória

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu mandei gerar o código IL de ambos e obtive exatamente o mesmo código, portanto não há diferença entre eles. [Há uma pergunta sobre C# que fala mais ou menos sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170393/101).

```
  .method private static void  Metodo() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (class Tipo V_0,
             int32 V_1,
             int32 V_2,
             bool V_3)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002:  stloc.2
    IL_0003:  newobj     instance void Tipo::.ctor()
    IL_0008:  stloc.0
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  callvirt   instance void Tipo::FacaAlgumaCoisa()
    IL_000f:  nop
    IL_0010:  ldloc.2
    IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0012:  add.ovf
    IL_0013:  stloc.2
    IL_0014:  ldloc.2
    IL_0015:  ldc.i4.s   100
    IL_0017:  cgt
    IL_0019:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_001a:  ceq
    IL_001c:  stloc.3
    IL_001d:  ldloc.3
    IL_001e:  brtrue.s   IL_0003

    IL_0020:  ret
  } // end of method Module1::Metodo

  .method private static void  Metodo2() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (int32 V_0,
             int32 V_1,
             class Tipo V_2,
             bool V_3)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002:  stloc.1
    IL_0003:  newobj     instance void Tipo::.ctor()
    IL_0008:  stloc.2
    IL_0009:  ldloc.2
    IL_000a:  callvirt   instance void Tipo::FacaAlgumaCoisa()
    IL_000f:  nop
    IL_0010:  ldloc.1
    IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0012:  add.ovf
    IL_0013:  stloc.1
    IL_0014:  ldloc.1
    IL_0015:  ldc.i4.s   100
    IL_0017:  cgt
    IL_0019:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_001a:  ceq
    IL_001c:  stloc.3
    IL_001d:  ldloc.3
    IL_001e:  brtrue.s   IL_0003

    IL_0020:  ret
  } // end of method Module1::Metodo2
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ezeLI5). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AksBR2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/ForVariable.vb).