# Por que esse loop com goroutines apenas repete o último valor?

Tags: loop, golang

Este *loop* está repetindo sempre o último valor, considere o seguinte:

```
type unique struct {
    id, nonce uint64
}

func (unique *unique) print() {

    fmt.Println(unique.id)

}

func main() {

    teste := []unique{unique{1, 2}, unique{3, 4}, unique{5, 6}}

    for _, valor := range teste {

        go valor.print()

    }

    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)

}
```

É bem simplório, usando o `unique.print()` irá mostrar na tela o valor do `id`, porém isso não funciona corretamente.  Seria esperado que retornasse `1`, `3` e `5`, mas ele retorna:

```
5
5
5
```

**[Veja isto aqui](https://play.golang.org/p/J0AJtfScSQ).**

Não consigo entender o motivo disso não funcionar, porque utilizando de maneira "normal", sem o uso do *goroutines*, diretamente usando `valor.print()` [ele funciona](https://play.golang.org/p/wk9gBUpfEG).

Me parece que isto é algo relacionado ao uso do *goroutine*, porque isso ocorre?

---

*Usando:*

```
teste := []*unique{&unique{1,2}, &unique{3,4}, &unique{5, 6}}
```

*Parece corrigir o problema, mas não sei o motivo.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Já respondi sobre isto em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170396/101).

Uma Goroutine é uma chamada de um código controlada pelo *runtime* para execução assíncrona paralela ou não. Obviamente que o código ali apresentado é executado de forma preguiçosa (*lazy*), ou seja, ele será chamado em outro lugar e não ali onde você vê ele escrito. Isto é feito com alguma [mecanismo de delegação, provavelmente com um clausura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Então a variável que é enclausurada passa ter uma referência para a variável original. Quando vai executar o valor a ser usado é o valor que estiver no final do laço, então `valor` no final vale `unique{5, 6}`, os demais são ignorados. Quando usa-se a referência resolve isto.

Uma outra forma seria fazer isto sem mudar a semântica do dado:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type unique struct {
    id, nonce uint64
}

func (unique *unique) print() {
    fmt.Println(unique.id)
}

func main() {
    teste := []unique{unique{1, 2}, unique{3, 4}, unique{5, 6}}
    for _, valor := range teste {
        valorTmp := valor;
        go valorTmp.print()
    }
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/euuPe6). E [no **Playground Go**](https://play.golang.org/p/tA6M-xayMH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Closure.go).

Pra mim isso é *design* errado de linguagem. Ela deveria destacar a variável por conta própria. C# era assim e arrumaram isso, mas os *designers* de Go são muito teimosos, um dos motivos da linguagem não decolar de vez.

Comment: Javascript tem o mesmo comportamento, bastando apenas capturar a variável. Desde que a regra seja clara (e é), eu não vejo nada de especial nisso.