# Ficar criando variáveis locais o tempo todo gera custo a mais para o software?

Tags: c#, variáveis, loop, escopo-de-variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Fiz um programa do qual ele escreve em variáveis o tempo todo, e com isso me gerou uma dúvida, instanciar uma variável o tempo todo gera mais custo do que só atribuir o valor a uma variável já existente?

#### Exemplos:

Instanciando uma variável o tempo todo:

```
while (true)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 30;
    int z = x + y;
}
```

Utilizando uma variável já existente:

```
int x, y, z;
while (true)
{
    x = 10;
    y = 30;
    z = x + y;
}
```

Esses exemplos são só para melhorar a ilustração do problema. O programa do qual irei aplicar isso é bem maior e usa muito mais variáveis.

> Pensei já ter visto uma pergunta dessa há algum tempo, mas hoje que
>  eu precisava dessa resposta, não a achei. Caso você a encontre-a,
>  sinta-se livre para marcar esta pergunta como duplicada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nesse exemplo dá no mesmo, [tem exemplo que existe uma mudança semântica importante e o código dará resultados diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170393/101).

Mas falando de custo, não faz diferença. Primeiro que o espaço de variável só existe para ela. Na variável é reservado espaço suficiente para caber o dado de seu tipo e nada mais, não importa quantas vezes ela seja modificada ou onde ou a forma como foi declarada, só existe aquele espaço.

Como nota lateral, se a variável for por referência cada atribuição nova provavelmente gerará um objeto novo, caso contrário fica sem sentido, e isso vai inchando o *heap* e coloca pressão no GC, o que não é o ideal, mas se precisa atribuir novos objetos não tem o que fazer.

Do ponto de vista de processamento também não faz diferença, a declaração de variável é o que chamamos de *no-op*. Então declarar fora não traz ganhos porque o custo de declarar dentro também é zero.

A declaração da variável no fundo ocorre no início do *stack frame*, ou seja, quando começa um escopo todo espaço necessário é reservado de uma vez, não importa onde foi declarado. Pode mudar o momento da reserva, mas só uma vez sempre. A declaração de todas variáveis daquele novo escopo ocorre com uma mudança de um ponteiro (*stack pointer*), sequer importa se é uma variável ou milhares delas, o custo é o mesmo, só há uma alteração no SP.

Já a atribuição sempre tem custo, a não ser que o compilador consiga determinar que ela pode ser apagada. E o código do exemplo tem chance de nem ocorrer já que está fazendo a mesma coisa e acho que é possível provar que não faz sentido ficar reatribuindo o mesmo valor sem parar, então esse código poderia ser escrito como:

```
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 30;
    int z = x + y;
    while (true);
}
```

Na verdade o compilador não faz:

```
//reservando espaço para as variáveis
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    [0] int32
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 10
IL_0002: ldc.i4.s 30
IL_0004: stloc.0
IL_0005: pop
IL_0006: br.s IL_0000
```

[Veja como ficou no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQYQQbwLACgEFKIwAsCAsgBQCUWehDCA7gBaQCmClwATgK7taOfI1FgAdsAQAPBAF4EARgAMAbnqjGEqQE95COGo2bC2hAC99sgNQId6kaIC+xhC8dEkZcshp0PDGbSADR2oeYOJqwcXLwCQq4msgoqkSaEegqGaekWVgi29omE7gzuTkA). Inclusive que gera exatamente o mesmo código.

Mas o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) faz até mais já que nada é usado, ele elimina quase todo o código deixando só o movimento do *stack frame* e laço no mesmo lugar:

```
L0000: push ebp     //protege o BP
L0001: mov ebp, esp //só move o SP para o Base Pointer
L0003: jmp L0103    //fica repetindo sem parar
```

[Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgZgARwExIMJIN4FgBQSRKycALEgLIAUAlDgcU0gO4AWAlgDYCmS1wAE4BXHvTyFmUjgDtgSAB5IAvEgCMABgDcjKc1nyAniqQJtuvcQNIAXiaUBqJIZ2SpAXwtJPbkigqUqHQMvkzWCgA0zlE2rpbs3HwCImIhlkxKqppx6UTGqmY5uXaqjs5FzD5MPu5AA).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).