# C# - OutOfMemoryException ao buscar milhares de grupos do Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, active-directory

Estou buscando milhares de grupos com centenas de usuários cada do Active Directory, mas está consumindo muita memória. Começa com mais ou menos 300 MB e quando chega a mais ou menos 1800 MB, visto no gerenciador de tarefa, é lançado um OutOfMemoryException. A exceção é lançada quando está sendo executada essa parte do código.

```
foreach (string objectGUID in listGroups)
{
    GroupDTO objGroup = new GroupDTO();

    objGroup = ADHelper.GetGroupByGUID(objectGUID, domainInfo.GeneratePathOfDomainObj(domainInfo.RootDN), domainInfo.UserName, domainInfo.Password, domainInfo.AuthType, new string[] { "distinguishedname", "name", "objectGUID", "samaccountname", "mail", "description", "whenchanged", "grouptype", "primaryGroupToken" });

    List listUsersGroup = new List();

    //Uma lista com todos os ID (ObjectGUID) do grupo atual
    listUsersGroup = ADHelper.GetUsersFromGroup(objectGUID, domainInfo.GeneratePathOfDomainObj(domainInfo.RootDN), domainInfo.UserName, domainInfo.Password, domainInfo.AuthType, new string[] { "objectguid" }, domainInfo.PropertiesGroupsAndUsers, domainInfo.RootDN);

    Dictionary dicGroup = new Dictionary();
    string jSonGroup = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objGroup);
    dicGroup.Add("group", jSonGroup);
    dicGroup.Add("lstUser", listUsersGroup); 

    arrayListGroups.Add(dicGroup);
}
```

Comment: Precisa ver se tem outras coisas complicado além disso e só aí estoura. Mas pode ser aí mesmo. Não tem milagre. Está usando 32bits? O limite é mais ou menos este mesmo. Será que precisa de tudo isso junto?

Comment: Segmente sua implementacão, via unidade lógica, blocos ou páginas. Trabalhe com subsets, por exemplo grupo a grupo. Não carregue tudo na memória ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Esse trecho do código é do método ImportGroups(listGroups). Eu já tentei repartir o listGroups em quatro partes mais ou menos iguais e executar ImportGroups(listGroups) para cada uma dessas partes. Tentei até repartindo 10 partes e executando, uma por vez, o ImportGroups(), mas sempre a memória vai subindo absurdamente até atingir uns 1800 MB ~ 2000 MB no Gerenciador de Tarefas e dar OutOfMemoryException (Sou estagiário, então me perdoe se estiver fazendo besteiras absurdas).

Comment: Foi resolvido. O problema era dentro do método GetUsersFromGroup() que instanciava uma classe que recebia resultados de busca no AD sem um Dispose() acumulando recursos indefinidamente na memória. Obrigado pelas respostas :)

Answer (score 0):

Já tive problemas de OutOfMemoryException, Resolvi colocando os objetos fora do loop, assim:

```
GroupDTO objGroup;
List listUsersGroup;
Dictionary dicGroup;
foreach (string objectGUID in listGroups)
{
    objGroup = new GroupDTO();

    objGroup = ADHelper.GetGroupByGUID(objectGUID, domainInfo.GeneratePathOfDomainObj(domainInfo.RootDN), domainInfo.UserName, domainInfo.Password, domainInfo.AuthType, new string[] { "distinguishedname", "name", "objectGUID", "samaccountname", "mail", "description", "whenchanged", "grouptype", "primaryGroupToken" });

    listUsersGroup = new List();

    //Uma lista com todos os ID (ObjectGUID) do grupo atual
    listUsersGroup = ADHelper.GetUsersFromGroup(objectGUID, domainInfo.GeneratePathOfDomainObj(domainInfo.RootDN), domainInfo.UserName, domainInfo.Password, domainInfo.AuthType, new string[] { "objectguid" }, domainInfo.PropertiesGroupsAndUsers, domainInfo.RootDN);

    dicGroup = new Dictionary();
    string jSonGroup = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objGroup);
    dicGroup.Add("group", jSonGroup);
    dicGroup.Add("lstUser", listUsersGroup); 

    arrayListGroups.Add(dicGroup);
}
```

Comment: Vi essa resposta do bigown: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225192/ficar-criando-vari%C3%A1veis-locais-o-tempo-todo-gera-custo-a-mais-para-o-software/225196#225196 mas não sei se aplica à objetos