# Existe algo em ADVPL equivalente a função lambda do Java?

Tags: advpl, função-anônima

Estou dando manutenção em um projeto ADVPL. Nele, tenho alguns arquivos fonte. Entre esses fontes, eu tenho um minerador de informação no arquivo GEO1 e um comunicador das informações mineradas no arquivo GEO3.

No funcionamento inicial, as cargas eram baixas e primeiro se fazia toda a extração para, só então, comunicar ao sistema externo sobre essas mudanças. Acontece que essa carga inicial é maior do que o esperado inicialmente, então estou refatorando o sistema para, durante a extração, executar o envio.

Se fosse algo em Java, que eu tenho mais costume, faria uma abordagem mais funcional, passando um Consumer para o meu extrator. Seria como se o seguinte fosse o código original:

```java
class Minerador {
  public List<InformacaoMinerada> mineraInformacoes() {
    List<InformacaoMinerada> info = new ArrayList<>();

    while (temInformacaoMineravel()) {
      info.add(minerarProximaInformacao());
    }

    return info;
  }
  private InformacaoMinerada minerarProximaInformacao() {
    // código de mineração que posso desconhecer, lei de Deméter
    ...
    return stuff;
  }
}

class Comunicador {
  public void enviaDados(List<InformacaoMinerada> informacoes) {
    // detalhes internos do envio
  }
}

class Principal {
  public static void main() {
    Minerador miner = getMiner();
    Comunicador mercurio = getComunicador();

    mercurio.enviaDados(miner.mineraInformacoes());
  }

  public static Minerador getMiner() {
    // inicia o minerador corretamente
    return miner;
  }

  public static Comunicador getComunicador() {
    // inicia o minerador corretamente
    return comunicador;
  }
}
```

Na transformação, eu faria com que o comunicador fosse avisado que há uma nova informação e, de acordo com um threshold, enviaria a informação recebida:

```java
class Minerador {
  public void mineraInformacoes(Consumer<InformacaoMinerada> consumidorInformacao) {
    List<InformacaoMinerada> info = new ArrayList<>();

    while (temInformacaoMineravel()) {
      consumidorInformacao.accept(minerarProximaInformacao());
    }
  }

  private InformacaoMinerada minerarProximaInformacao() {
    // código de mineração que posso desconhecer, lei de Deméter
    ...
    return stuff;
  }
}

class Comunicador {
  private List<InformacaoMinerada> informacoesBufferizadas;
  private int threshold;

  public void enviaDadosBufferizados() {
    if (informacoesBufferizadas.size() > 0) {
      enviaDados(informacoesBufferizadas);
      informacoesBufferizadas.clear();
    }
  }

  public void adicionaInformacao(InformacaoMinerada info) {
    informacoesBufferizadas.add(info);
    if (informacoesBufferizadas.size() >= threshold) {
      enviaDadosBufferizados();
    }
  }

  private void enviaDados(List<InformacaoMinerada> informacoes) {
    // detalhes internos do envio, mesmo código da enviaDados antiga
  }
}

class Principal {
  public static void main() {
    Minerador miner = getMiner();
    Comunicador mercurio = getComunicador();

    miner.mineraInformacoes(mercurio::adicionaInformacao);

    // para eventual envio de dados residuais
    mercurio.enviaDadosBufferizados();
  }

  public static Minerador getMiner() {
    // inicia o minerador corretamente
    return miner;
  }

  public static Comunicador getComunicador() {
    // inicia o minerador corretamente
    return comunicador;
  }
}
```

Existe algo equivalente a essa função lambda no ADVPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe algo chamado Code Block, que é inclusive uma clausura também (com os [mesmos problemas que a maioria das linguagens possuem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170396/101) quando rodam em cenários como um laço por exemplo). A ideia é justamente essa, mas o funcionamento interno é péssimo.

Já existe isso desde o Clipper e lá era bem implementado. No Harbour foram até um pouco à frente e criaram uma referência para os casos mais simples que não precisam de clausura, dando mais eficiência. No fundo era um ponteiro, por isso até chamam o tipo de `Pointer`, embora tecnicamente seja uma referência (assim como eles chamam da `Hash` um tipo que tem duas implementações distintas no mesmo tipo, é um pavor, e nenhuma das duas é um *hash*e já viu que eles não são bons em dar nomes pras coisas).

Clipper sempre teve uma coisa chamada macro, porque dBase tinha, e no dBase era obrigatório porque não tinha os mecanismos mais corretos. Clipper criou esses mecanismos melhores, mas manteve a macro pra dar compatibilidade. Ela é basicamente um compilador, ela pode gerar execução a partir de um texto. Algo como um [`eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101). Usa-se com um "operador" `&`. Imagina que ele é bem lento e suscetível a erros, sem falar na insegurança. Por isso o bloco de código foi criado. Mas ADVPL criou só a macro, e para manter a compatibilidade com a sintaxe de Code Block eles transformaram ela em macro internamente, ou seja, a performance é sofrível.

Funciona assim:

```
aArray := { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
nValor := 5
Scan(aArray, {|i| conout(i + nValor) })

user function Scan(aArray, bAction) {
    for i := 0 to len(aArray)
        eval(bAction)
    next
return nil
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLCodeBlock.prx).

Imprimirá de 5 à 8.

Neste caso usei clausura no `nValor`, mas não é necessário se não tem necessidade. Use com parcimônia, foi só para dar um exemplo completo.

Answer (score 1):

Existe, se chama bloco de código (*code block*).

Pode ser visto um uso do bloco de código no exemplo a seguir:

```
// arquivo Test1.prw

static function apendar(aArray, cStr)
  // se o threshold for 2:
  if len(aArray) >= 2
    msgInfo('fazendo a chamado do threshold e limpando o vetor')
    aArray := {}
  endif

  aAdd(aArray, cStr)
return

user function principal()
  local aVetor := {}
  local cVetorLegivel := ''
  local i

  u_fext('1', {|cStr| apendar(aVetor, cStr)})
  u_fext('2', {|cStr| apendar(aVetor, cStr)})
  u_fext('3', {|cStr| apendar(aVetor, cStr)})
  u_fext('4', {|cStr| apendar(aVetor, cStr)})

 for i := 1 to len(aVetor)
   cVetorLegivel  += aVetor[i] + ','
 next i
 MsgInfo(cVetorLegivel)
return
```

```
// arquivo Test2.prw

user function fext(cStr, bBloco)
  eval(bBloco, cStr)
  MsgInfo(cStr)
return
```

Note que a função `fext` desconhece totalmente a implementação de `bBloco`, porém é capaz de chamá-la corretamente através do `eval`.

Fiz testes passando o primeiro argumento de `apendar` tanto com a referência da variável `aVetor` como usando-a diretamente e os resultados foram iguais:

```
// bloco de código usando `aVetor` diretamente
{|cStr| apendar(aVetor, cStr)}

// bloco de código usando a referência a `aVetor`
{|cStr| apendar(@aVetor, cStr)}
```