# Por que está sobrando um asterisco?

Tags: c, loop, lógica

Quero que, na saída do meu programa, o número de fileiras e colunas seja igual ao *input* dado. Por que está sobrando este último `*`?

Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int row = 0;
char column = 0;
int n;


int main ( void )
{
    printf("TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while ( column <= n ){
        printf("*");
        column = column + 1;

        if ( column == n ){
            printf("\n");
            row = row + 1;
            column = column - n;
        }
        else if ( row == n ){
            break; }

    }
}
```

Saída:

```
TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT
4
****
****
****
****
*
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu não vou nem tentar resolver o problema nesse código porque ele é confuso demais e talvez o problema tenha nascido da confusão. Quanto mais simples puder fazer, melhor. Mesmo que queira aprender algum conceito específico com este tipo de código, é melhor aprender em um caso onde ele seria necessário. Se alguém pediu para fazer desta forma, a pessoa fez um desserviço para você. Seria um requisito inútil e improdutivo. e eu argumentaria que essa forma é desvantajosa.

[Não declare variáveis fora da função sem necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170324/101). Declare sempre o mais próximo possível de onde será usada. Tem gente que não vê o valor disto, mas cria uma capacidade cognitiva maior para fazer coisas mais simples. [Se precisa da variável apenas dentro do laço, crie ela dentro do laço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170393/101).

Se você tem dois vetores a serem considerados, crie dois laços, é a forma natural de se fazer isto. Está é a [forma estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101) de fazer este código. O original dá nó na cabeça. Inclusive um laço `for` é muito mais natural para o caso.

Havia uma variável da coluna do tipo `char`. Ou faz a linha também ser `char` e limita o número de asteriscos em 127 ou deixa `int` em ambos. Eu deixei `int` porque não há ganho real em usar `char` aí, mesmo que só queira valores baixos, o que na verdade nem é validado, até porque [o `scanf()` nem é muito adequado para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168882/101). Seja consistente.

Dei uma organizada. É muito difícil entender o que o código faz na forma escrita.

Feito isso o código fica simples demais.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT: \n");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YRqe6k). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DrawSquarec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/DrawSquare.c).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! sou iniciante e estou aprendendo por conta própria, seus conselhos irão me ajudar bastante... eu mesmo percebi que " esteticamente" estava estranho o que eu tinha feito, mas não sabia fazer de outra forma, infelizmente...

Answer (score 4):

A cada "loop" do while, você primeiro printa o * e depois checa se chegou no limite (row == n). Simplesmente coloque o print abaixo dos checks de fim do loop que o seu problema se resolve.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int row = 0;
char column = 0;
int n;


int main ( void )
{
    printf("TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while ( column <= n ){

        column = column + 1;

        if ( column == n ){
            printf("\n");
            row = row + 1;
            column = column - n;
        }
        else if ( row == n ){
            break; }

        printf("*");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O código da pergunta não leva em consideração que, nesse algoritmo, o valor de `row` muda com menos frequência que o de `column`. Assim sendo, seria melhor usar um par de loops aninhados ao invés da lógica atual.

Alguns outros conselhos:

- Evite dar `#include` em cabeçalhos se você não vai usar as funções.
- Quando executar uma função do tipo `scanf()`, sempre verifique o valor retornado para ter certeza de que a execução foi bem sucedida.
- Use comentários para deixar suas intenções no código mais clara para quem estiver lendo.
- Mantenha um padrão consistente de indentação:

  - Suba um nível depois de cada `{`
  - Desça um nível depois de cada `}`
- Também é *aconselhável* evitar variáveis globais, na maioria dos casos. E também inicializar suas variáveis locais.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <math.h>

// usar um valor definido dá significado à "números mágicos" no seu código
// e facilita mudar os valores mais tarde, se necessário
#define MAX_COLUMNS (80)

int main ( void )
{
    size_t n = 0;  

    printf("TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT: \n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%lu", &n) )  // se um valor < 0 não for permitido, use unsigned int
    {
        perror( "scanf não registrou um unsigned int" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // else implícito, com scanf bem-sucedido

    // verifique o valor de entrada. Nunca confie que o usuário sabe o que está fazendo
    if( MAX_COLUMNS < n )
    {
        printf( "O valor de entrada deve ser %lu. Você usou: %lu\n", (size_t)MAX_COLUMNS, n );;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // else implícito, valor inserido menor que o máximo permitido

    for( size_t row = 0; row < n; row++ )
    {
        for( size_t column = 0; column < n; column++ )
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
} // fim de função: main
```

Esta é a saída gerada:

```
TELL ME THE NUMBER YOU WANT: 
4
****
****
****
****
```

Comment: Traduzi o post para o Português mas devo dizer que, assim como na pergunta, não sei muito bem como me sinto à respeito dos trechos em inglês no código (dentro dos `printfs`, por exemplo). Por isso traduzi aqui os novos, e deixei alguns antigos que já estavam na pergunta