# Sobre a passagem de parâmetros em linguagens de programação compiladas

Tags: c, funções, parâmetros, pascal

O que seria mais vantajoso ao chamar uma função, colocar na pilha da direita para esquerda ou vice-versa? E a limpeza da pilha? A função que chama (*caller*) ou a que é chamada (*calee*) deve ficar responsável por isso?

Meus dois centavos:

Quando a função que chama fica responsável por limpar a pilha, é possível a criação de funções com a quantidade de parâmetros variáveis, pois não é necessário saber tal quantidade antes do tempo de execução, sendo somente necessário alguma lógica a mais. (ex: `printf`)

Em relação a ordem em que se põe o argumentos na pilha, da esquerda pra direita permite que os primeiros argumentos sejam usados para determinar a quantidade de argumentos que a função vai receber, no entanto, isto é possível na outra ordem colocando tal informação nos últimos argumentos, sendo então uma questão de convenção, somente.

Algum complemento ou correção?

Comment: Está confuso de entender sua dúvida e, isso é uma pergunta? Você mesmo parece estar tentando responder...

Comment: Desculpem se está confuso... sim, estou tentando responder, é uma questão de prova, mas percebo que pode ser complexo a reposta, depende de o quanto quem vai corrigir a questão quiser aprofundar nos detalhes. Estou tentando não fazer afirmações na resposta, mas apontar o que usualmente acontece na maioria dos compiladores, arquiteturas, convenções etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que seria mais vantajoso ao chamar uma função, colocar na pilha da direita para esquerda ou vice-versa?

Se entendi o que deseja saber, no seu código, de uma maneira geral, faz pouca diferença como coloca. É interessante se preocupar com isso só por causa de alguma otimização para alguma situação específica, afinal tem [convenção de chamada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) que colocar os primeiros parâmetros diretamente em registrador, se possível.

Estamos falando de qual arquitetura? Pode variar. O que pode ficar bom em uma pode não ser o melhor em outra. Até como compila pode variar. Na verdade está falando de duas linguagens e isso muda também. Pode variar de acordo com a API que está usando.

Note que há uma diferença entre você escrever seu código e o que o compilador fará. E o que o compilador tomará uma decisão de acordo com a convenção padrão ou outra se o código indicar isto.

C costuma usar da direita para a esquerda. Pascal costuma usar da esquerda para a direita. Mas não é problema do seu código, a não ser que precise interoperar ou precise de otimização extrema.

Note que a convenção típica da linguagem não precisa ser necessariamente a usada nele, e nem é exclusiva dela.

Se não está pensando em otimização, não importa como coloca os argumentos.

> E a limpeza da pilha? A função que chama (*caller*) ou a que é chamada (*calee*) deve ficar responsável por isso?

Depende da convenção usada, pode ser responsabilidade de ambas, cada uma cuida de uma parte, que é o caso da [`cdecl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), embora estritamente se considere que é a chamadora que é responsável.

Boa parte das convenções deixam a função chamada tratar da preservação e limpeza dos registradores, incluindo o ponteiro para a pilha, o que tende deixar o código mais eficiente, com a [`stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall).

> Quando a função que chama fica responsável por limpar a pilha, é possível a criação de funções com a quantidade de parâmetros variáveis

Na verdade é possível ter quantidade variável de [argumentos, não de parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Fora algo que eu não sei ou não tenha me atentado ou entendido na pergunta, o resto parece correto.

Comment: É uma questão que tenho que resolver de uma prova e que está aberta a muitas interpretações, pois tudo pode influenciar: a linguagem, a  arquitetura, a convenção utilizada e a própria interpretação da convenção utilizada, como ocorre com cdecl, por parte do compilador escolhido.  Conclusão: usualmente, o "cleanup" pela função que chama é mais vantajoso por possibilitar argumentos variáveis, mas pode ser aberto a interpretação pelo fato de um stdcall, por exemplo, ser mais eficiente e a ordem de inserção não importa. É uma questão de uma cadeira de microcontroladores com um professor casca...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Não é fácil responder algo complexo aqui, ainda mais sem detalhes.

Comment: Pois então! Não existem muitos detalhes, infelizmente! A questão simplesmente afirma que *usualmente* C usa uma convenção e pascal usa outra e pergunta qual convenção é mais vantajosa e o porquê. Visto que a própria questão não entrega tantos detalhes, acho que a resposta deve ser escrita se baseando no que se é esperado *usualmente*. Então vim aqui pedir ajuda para saber se minhas afirmações tem algum fundamento ou não, junto de uma possível correção.

Comment: Sem detalhes a pergunta tende ficar baseada em opiniões e sequer dá para responder, não há critérios claros. Pode ser que dê com o que foi passado em aula, mas não temos essa informação.

Comment: O pior que nem foi passado em aula, e não tem muito haver com a disciplina, mas acho que esse assunto não é de muito interesse da comunidade stackoverflow, de qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda. abs