# Diferença de parâmetros em Python

Tags: python, parâmetros

Em Python, qual a diferença entre `Funcao(param='value')` e `Funcao(value)`? Ou ainda `Funcao(u'value')`?

Estou começando com Python e já vi códigos com essas três formas. Não sei se eram funções ou métodos, mas levei tudo como função, para constar.

Comment: Pode esclarecer se a sua dúvida consiste na definição de uma função ou se é na chamada da mesma? E onde viu este `p'value'`? Particularmente eu desconheço este prefixo. Existem os `u`, `r`, `f` e `b` que conheço, mas `p` nunca vi. Inclusive o `p` nem consta na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  Era u, mas coloquei p pois achei que fosse nomeado aleatoriamente. Vou corrigir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Funcao(param = 'value')
```

é uma função que tem um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) padrão, ou seja, se o argumento não for passado na chamada de `Funcao`, o valor `'value'` será atribuído para o parâmetro `param`.

```
Funcao(value)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/DefaultArgument.py).

Neste caso o parâmetro chama `value`, ele está no lugar de de `param`, no fundo parâmetros são variáveis locais, a única diferença é que elas serão inicializadas na chamada da função. Neste se não passar um argumento na chamada de `Funcao` a variável `value` terá um valor nulo ([`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)).

Pode estar usando em outro contexto e aí `value` pode ser uma variável chamada `value` que está sendo passada para `Funcao()` como argumento.

`Funcao(u'value')` é uma *string* em codificação Unicode, nada a ver com o parâmetro, mas é um argumento sendo passado, isso não pode ser a declaração da função, tem que ser a chamada.

Sem o contexto em cada um não dá para ter certeza então dei as opções.

Comment: Acho que o contexto da pergunta, mesmo não claro, é na chamada da função, sendo diferenciado entre parâmetros posicionais e parâmetros nomeados.

Comment: Pode ser, vamos ver o que ele fala.

Comment: É, pelo visto era na definição da função mesmo.

Comment: O `u'texto'` é uma representação de uma string em unicode, mas desconheço também nessa notação na função https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings