# Como criar um parâmetro opcional em ADVPL?

Tags: parâmetros, advpl

Em diversas funções documentadas pela Totvs há parâmetros opcionais. Gostaria de criar um parâmetro opcional em minha função, como fazer?

Estou querendo fazer com que a função `updEnvio` receba um vetor (de `recno`s) como parâmetro opcional.

```
User Function updEnvio(cTabela)
    Local cSQL := ""
    Local cCampo := IIF(SUBS(cTabela,1,1)=='S', SUBS(cTabela,2,2), cTabela)
    Local nStatus := 0

    cSQL := ""
    cSQL += " UPDATE " + RetSqlName(cTabela)
    cSQL += " SET " + cCampo + "_YGSENV = 'S' "
    cSQL += " WHERE 1=1 "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_FILIAL = '" + xFilial(cTabela) + "' "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_YGSENV <> 'S' "

    nStatus := TcSqlExec(cSQL)

    If (nStatus < 0)
        conout("Oops, TCSQLError: " + TCSQLError())
    Endif
Return
```

A grosso modo, queria transformá-la de modo que, se o vetor estivesse vazio, ela atualizasse toda a tabela; porém, se tivesse conteúdo, apenas os elementos cujos `recno`s estejam descritos nesse vetor. Usando a lógica C++ de ser, eu escreveria o valor padrão do parâmetro em sua declaração. Então, meu pseudocódigo ADVPL fica assim:

```
User Function updEnvio(cTabela, aRecnos := {})
    Local cSQL := ""
    Local cCampo := IIF(SUBS(cTabela,1,1)=='S', SUBS(cTabela,2,2), cTabela)
    Local nStatus := 0
    Local i

    cSQL := ""
    cSQL += " UPDATE " + RetSqlName(cTabela)
    cSQL += " SET " + cCampo + "_YGSENV = 'S' "
    cSQL += " WHERE 1=1 "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_FILIAL = '" + xFilial(cTabela) + "' "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_YGSENV <> 'S' "

    If LEN(aRecnos) > 0
      cSql += " AND R_E_C_N_O_ IN ("
      cSql += STR(aRecnos[1])
      For i := 2 to len(aRecnos)
        cSql += "," + STR(aRecnos[i])
      Next i
      cSql += ")"
    Endif

    nStatus := TcSqlExec(cSQL)

    If (nStatus < 0)
        conout("Oops, TCSQLError: " + TCSQLError())
    Endif
Return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes vamos adotar uma nomenclatura correta: [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Parâmetro nunca são opcionais, ou eles existem ou não existem, não é como em JavaScript. Argumentos podem ser opcionais. E o que quer saber é se os parâmetros podem ter seus valores inicializados se o argumento referente a ele não for a passado.

Não é possível com esta sintaxe, a linguagem não dá suporte ao que deseja na pergunta. Ela tem um truque para facilitar o que deseja (por sinal foi eu que criei isso nela em 1994 e até hoje é da mesma forma, um recursos de `include`) usando `default`.

```
User Function updEnvio(cTabela, aRecnos)
    Local cSQL := ""
    Local cCampo := IIF(SUBS(cTabela,1,1)=='S', SUBS(cTabela,2,2), cTabela)
    Local nStatus := 0
    Local i
    Default aRecnos := {}

    cSQL := ""
    cSQL += " UPDATE " + RetSqlName(cTabela)
    cSQL += " SET " + cCampo + "_YGSENV = 'S' "
    cSQL += " WHERE 1=1 "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_FILIAL = '" + xFilial(cTabela) + "' "
    cSQL += " AND " + cCampo + "_YGSENV <> 'S' "

    If LEN(aRecnos) > 0
      cSql += " AND R_E_C_N_O_ IN ("
      cSql += STR(aRecnos[1])
      For i := 2 to len(aRecnos)
        cSql += "," + STR(aRecnos[i])
      Next i
      cSql += ")"
    Endif

    nStatus := TcSqlExec(cSQL)

    If (nStatus < 0)
        conout("Oops, TCSQLError: " + TCSQLError())
    Endif
Return
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLDefault.prx).

Com o `default` o valor só será atribuído se não vier nada como parâmetro. Ou seja, pegaram o que eu criei e transformaram em sintaxe oficial, quando na verdade tinha uma sintaxe óbvia melhor quando resolveram colocar na linguagem.

Como curiosidade abra o arquivo `protheus.ch` que você tem acesso para fazer personalização e procure o trecho (pra não falar que é idêntico ao que eu fiz, eu usava `Iif()` sempre para não confundir visualmente com um comando `If` com parênteses):

```
#xcommand DEFAULT <uVar1> := <uVal1> ;
      [, <uVarN> := <uValN> ] => ;
    <uVar1> := If( <uVar1> == nil, <uVal1>, <uVar1> ) ;;
   [ <uVarN> := If( <uVarN> == nil, <uValN>, <uVarN> ); ]
```

Uma curiosidade que poucos sabem é que dá pra usar o pré-processador, que é bem mais poderoso que o de C, e criar argumentos nomeados, que acabam sendo até mais úteis porque em essência a linguagem não trabalha com objetos (tem uma implementação muito ruim e ineficiente, então evita-se o uso).

Comment: Quando o workaround vira sintaxe oficial

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei, de fato ainda é o que eu tinha criado :D

Answer (score -1):

Em ADVPL os parâmetros de uma função são opcionais. Parâmetros não fornecidos vêm com valor `nil`.

Exemplo:

```
#include "protheus.ch"

user function test(xParm)
  if xParm != nil
    conout("xParm=" + xParm)
  else
    conout("nao recebeu parametros!")
  end if

  return
```

That's it.