# É obrigatório colocar os mesmos atributos em construtores diferentes?

Tags: java, parâmetros, construtor, campos

Eu tenho estes construtores:

//1º Construtor - Criar mota com um novo quadro

```
public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, float peso, int robustez) { 
    //Nivel 2
    this.marca = validarMarca(marca);
    this.modelo = validarModelo(modelo);
    this.quadro = new Quadro(peso, robustez);
}

//2º Construtor - Criar mota com um quadro existente
public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, Quadro quadro) { 
    //Nivel 2
    this.marca = validarMarca(marca);
    this.modelo = validarModelo(modelo);
    this.quadro = quadro;
}

//3º Construtor - Criar mota com um novo quadro, que tem cor
public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, float peso, int robustez, Cor cor) {
    //Nivel 3
    this.marca = validarMarca(marca);
    this.modelo = validarModelo(modelo);
    this.quadro = new Quadro (peso, robustez, cor);
}

//4º Construtor - Criar mota com um quadro existente e um numero de quilometros
public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, int quilometragem, int numeroRevisoes, Quadro quadro) {
    //Nivel 4
    this.marca = validarMarca(marca);
    this.modelo = validarModelo(modelo);
    this.quilometragem = quilometragem; //se for uma mota e segunda-mão, os quilometros não seram 0.
    this.numeroRevisoes = 0;
    this.quadro = quadro;
```

Quando criamos um atributo novo, por exemplo quilometragem, é obrigatório colocá-lo nos outros construtores criados anteriormente ou é opcional?

É que na solução deste exercício cada vez que meu professor cria um novo atributo ele o coloca em todos os construtores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É a resposta de sempre: depende.

Antes da gente começar tenho que mostrar algumas respostas para usarmos os termos corretos aqui:

- [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)

Aí você precisa entender [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Só aí podemos analisar se deve ou não colocar parâmetros quando adiciona um campo novo.

Esses dados são obrigatórios em todos os objetos desse tipo? Se são não tem nem o que pensar. Se não são então provavelmente eles deveriam ser adicionados depois que a instância foi criada. Mas nem sempre, pode ser que compense ter construtores de conveniência.

Se você mexe demais em classes pode estar arrumando dor de cabeça para dar manutenção em toda aplicação.

Engenharia de software não é seguir fórmulas, é entender o problema e fazer o que for mais adequado para aquele caso. Sem entender o problema, sem analisar os requisitos não é possível afirmar se deve ou não colocar um parâmetro novo. Sem saber como provavelmente essa classe será consumida não dá para afirmar se o que deve criar apenas para conveniência.

O perfil deste código dá a entender que eles nem todos são tão necessários, mas não posso garantir. É estranho que cada construtor tenha um conjunto diferente de parâmetros quase completamente isolados. Não sei, isso parece algum erro conceitual, afinal cada objeto pode ser muito diferente do outro, começa não fazer sentido, então talvez o problema não seja só o construtor, mas toda classe ter problemas. Com uma descrição melhor do problema eu poderia falar com mais propriedade.

Claro, o professor pode estar querendo só passar o mecanismo do construtor, sem se atentar para o conceito correto. Mas não gosto disso, eu vejo que as pessoas começam aprender o conceito errado e nunca mais conserta. Estou só especulando sobre a situação real.

Obrigatório não é, mas não sei se faz sentido nesse caso. Tem que ter um motivo para criar construtores tão diferentes.

Não responde o que foi perguntado, porque o AP quer saber de construtores heterogêneos, e não encadeamento de construtor com os mesmos parâmetros, mas seria bom dar uma olhada na resposta do Gustavo Fragoso que é possível evitar duplicação de código. E não é só para escrever menos, é para ficar mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Tem uma prática muito comum que é utilizada nessas situações: usar a palavra-chave `this()`, que representa o construtor da própria classe, e preencher o construtor mais genérico com valores default. Veja o exemplo para ficar mais claro:

```
public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, float peso, int robustez) { 
    // Preenche o construtor mais genérico com valores padrão
    this(marca, modelo, peso, 0, 0, robustez, null, Color.BLACK);
}

public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, Quadro quadro) { 
    // Preenche o construtor mais genérico com valores padrão
}

public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, float peso, int robustez, Cor cor) {
    // Preenche o construtor mais genérico com valores padrão    
}

public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, int quilometragem, int numeroRevisoes, Quadro quadro) {
    // Preenche o construtor mais genérico com valores padrão
}

public Motociclo (String marca, String modelo, float peso, int quilometragem, int numeroRevisoes, int robustez, Quadro quadro, Cor cor) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.quilometragem = quilometragem;
    this.numeroRevisoes = revisoes;
    this.robustez = robustez;
    this.quadro = quadro;
    this.cor = cor;
}
```

O Java vai saber qual construtor usar e seus valores não ficarão sem ser preenchidos, o que evita NPE indesejados.

Comment: Apenas como nomenclatura, essa técnica tem um nome: _constructor chaining_ (encadeamento de construtores).

Comment: Neste caso o polimorfismo nao tem parte no assunto. É mais por conta do "overloading".

Answer (score 4):

É opcional. Só é obrigatório quando você coloca ele como parâmetro. Você pode ter um construtor vazio e atribuir valores aos atributos chamando a variável + método set.
Exemplo:

```
Motociclo m = new Motociclo()
m.setMarca("Honda");
m.setModelo("CB500F");
```

etc...

Comment: Então no meu caso é obrigatório porque eu tenho o atributos quilometragem declarado como variável da minha classe certo??

Comment: Não exatamente. Você pode criar um motociclo com algum dos construtores que vc já tem e depois atribuir valor aos outros atributos. Ex: `Motociclo m = new Motociclo("Marca X", "Modelo Y", quadro); m.setQuilometragem(12000)`

Comment: @LuisAmaro não existe relação entre construtor e atributos da classe. Você pode tanto ter um construtor sem atributo algum (que, aliás, chama-se construtor padrão) como um com todos os atributos. O que vai mandar nesse caso é a sua necessidade. Não há certo ou errado aqui.