# Omitir passagem de parâmetro

Tags: typescript, método, parâmetros

Tenho o seguinte método que contem o segundo parâmetro declarado

```
post(path:string, body: Object = {}){
   ...
}
```

E aqui a chamada do mesmo com a omissão do segundo parâmetro

```
obj.post('/path/obj');
```

Com base nisso, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- Por que o Typescript permite omitir o segundo parâmetro?
- Isso é por causa da declaração literal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Por que o Typescript permite omitir o segundo parâmetro?

Porque os criadores da linguagem acharam que assim era melhor. Não tem como responder essa pergunta de outra forma. A provável motivação para terem permitido isso é que simplifica a sintaxe da chamada de funções em boa parte dos casos quando fizer sentido ter algo assim. Esse mecanismo é chamado de argumentos opcionais já que embora tenha uma parâmetro declarado na assinatura da função não é necessário passar um argumento para ele já que em boa parte dos casos o valor que seria passado é o mesmo e seria desnecessário repeti-lo sempre.

Várias linguagens aceitam assim. A alternativa para dar essa flexibilidade é ter sobrecarga de funções ou ter que criar uma função com nome diferente para aceitar sem o argumento porque nesses dois casos o parâmetro não seria declarado. Muito mais complicado.

A documentação da linguagem chama de parâmetro opcional, o que é um erro, o parâmetro não pode ser opcional, só o argumento, provavelmente quem escreveu não entende [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

> Isso é por causa da declaração literal?

Para que o mecanismo funcione é necessário que o parâmetro saiba qual seria o valor padrão a ser adotado na ausência do argumento explicitamente passado. Então a presença do literal sendo atribuído ao parâmetro é uma forma que permite este mecanismo funcionar.

Mas seria um engano achar que só o literal permite a omissão do argumento. Se o tipo tiver um valor padrão pode funcionar, por exemplo se o tipo dor anulável, então mesmo sem um literal atribuído nele se nada for passado o nulo será o valor padrão.

Há limitações de como isso pode ser usado, por exemplo só pode omitir argumentos da direta para a esquerda, o primeiro nesta ordem que não for omitido não pode mais omitir qualquer outro.

A linguagem não possui argumentos nomeados como algumas outras, o que daria mais flexibilidade. Não sei ao certo mas é provável que seja porque JavaScript já tenha um mecanismo que pode simular isso e aí ele deva ser usado, até para evitar certas ambiguidades, embora nada tenha a ver com a filosofia de TypeScript.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Por que voce esta atribuindo um valor default para o segundo parametro.

`body:Object={}`

A variavel `body` e do tipo `Object` com o valor padrao definido como `{}`(um objeto vazio)
Para deixa-lo obrigatorio basta remover o `={}`, assim

`post(path:string, body: Object){`