# Por que não preciso declarar o parâmetro na função?

Tags: javascript, funções, react, callback, função-anônima

Na documentação do React ele traz um exemplo de *form*, quando o `input` recebe algum valor a propriedade `onChange` é chamada com a função `handleSubmit(event)` dessa maneira `onChange={this.handleChange}` porque eu não preciso definir o parâmetro nesse caso, já que a assinatura da função tem um parâmetro?

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque você não está chamando a função, está apenas dizendo qual função será usada pelo *framework* neste momento. Isto é o que se chama função anônima ou técnica de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), você está parametrizando o que será executado em determinando momento, no caso específico o que será chamado quando ocorrer o evento `onChange`, então quem chamará a função de verdade é o React e ele é que passará um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para sua função. Portanto você está passando uma referência para a função e não chamando-a, os parênteses é justamente o que diferencia isto, com, chama, sem, passa referência.

Comment: como ele sabe exatamente que o parâmetro está certo? tipo como ele sabe que tem que usar o event ou qualquer coisa?

Comment: Ele não sabe exatamente, isto não é característica do JS ou do React. Você tem que fazer certo o que ele espera, ele faz o que tem que fazer e espera que sua parte esteja ok, se não estiver vai dar erro. È um contrato que ele faz com você e espera que você cumpra. Mesmo em linguagens e tecnologias que garantem mais isso, a garantia vai até certo ponto, é como você fazer um `for` em todo um *array*, se você fizer errado vai dar erro de compilação, ou execução ou de lógica.

Answer (score 5):

Em linguagem JSX escreve-se `onChange={this.handleChange}` mas na verdade é o mesmo que `.addEventListener('change', this.handleChange)` ou seja [uma callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129). No momento em que essa callback é usada ela vai receber todos os argumentos que lhe forem passados.

Exemplo:

```js
function handleChange(e){
    console.log(e.type, this.checked);
}

const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
```

```html
Clica aqui: <input type="checkbox" />
```

Nota que em classes React por vezes tens de usar o `.bind(this)` para garantir que essa callback vai ter o contexto de execução que esperas, ou seja o `this` é a instância da classe:

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```