# Web scrapping NodeJS - Não consigo utilizar variável como parâmetro

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

Estou usando a biblioteca **Nightmare**, para **Web scrapping**, a função funciona normalmente quando passo uma string como parâmetro `'.seletor'`, o problema ocorre quando armazeno este valor em uma variável e passo como parâmetro, segue código abaixo (irei utilizar um produto da amazon como exemplo):

**JS:**

```js
const nightmare = require('nightmare')()

async function checkPrice () {
      const url = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/250GB-SAMSUNG-970-EVO-PCIe/dp/B07CGGNX7S/'

      const priceNow = await nightmare.goto(url)
        .wait('#priceblock_ourprice')
        .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#priceblock_ourprice').innerText)
        .end()

      console.log(priceNow) // R$664,90
    }

checkPrice()
```

Dessa maneira o preço do produto é retornado, sem nenhum tipo de erro...

Segue exemplo com o erro:

**JS:**

```js
const nightmare = require('nightmare')()

async function checkPrice () {
      const url = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/250GB-SAMSUNG-970-EVO-PCIe/dp/B07CGGNX7S/'
      const priceSelector = '#priceblock_ourprice'

      const priceNow = await nightmare.goto(url)
        .wait(priceSelector)
        .evaluate(() => document.querySelector(priceSelector).innerText)
        .end()

      console.log(priceNow) // Mensagem de erro
    }

checkPrice()
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em qual chamada o erro (`priceSelector` aparentemente não está definido) está ocorrendo? Na linha da chamada do método `wait` ou no `querySelector`, que está no `evaluate`? Suponho que seja no `evaluate`, que provavelmente faz um pouco de _black magic_ por baixo dos panos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após uma pequena pesquisa, encontrei [este documento](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/variable-lifting.md). Conforme [ponderei nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430307/web-scrapping-nodejs-n%c3%a3o-consigo-utilizar-vari%c3%a1vel-como-par%c3%a2metro#comment833807_430307), o método [`evaluate`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2) realmente faz uma certa magia por baixo dos panos, o que causa toda essa confusão.

O que ocorre é que como essa biblioteca utiliza Electron por baixo dos panos (de alguma forma que não procurei entender). Por isso, ele transforma a função de callback que você passa para como argumento para o método em questão para que possa ser executada no contexto do Electron. Por isso que mesmo parecendo estar no escopo, variávies como o `priceSelector` não estão, já que a função estará sendo executada somente no contexto Electron. Também é por isso que passando valores literais não causa nenhum tipo de erro: eles também são colocados na função "*stringificada*".

Veja [no GitHub](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/b230e85375bb084007a54c6a1bf698d81b5f2feb/lib/nightmare.js#L440) o momento em que a função de callback é convertida em string.

Desse modo, você tem duas alternativas para resolver o problema:

#### Utilizando os últimos argumentos de `evaluate` para fornecer parâmetros para o callback que será avaliado

Conforme consta na [documentação do `evaluate`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2) e no [documento](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/variable-lifting.md) que mencionei anteriormente, você pode passar outros argumentos para o `evaluate`, que serão passados para o seu callback. Mais ou menos assim:

```js
// ...
.evaluate(
  (selector) => document.querySelector(selector).innerText,
  priceSelector
)
// ...
```

Note que agora a função de callback está recebendo `selector` como parâmetro. Parâmetro esse que passamos como argumento para `evaluate` após o callback. <sup>[[4]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32448/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-par%C3%A2metro-e-argumento)</sup>

#### Passar valores literais

Se você achar mais simples, também pode passar os valores de forma [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guia/Valores,_Vari%C3%A1veis_e_Literais#Literais). Basicamente, se você preferir essa opção, ficará restrito somente a usar qualquer tipo de referência externa ao escopo do callback.

---

Enfim, cabe a você escolher qual opção prefere. :-)