# Significado dos parênteses na instanciação em C#

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, sintaxe, instanciar-objeto

Não consigo entender a necessidade do `()` para instanciar uma classe.

```
Retangulo n1 = new Retangulo();
```

É coisa própria da linguagem esse padrão ou tem significado por de trás?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consegue entender que todo método chamado precisa de parênteses? Até para diferenciar de um campo ou propriedade ou outra forma que não seja para executar?

E sabe que toda execução de código deve estar dentro de um método? O código não pode estar solto.

Pois bem, o que está fazendo aí é exatamente a chamada de um método. Ele é chamado de construtor (o `new` entrega isso). Ele executa o código necessário para construir o objeto, portanto alocar a memória e inicializar seus membros com valores base para iniciar, e quem sabe executar alguma coisa a mais que seja necessário no início de cada objeto.

Portanto não tem algo especial nesses parênteses, está chamando um método que não tem [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para passar, então nada é passado, mas ainda usa parênteses porque é uma chamada de método e não uma simples variáveis ou outra coisa.

O que provavelmente não sabia era sobre o método construtor. Tem algo mais sobre ele em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Em grande parte dos casos que uma classe não tem um construtor com parâmetros ela está errada, ainda que funcione. E se tem um construtor com parâmetros, em muitos casos não deveria ter um construtor sem eles. E mesmo que tenha, quase sempre não deveria usar.

Esse exemplo mesmo, sem nem ver o contexto posso dizer que ele está errado, afinal por que criar um objeto que não tem dados? Não faz muito sentido. Tem dados padrões dentro dele? Duvido, mas se tiver que vantagem existe em ter dados padrões? Se vai mudar depois, pra que? Que vantagem tem isso? Tem desvantagens! E por que pode mudar os dados depois? Se mudar os dados será que o objeto não passa ser outro objeto? Se se ele for imutável, o que obrigaria ter um construtor com parâmetros para ser útil, então será que não deveria criar uma `struct` e não uma classe? Não estou garantindo que isso é uma classe, é uma falha do C#.

Programar é pensar em todas essas coisas, não é só sintaxe.

Algumas linguagens optaram por permitir que os parênteses do método/função sejam opcionais quando eles são vazios, ou até mesmo em outros casos, mas gera ambiguidade, complica para o compilador e é comum ficar mais difícil de ler código assim porque você tem que parar para pensar se aquilo é um método ou não.

Particularmente eu preferiria uma sintaxe diferenciada para o construtor, mas nunca vi uma linguagem fazer isso, acho que simplificaria algumas coisas, mas esse é outro assunto não vou levantar detalhes aqui.

C# está evoluindo para futuras versões precisar se valer menos do construtor, mas só em alguns cenários, pode ser um perigo nas mãos erradas (que sãos as mesmas que já não criam construtores quando devem).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).