# Por que em Python existem funções onde o parâmetro deve ser posto entre parênteses e outras devem ser postas com um ponto e o nome da função?

Tags: python, funções, sintaxe

Existem funções que deve ser escritas como por exemplo

`sorted(variavel)`

e outras são escrita como

`variavel.sort()`

Sei das diferenças entre as duas funções acima, apenas usei para exemplificar. Quero apenas entender a diferença da forma da escrita das funções em Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira sintaxe é considerada mais imperativa, ou seja, a função é o que mais importa, portanto ela vem primeiro, e o objeto que será manipulado dentro dela é só um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) da função.

A segunda sintaxe é considerada mais orientada a objeto, então o que importa mais é o objeto que será manipulado, por isso ele vem antes. E partindo desse objeto você chama uma função que executará algo com ele. Essa função passa se chamar método por estar vinculado a um objeto.

A segunda faz a função ser um membro de uma estrutura assim como acessaria um campo do tipo de dado.

Na prática dá na mesma, quando for executar a segunda ela chama igual a primeira, é só uma forma de mostrar que o objeto é importante, mas a função será chamada e o argumento passado para ela será o objeto que veio antes dela.

Tem uma vantagem de legibilidade para alguns cenários e um IDE pode ajudar mostrando os métodos que ele pode chamar partindo daquele objeto o que ajuda um pouco. O IDE precisa ser bem mais inteligente em Python porque é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e o tipo da variável pode mudar, então torna-se um pouco complicado ele "adivinhar" que tipo é naquele ponto do código. Em alguns casos impossível saber que objeto é aquele e a ajuda não é possível.

Quando você tem uma função que funciona para muitos tipos diferentes pode ser mais interessante a primeira sintaxe. Quando o método é só para aquele tipo a segunda pode ser melhor.

Em Python a segunda só é possível se o método foi definido dentro de uma classe daquele tipo (a não ser que tenha alguma exceção de sintaxe da linguagem para coisas *builtin*).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale lembrar que no exemplo específico da pergunta, `sorted` retorna outra lista, enquanto `lista.sort()` modifica a lista *in place*

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, não entrei nesse ponto porque ele disse que sabe essas diferenças e só usou isso como exemplo para perguntar sobre a sintaxe. Essa questão é pontual.

Comment: exatamente, a diferença entre as duas eu sei. Muito obrigado!