# Por que a classe aceita parâmetro e o método não?

Tags: python, classes, método, parâmetros

Estou estudando classes em Python e não entendo uma coisa: considerando as últimas duas linhas de comando abaixo, por que o valor 4 é aceito na classe Operadores e não no método `metade()`? Não são estes que aceitam os parâmetros? Se eu botar, o código não executa.

```
class Operadores:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def metade(self):
        return self.a/2
    
    def dobro(self):
        return self.a*2

    def triplo(self):
        return self.a*3

pass

operacao1 = Operadores(4)

print(operacao1.metade())
```

Answer (score 8):

Não existe isso de classe que aceita parâmetro, classe não tem parâmetros. Existe um construtor de objeto de uma classe chamado `init()` que aceita receber um argumento porque está declarado que este método tem um parâmetro. Quando vai construir o objeto você chama pelo nome da classe para indicar qual `init()` deve ser chamada, mas não é a classe que aceito argumento, menos ainda parâmetro.

O método `metade()` não tem declarado qualquer parâmetro para receber além do próprio objeto através do `self`, então o código não pode aceitar argumentos, se quer que aceite, então deve declarar isso. Mas pelo código interno não faz muito sentido porque nada está sendo necessário.

O `self` é adotado para dizer que aquele parâmetro é o próprio o objeto, assim o argumento usado será escrito antes do método, e assim fazer a sintaxe orientada a objeto em que o objeto principal é que chama a função a ser executada. No fundo aquilo é um argumento, mas parece não ser na sintaxe de chamada.

Você só declara que existirá um parâmetro se ele é necessário.

Útil: [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).