# Erro: Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: variáveis, dart

Estou fazendo um pequeno projeto usando dart, só que está acontecendo um erro no meu arquivo `ImprimirResultado.dart`.

- Erro

> Undefined name 'IMCFormated'. Try correcting the name to one that is
> defined, or defining the name.

---

- Arquivo main.dart

```
import 'package:dart1/CalculoIMC.dart';

main() {
  CalculoIMC();
}
```

- Arquivo CalculoIMC.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dart1/ImprimirResultado.dart';

CalculoIMC() {
  stdout.write("Digite a sua massa: ");
  var massa = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
  var altura = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  var IMC = massa / (altura * 2);

  var IMCFormated = IMC.toStringAsFixed(2);

  ImprimirResultado(IMC);
}
```

- Arquivo ImprimirResultado.dart

```
import 'package:dart1/CalculoIMC.dart';

ImprimirResultado(IMC) {
  if (IMC < 16) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MUITO ABAIXO DO PESO");
  } else if (IMC > 16 && IMC < 17) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MAGREZA MODERADA");
  } else if (IMC > 17 && IMC < 18.5) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MAGREZA LEVE");
  } else if (IMC > 18.5 && IMC < 25) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, SAUDÁVEL");
  } else if (IMC > 25 && IMC < 30) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, SOBREPESO");
  } else if (IMC > 30 && IMC < 35) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU I");
  } else if (IMC > 35 && IMC < 40) {
    print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU II");
  } else if (IMC >= 40) {
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU III");
  }
}
```

Comment: arquivo ```CalculoIMC.dart``` e arquivo ```ImprimirResultado.dart``` estão dentro da pasta lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você passou só `IMC`, tem que passar `IMCFormated` também, para que as duas variáveis existam na função local e possam ser usadas. Portanto a função tem que receber dois parâmetros. Algo assim:

```
ImprimirResultado(IMC, IMCFormated)
```

E a chamada exatamente igual.

Eu colocaria tipos para deixar o código mais robusto.

Por outro lado poderia deixar a formatação para realizar dentro da função e aí não se preocuparia com isso. Não posso afirmar porque não conheço o problema exato, mas parece fazer mais sentido já que só a função que faz a impressão deveria cuidar de formatação.

Também não vi motivo para tantos arquivos.

O código tem alguns problemas problemas, mesmo que nem sempre gere erros. Não trate como se ele estivesse completamente correto. Eu faria algo assim:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  CalculoIMC();
}

CalculoIMC() {
    stdout.write("Digite a sua massa: ");
    var massa = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
    if (massa == null) return;
    stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
    var altura = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
    if (altura == null) return;
    ImprimirResultado(massa / (altura * 2));
}

ImprimirResultado(double IMC) {
    var IMCFormated = IMC.toStringAsFixed(2);
    if (IMC < 16) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MUITO ABAIXO DO PESO");
    else if (IMC > 16 && IMC < 17) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MAGREZA MODERADA");
    else if (IMC > 17 && IMC < 18.5) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, MAGREZA LEVE");
    else if (IMC > 18.5 && IMC < 25) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, SAUDÁVEL");
    else if (IMC > 25 && IMC < 30) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, SOBREPESO");
    else if (IMC > 30 && IMC < 35) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU I");
    else if (IMC > 35 && IMC < 40) print("Você está com $IMCFormated\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU II");
    else if (IMC >= 40) print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU III");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7F2Igd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fntrrdaq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Imc.dt).

Para entender melhor o que está fazendo leia:

- [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101)

Programar é entender dos os conceitos, ler a documentação, e procurar o jeito certo de fazer as coisas, não chute, não faça apenas funcionar.

Comment: O problema era aquele dos parâmetros da função.