# Por que está dando erro na chamada de um método?

Tags: python, classes, método

Estou tentando este código:

```
class Car:
    def beep():
        print('Beep')

car = Car()
car.beep()
```

> TypeError: method() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Por que dá o erro?

Comment: Tira o () de Car()

Comment: @FourZeroFive se for python3 esta "quase" certo, mas o autor não informou se é 2 ou 3, que já é um problema da pergunta ... se for 2 vai ter o erro: `TypeError: unbound method beep() must be called with Car instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`, tem que ter certeza se o caso é de fato OO ou outra coisa que o autor deseja, retirar `()` pode resolver aparentemente, mas não adianta "resolvermos" sem que a necessidade técnica real seja evidente, porque na verdade pode apenas estar gerando outro problema.

Comment: Olá @MarconcilioSouza, é um bom link, mas como já disse, precisamos ter certeza qual a necessidade real do código, se é realmente OO, se precisa do método, se ele estiver aprendendo OO não adianta muito só chegar e demonstrar o "meios" sem ter um contexto claro de suas necessidades. O link não é ruim, como já disse, mas é só uma série de como resolver problemas sem entender para que servem.

Comment: Olá @MarconcilioSouza removida não, editada pelo autor e detalhada. Eu não acho que o link seja ruim como eu disse antes, até explica algumas coisas, mas a resposta abaixo também explica (vale lembrar que somos uma comunidade em português). Mas estou apenas tentando orientar a "todos" que a pergunta esta com problema, só me segurei para fecha-la porque vi atividade de 3 usuários, fora o autor e estou avaliando como fazer isso sem causar mal estar a ninguém. Espero que compreenda que vim aqui apenas querendo ajudar e claro esperando ver suas opiniões também. Obrigado.

Comment: A pergunta não está na melhor forma, mas não tem muita dificuldade em responder isso. Eu fiquei curioso em saber o que a resposta tem de errado, porque eu mesmo quero aprender com a pessoa que negativou e sabe de algo que eu não sei sobre o assunto.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Que detalhes você quer? Não importa a versão do Python para resolver isso. O erro nada tem a ver com o primeiro comentário, que aliás desviou completamente do assunto real da pergunta e aí tem gente começou achar que a pergunta é sobre outra coisa, mas é culpa dos comentários e não da pergunta. Se a resposta não está errada, não merece negativo. E a resposta resolveu o problema, o AP até chegou comentar, mas eu apaguei porque não é comentário relevante. Vocês querem mais detalhes, mas a pergunta é muito simples, isso virou uma torre de marfim. Não tem o que problematizar.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza eu vi oportunidade de explicar algo que muita gente confunde, infelizmente o fuzuê que fizeram jogou tudo no lixo, e quando tiver outras oportunidade dessa terei que responder de novo. O site existe para criar conteúdo que ensina as pessoas resolver seus problemas e a pergunta era boa pra isso, pena que estragaram. Se teve essa oportunidade e dava pa responder bem não tem porque ser fechado. Vocês criaram uma situação confusa, a pergunta não era confusa, só não era uma maravilha.

Comment: As pessoas precisam entender qual é o objetivo do site e aqui foi atingido (exceto por esse monte de negativos em algo que não é tão ruim, tem coisa muito pior, coisa errada, que desensina, que causa problemas que não tem tanto assim. E esse tip ode atitude já foi discutido antes no meta, as pessoas entram em uma espiral positiva ou negativa de acordo com o fluxo e não de acordo com a qualidade do conteúdo. Não merece positivo, mas não esse negativos todos. A resposta então nem se fala, nem quem deu concorda que ela está errada.

Comment: Pode sinalizar ou discutir no meta todas perguntas elaboradas que foram fechadas. Escrever um monte de coisa não significa que dá pra responder bem, geralmente é o que causa confusão. Algumas pessoas acusam o SOpt de não gostar de novatos, eu gosto, tanto que perguntas simples são respondidas por mim. Eu não gosto de gente sem noção, que pega algo complexo pra fazer e não tem condições, quer que outras pessoas resolvam pra ela. Quem não gosta de novato é quem não entende o site.

Answer (score 6):

O método `beep()` não tem parâmetro algum, e você está passando um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) quando chama ele. Colocando o parâmetro `self` que é sempre obrigatório quando está criando um método resolve o problema:

```
class Car:
    def beep(self):
        print('Beep')

car = Car()
car.beep()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y0rS0p). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yqlitsxy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/Self.py).

Quando chama `car.beep()` na verdade está chamando uma função dessa forma: `Car.beep(car)`, ou seja, está chamando uma função chamada `beep()` com sobrenome `Car`, já que ela só é vista dentro dessa classe, e está passando o valor da variável `car` como argumento da função. Então tem que ter uma variável como parâmetro dessa função, e se convencionou que sendo um método o nome desse parâmetro é `self`.

Assim também funciona:

```
class Car:
    def beep():
        print('Beep')

car = Car()
Car.beep()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nV11Sw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/udstutte-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/Static.py).

Mas não é o que deseja, isso não é um método de instância, ele [e estático.