# Javascript recursividade

Tags: javascript, recursão, ecmascript-6

Salve, comecei a ler o livro "Javascript Eloquente" e no capítulo sobre funções de ordem superior me deparei com o seguinte exemplo de um código que calcula os Genes que um indivíduo herdou da familia:

```
var ANCESTRY_FILE = JSON.stringify([
    {"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"},
    {"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"},
    {"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"},
    {"name": "Jan van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1714, "died": 1748, "father": "Jacobus van Brussel", "mother": "Joanna van Rooten"},
    {"name": "Philibert Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1907, "died": 1997, "father": "Emile Haverbeke", "mother": "Emma de Milliano"},
    {"name": "Jan Frans van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1761, "died": 1833, "father": "Jacobus Bernardus van Brussel", "mother":null},
    {"name": "Pauwels van Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1535, "died": 1582, "father": "N. van Haverbeke", "mother":null},
    {"name": "Clara Aernoudts", "sex": "f", "born": 1918, "died": 2012, "father": "Henry Aernoudts", "mother": "Sidonie Coene"},
    {"name": "Emile Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1877, "died": 1968, "father": "Carolus Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria Sturm"},
    {"name": "Lieven de Causmaecker", "sex": "m", "born": 1696, "died": 1724, "father": "Carel de Causmaecker", "mother": "Joanna Claes"},
    {"name": "Pieter Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1602, "died": 1642, "father": "Lieven van Haverbeke", "mother":null},
    {"name": "Livina Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1692, "died": 1743, "father": "Daniel Haverbeke", "mother": "Joanna de Pape"},
    {"name": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1695, "died": 1762, "father": "Willem Haverbeke", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"},
    {"name": "Lieven van Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1570, "died": 1636, "father": "Pauwels van Haverbeke", "mother": "Lievijne Jans"},
    {"name": "Joanna de Causmaecker", "sex": "f", "born": 1762, "died": 1807, "father": "Bernardus de Causmaecker", "mother":null},
    {"name": "Willem Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1668, "died": 1731, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"},
    {"name": "Pieter Antone Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1753, "died": 1798, "father": "Jan Francies Haverbeke", "mother": "Petronella de Decker"},
    {"name": "Maria van Brussel", "sex": "f", "born": 1801, "died": 1834, "father": "Jan Frans van Brussel", "mother": "Joanna de Causmaecker"},
    {"name": "Angela Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1728, "died": 1734, "father": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"},
    {"name": "Elisabeth Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1711, "died": 1754, "father": "Jan Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria de Rycke"},
    {"name": "Lievijne Jans", "sex": "f", "born": 1542, "died": 1582, "father":null, "mother":null},
    {"name": "Bernardus de Causmaecker", "sex": "m", "born": 1721, "died": 1789, "father": "Lieven de Causmaecker", "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"},
    {"name": "Jacoba Lammens", "sex": "f", "born": 1699, "died": 1740, "father": "Lieven Lammens", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"},
    {"name": "Pieter de Decker", "sex": "m", "born": 1705, "died": 1780, "father": "Joos de Decker", "mother": "Petronella van de Steene"},
    {"name": "Joanna de Pape", "sex": "f", "born": 1654, "died": 1723, "father": "Vincent de Pape", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"},
    {"name": "Daniel Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1652, "died": 1723, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"},
    {"name": "Lieven Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1631, "died": 1676, "father": "Pieter Haverbeke", "mother": "Anna van Hecke"},
    {"name": "Martina de Pape", "sex": "f", "born": 1666, "died": 1727, "father": "Vincent de Pape", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"},
    {"name": "Jan Francies Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1725, "died": 1779, "father": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"},
    {"name": "Maria Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1905, "died": 1997, "father": "Emile Haverbeke", "mother": "Emma de Milliano"},
    {"name": "Petronella de Decker", "sex": "f", "born": 1731, "died": 1781, "father": "Pieter de Decker", "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"},
    {"name": "Livina Sierens", "sex": "f", "born": 1761, "died": 1826, "father": "Jan Sierens", "mother": "Maria van Waes"},
    {"name": "Laurentia Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1710, "died": 1786, "father": "Jan Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria de Rycke"},
    {"name": "Carel Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1796, "died": 1837, "father": "Pieter Antone Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina Sierens"},
    {"name": "Elisabeth Hercke", "sex": "f", "born": 1632, "died": 1674, "father": "Willem Hercke", "mother": "Margriet de Brabander"},
    {"name": "Jan Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1671, "died": 1731, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"},
    {"name": "Anna van Hecke", "sex": "f", "born": 1607, "died": 1670, "father": "Paschasius van Hecke", "mother": "Martijntken Beelaert"},
    {"name": "Maria Sturm", "sex": "f", "born": 1835, "died": 1917, "father": "Charles Sturm", "mother": "Seraphina Spelier"},
    {"name": "Jacobus Bernardus van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1736, "died": 1809, "father": "Jan van Brussel", "mother": "Elisabeth Haverbeke"}
])

var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);

var byName = {};

ancestry.forEach(function(person){
    byName[person.name] = person;
});

function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue){
    function valueFor(person){
        if(person == null){
            return defaultValue;
        } else {
            return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]))
        }
    }
    return valueFor(person);
}

function sharedDNA(person, fromFather, fromMother){
    if(person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke")
        return 1
    else
        return (fromFather + fromMother) / 2
}

var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
```

Se vocês observarem a função "valueFor" é uma função recursiva que retorna para a função "f" que faz referência a "sharedDNA". A questão são aquelas duas variáveis da função "sharedDNA" a "fromFather" e "fromMother" essas duas váriaveis aparecem dentro da função com valores como 1, 0.5, 0.125

```
fromFather = 0.5
fromMother = 0
```

Mas a função "f" retorna um objeto de pai ou da mãe e não um número decimal

```
return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]))
```

Eu não entendo como "sharedDNA" recebe aqueles números decimais. Se alguém entendeu e poder ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"f" retorna um objeto de pai ou da mãe*

Não, os objetos do pai e da mãe são passados como [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/112052) para `valueFor`, cujos **resultados** são passados como argumentos para `f`. Repare nos parênteses (coloquei uns espaços a mais para facilitar a visualização):

```
return f ( person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]) )
         ^    ^    ^                                ^                               ^
         |    |    |                                |                               |__ parênteses que encerra a lista de argumentos de f
         |    |    |                                |
         |    |    |                                |__ terceiro argumento de f
         |    |    |
         |    |    |__ segundo argumento de f
         |    |
         |    |__ primeiro argumento de f
         |
         |__ parênteses que inicia a lista de argumentos de f
```

Ou seja, `f` recebe 3 argumentos: o `person`, o **resultado** de `valueFor(byName[person.mother])` (que é um número) e o **resultado** de `valueFor(byName[person.father])` (que é outro número). Os objetos referentes ao pai e a mãe são passados para `valueFor`, não para `f`. O que `f` recebe é o **resultado** de `valueFor`.

E `valueFor` sempre retornará um número, pois chega uma hora em que uma pessoa não tem mais pai nem mãe cadastrados no array (então `person.mother` e `person.father` serão nulos) e ele retornará zero (que é o `defaultValue` que indicamos ao chamar `reduceAncestors`). E quando tem pai e mãe, ele retorna o valor de `f`, passando o resultado do `valueFor` dos pais destes (e para calcular os valores do pai e da mãe, ele vai chamando recursivamente nos ancestrais destes). Ou seja, no fim `valueFor` sempre retorna um número.

Comment: Perfeito mano, entendi, nível Jedi você TMJ