# Como criar parâmetros opcionais em C++?

Tags: c++, funções, argumento

Em Python é possível ter parâmetros opcionais numa função. Ficaria algo assim:

```
def soma(n1, n2 = 5):
    return n1 + n2

print(soma(5, 7))
```

Se caso não fosse passado um segundo parâmetro o `n2` receberia o número 5 e não haveria erros.

Eu queria saber se seria também possível ter parâmetros opcionais em C++, eu até tentei fazer isso (ficou horrível) usando sobrecarga de funções e deu certo. Ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int soma(int n1, int n2);
int soma(int n1);


int main() {
    cout << soma(5, 7) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

//Funções
int soma(int n1, int n2) {
     return n1 + n2;
}

int soma(int n1) {
    return n1 + 5;
}
```

Terá o mesmo resultado que no código acima feito em Python.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: Tentou escrever igualzinho em C++? Python não foi muito original nisso :)

Answer (score 1):

C++ possui [argumentos padrões](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) (o termo correto, [veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)).

E pode escrever de forma mais sucinta se quiser, só não pode ser menor porque C++ não é uma linguagem de *script* por padrão, então não faz sentido ficar economizando, embora tenha implementação de C++ que permite usar como se fosse *script*. E algumas coisas usadas não são obrigatórias, não faz muito sentido usar isso.

Tem que ser muito ruim em C++ para escrever um código 10x maior que Python. Usando as mesmas 3 linhas:

```
#include <iostream>

int soma(int n1, int n2 = 5) { return n1 + n2; }

int main() { std::cout << soma(5) << std::endl; }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MZGlfT). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/tcvganakjx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/DefaultArgument.cpp).

Note que qualquer coisa mais útil Python não consegue ser tão econômico, ele tem um pequeno ganho em coisas muitos simples comparando com um código de linguagem que existe para criar aplicação e não *scripts*.