# Append() do StringBuilder converte para string automaticamente

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, append, stringbuilder

Por que quando uso `.AppendLine()` é necessário converter o parâmetro para string, mas quando uso `.Append()` não é necessária a conversão?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos a documentação do [`AppendLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e do [`Append()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), que por sinal é o que sempre deve ser feito antes de usar qualquer recurso da linguagem/tecnologia adotada e suas APIs.

Lá mostra que o segundo método tem várias sobrecargas lidando com muitos tipos de dados diferentes como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). E quando nenhum for satisfeito de forma direta pelo menos o [`object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é adotado, que é o tipo pai de todos. E caindo nesse método [**ele faz uma conversão para `string` internamente**](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StringBuilder.cs,1201).

O primeiro método só aceita um dado que já seja `string` (tem uma opção onde não tem dado algum a passar).

Há uma chance maior de algo dar errado no `Append()` já que uma conversão implícita pode não dar o resultado esperado e que pode ser cisto apenas durante a execução em certas situações. Uma conversão antecipada dá um pouco mais de controle do que está querendo. Não quer dizer que é mais certo, mas é preciso considerar isto.