# Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?

Tags: funções, algoritmo, terminologia, procedure

Estou estudando algorítimos e estou com uma certa dificuldade para entender a diferença entre eles e quando usar esses sub-algoritmos em um programa. Estou aprendendo a programar com algoritmo em Portugol.

Comment: É uma explicação meio "porca", mas só pra iniciar o assunto: na maioria dos contextos, a função retorna um valor, e o procedimento não. Na verdade, isso depende muito do contexto. Idealmente, procedimentos executariam tarefas passo a passo, e funções simplesmente fariam processamento de dados e devolveriam um retornoresultado, sem gerar efeitos colaterais, mas em linguagens imperativas essa coisa do efeito colateral fica meio relativizada.

Comment: Ainda não estudei nenhuma linguagem de programação, estou ainda no curso de algorítimos em portugol.

Comment: possível duplicada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11848/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-defini%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-m%C3%A9todo-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-procedimento

Comment: @Bacco Concordo com você ^^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Confusão

Muitos programadores experientes podem ter dificuldade de entender a diferença entre um e outro. Tanto confundem que algumas pessoas acham que linguagens do paradigma funcional são as linguagens que possuem funções e as linguagens do paradigma procedural são as que possuem procedimentos. O que é um completo absurdo, porque no fundo ambos são (quase) a mesma coisa.

## No fundo é a mesma coisa

É raro encontrar linguagem que só possua procedimentos (algum dialeto de SQL pode ser, alguma linguagem muito antiga e virtualmente abandonada, ou em algum nicho muito específico).

Em algumas poucas linguagens de programação há uma distinção clara entre as duas, outras preferem tratar tudo como funções. Algumas até tratam as funções só como métodos.

No fundo tanto os dois citados na pergunta quanto métodos funcionam da mesma forma e concretamente a implementação é essencialmente a mesma.

## O que difere

Conceitualmente **um procedimento difere da função pela ausência de um retorno de valor**.

Então um procedimento é um algoritmo que será executado, enquanto que a função é um algoritmo que será executado e produzirá um resultado final concreto que poderá ser usado por outro algoritmo.

## Função pura

Como o termo "função" vem da matemática, ela deveria apenas executar um cálculo e retornar o resultado sem fazer operações extras, sem fazer entrada e saída, sem alterar estado fora de sua execução (só mexe em variáveis locais, criadas dentro da função), enfim, a função deveria ser pura (determinística, sem efeitos colaterais). Só algumas poucas linguagens funcionais realmente exigem a pureza. A prática da pureza é pouco pragmática para a maioria dos problemas comumente encontrados na computação.
[image: Fucntion]
Em outras palavras, a função computa algo (no sentido de cálculo) e o procedimento executa uma lógica de negócio (ainda que tecnicamente isso não deixe de ser uma computação).

## Convenção

As linguagens que só possuem funções retornam "nada" quando se deseja apenas um procedimento, mas elas ainda são consideradas funções. Comparando:

```
procedimento teste()
```

é o mesmo que

```
funçao teste() : nada //tipo do dado que será retornado, o Portugol não possui "nada"
```

## O que fazer com cada um

Cada linguagem ou até mesmo cada equipe pode definir o que pode ou não fazer dentro de uma função ou procedimento, mas isso costuma ficar em estilo de codificação e não regras rígidas obrigatórias para validade do código.

É comum que a linguagem exija que o procedimento só possa ser chamado como um *statement* (comando, algo no início da linha ou através de comando específico de chamada) e não como expressão, afinal uma expressão costuma exigir um resultado que o procedimento não fornece.

Então se for aplicar a um algoritmo definido abstratamente, deve-se considerar a sintaxe da representação usada para saber se haverá uma diferenciação sobre um ou outro. Agora que a pergunta tem uma definição que está usando Portugol posso dizer que ela segue um pouco o que o Pascal faz, que é uma linguagem que usa técnica um pouco antiga.

Para todos os efeitos entenda bem o funcionamento da função que saberá como deve ser o procedimento. A não ser que deseja aprender de forma muito acadêmica e só utilizar funções puras e deixar rotinas não puras para procedimentos. Não acho que vale a pena distinguir isso em casos práticos (não estou dizendo que aprender de forma acadêmica não tenha sua serventia teórica).

## Conclusão

Não se assuste se encontrar definições diferentes em contextos diferentes.

Particularmente acho que essas linguagens muito abstratas acabam criando certos vícios no programador porque ele é obrigado fazer coisas que não faria em linguagem mais concreta. De que adianta aprender criar um procedimento se quase todas as linguagens modernas só possuem funções?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).