# Como testar o fatorial no Main()?

Tags: c, funções, if

Como ficaria a `main()` desta função abaixo? O usuário digita um número e aparece na tela o fatorial do mesmo.

```
int fatorial(int num) {
if (num >= 0) {
    int fat = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        fat *= num;
        num--;
    }
    return fat;
} else {
    return -1;
}}

int main(){
int n,num,fat;
printf("ESTE POGRAMA CALCULA N FATORIAL = N!\n");
printf("Digite um valor para ser calculado: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

printf("\n\tO fatorial de %d = %d\n\n",fatorial);
//printf("%d!=%d\n",num,fat);

//else printf("O calculo do fatorial se aplica somene aos numeros naturais.\n");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse código não tem lógica alguma.

Até começa bem, a não ser pelo fato de criar variável desnecessária novamente.

Para chamar a função precisa ser com parenteses e passar como argumento o número digitado para poder efetuar o cálculo.

Tem que verificar o retorno dessa função se é negativo. Se for, tem que dar a mensagem de erro. Se vir um número natural pode imprimir.

Procure manter o código organizado que ajuda entendê-lo.

Ainda te falta algumas coisas básicas de sintaxe e os conceitos de [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), [parâmetros, argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101), [funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101), etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fatorial(int num) {
    if (num >= 0) {
        int fat = 1;
        while (num > 0) {
            fat *= num;
            num--;
        }
        return fat;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("ESTE POGRAMA CALCULA N FATORIAL = N!\n");
    printf("Digite um valor para ser calculado: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int fat = fatorial(num); //chama a função passado o que foi digitado e guarda em fat
    if (fat < 1) { //verifica se o retorno é menor que 1, se for indica erro
        printf("O calculo do fatorial se aplica somene aos numeros naturais.\n");
    } else { //se fat não for menor que um, então pode imprimir o resultado
        printf("\n\tO fatorial de %d = %d\n\n", num, fat);
    } //encerrou o bloco do if, só executa um dos dois blocos, nunca ambos
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/enx2bc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jrclfwbc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ErrorInFactorial.c).

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está uma função recursiva e uma função iterativa, onde ambas calculam o fatorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fatorialRecursivo(int n) {
    if(n < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * fatorialRecursivo(n - 1);
    }
}

int fatorialIterativo(int n) {
    if(n >= 0) {
        int fatorial = 1;
        for(; n > 0; n--) fatorial *= n;
        return fatorial;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {

    int n = 10;

    if(n < 0) {
        printf("Nao e possivel calcular o fatorial de %d\n", n);
    } else {
        printf("O fatorial de %d e %d\n", n, fatorialRecursivo(n));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

PS1: Aprenda funções recursivas, umas vez consegui um estágio em TI porque fui o único que usou funções recursivas no teste de seleção

PS2: Ah, e se você está começando, indico a você estudar código limpo (clean code)

Comment: Ah essa ai tem na internet, ela é bem mais enxuta, mas a primeira de cima ajuda a esclarecer melhor pra quem é iniciante, com for, while... mas de qualquer forma obrigado.