# Por que o return não funciona?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou com um problema do `return` não funcionar de jeito nenhum.

Por enquanto só estou imprimindo no console, então estou substituindo o `return` por `Console.WriteLine()`, mas não queria sempre ficar tendo que fazer isso.

Aqui um exemplo que o `return` não retorna nada no console mas com o `Console.WriteLine()` funciona:

Class1

```
    class Class1 {

    Dictionary<int, int> teste = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        { 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2 }
    };

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return teste[1];
    }
}
```

Launcher

```
    class Program {

    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 classe = new Class1();
        classe.GetValue();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que deseja e qual o problema, qual o resultado desejado? Você diz que o `Console.WriteLine()`, mas não tem um no código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um método pode retornar ou não valores. Os métodos que retornam valores podem ser chamados de funções. E temos os métodos que não retornam nada (`void`).

Vamos analisar a seguinte função, `Multiplicar(int x, int y)`.

```
public int Multiplicar(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

O que podemos notar, é que esse método é **[público](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public)**, possui um retorno do tipo [**`int`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) e recebe dois parâmetros, `x` e `y`, ambos do tipo [**`int`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int). O que esse método faz é multiplicar os parâmetros recebidos e retornar para quem chamou.

Vejamos esse contexto:

```
// ...
int resultado = 0;
resultado = Multiplicar(10, 20);
```

Criei uma variável do tipo inteiro, que recebe o valor processado pelo método `Multiplicar(10, 20)`. No final, o valor de resultado será 200.

Veja que nada foi impresso na tela nem nada, o que aconteceu foi só o que foi pedido a ser feito: multiplicar dois números e retornar para quem o chamou, que foi a variável `resultado`.

---

Você tem um [método](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods), chamado `GetValue()`. No seu caso, `GetValue()` retorna um inteiro (`int`) e não recebe parâmetros, tudo bem.

Vamos analisar o que `GetValue()` faz:

```
Dictionary<int, int> teste = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    { 1, 1 },
    { 2, 2 }
};

public int GetValue()
{
    return teste[1];
}
```

Ele retorna o valor do dicionário na chave 1, nada mais. Ele retornará um inteiro para quem chamou a função.

Analisando "quem chamou" `GetValue()`...

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 classe = new Class1();
    classe.GetValue();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Nesse caso, o valor evaluado de `GetValue()` não está sendo armazenado e nem usado para nada. Esse valor é retornado porém não utilizado.

Como no seu caso, você quer imprimir na tela, em aplicações console (que é seu caso), você pode utilizar o método [`WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx), da classe `Console`.

> **Console.WriteLine(int)**: Grava a representação em texto (cadeia de caracteres) do inteiro especificado, seguido pelo terminador de linha atual para o fluxo de saída padrão.

Trocando em miúdos, grava o valor do inteiro em forma de texto (tipo `String`) para o fluxo de saída padrão, que é o Console.

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 classe = new Class1();
    Console.WriteLine(classe.GetValue());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

No caso, `classe.GetValue()` será evaluado e impresso na tela através do `Console.WriteLine`.

Retomando ao início, `Console.WriteLine` é um daqueles métodos que não possuem um retorno, `void`.

Leitura obrigatória: **instrução** [**`return`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return).

Comment: Falo algo sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122434/101

Answer (score 2):

O `return` não imprime nada na tela, apenas retorna, o correto é fazer isso:

```
class Program {

    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 classe = new Class1();
        Console.WriteLine(classe.GetValue());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu vi em alguns tutoriais o uso do return. Por exemplo, pra demonstrar a área de um retângulo, tem um método AreaRetanuglo() e dentro dele tem return (resultado). O valor do return não vai pra nenhum lugar?

Comment: @Nash vai para o local que a função foi chamada, como se você tivesse colocado esse valor no lugar da função. Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, se melhorar o que está querendo saber pode obter melhores respostas. No seu código vai para alugar nenhum. NO código do Roberto é resultado é usado como argumento do `Console.WriteLine()` e imprime seu valor (a grosso modo).