# Por que no Angular usamos a tipagem ": void"?

Tags: angular, funções, typescript, tipagem

Por que no Angular usamos a tipagem  `: void`? Exemplo:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void` significa algo inexistente. Não é algo específico do Angular e sim do TypeScript, na verdade até na imensa maioria das [linguagens de programação de tipagem estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). Por simplificação as linguagens só criam funções, que pressupõem que sempre haverá um resultado e ele será retornado para quem chamou (existe uma ou outra que preferiu separar e criar [*procedures* que não possuem retorno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101)). Então, o que fazer quando a função não retorna um valor, nem mesmo um valor nulo? Convencionou-se usar o `void` indicando que nada será retornado.

Isto ocorre em funções que na verdade não são bem funções, são procedimentos a serem executados e só. Angular usa em vários casos, você só manda executar e não espera um resultado. O que você esperaria receber em `ngAfterViewInit()`? Nada, ele só está inicializando algo, fez isso, acaba e não devolve nada.

Você não pode usar essas funções em [expressões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).