# Quem é quem no uso de funções?

Tags: funções, terminologia, lógica, característica-linguagem

Tenho procurado muito, e tem muito conteúdo bom aqui, que abrange esse tema, entretanto ainda não consegui entender o funcionamento.

Os personagens a que me refiro são:

- Funções
- Parâmetros
- Argumentos
- Valores
- Variáveis
- Escopo

A resposta que tenho procurado, é um exemplo de um código com 2 ou mais funções, de forma que ficasse explícito o relacionamento e a necessidade desse relacionamento entre os personagens.

Vou tentar produzir um código que reflita minha dúvida.

#### Exemplo

[retirado dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135572/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-escopo-e-tempo-de-vida)

```cs
class Teste {
    int x = 5; //escopo da classe, tempo de vida de acordo com a instância
    StringBuilder txt; //o mesmo
    int Metodo(int y) { //parâmetro existe dentro da função escopo/lifetime 
        var x = 2; //note que há ambiguidade com a variável da classe
        var t = new StringBuilder(10); //variável e objeto locais vivem até a função
        for (var z = 0; z < 10; z++) { //só existe dentro deste bloco
            WriteLine(this.x * x + y * z); //desambigua e usa todas variáveis
        } //z morre aqui
        //uma tentativa de acessar z aqui produziria erro
        for (var z = 0; z < 10; z++) { //este z é diferente do outro
            t.Append(z.ToString()); //declarada fora, continuará existindo no fim do bloco
        } //z morre aqui
        txt = t; //a variável vai morrer o seu objeto sobreviverá em txt
        return x; //o valor será copiado para algum lugar, será um novo objeto igual
    } //aqui morrem x (local), y, t (não seu objeto, qua ainda tem referência)
}
static class Program {
    static int x = 10; //escopo desta classe tempo de vida da aplicação
    static void Main() { //só existe dentro desta classe
        StringBuilder t; //vive por toda função
        { //inicia um novo escopo
            var y = new Teste(); //variável e objeto têm escopo e tempo de vida deste bloco
            x = y.Metodo(3); //este x nada tem a ver com o x da outra classe, nem poderia
            t = y.txt; //o texto ainda viverá
        } //y morre aqui, seu objeto precisa viver mais porque tem uma referência para ele
        WriteLine(t); //o texto 0123456789 será impresso, ainda vive
        //não é possível acessar o conteúdo de y mais, mesmo o objeto estando vivo
        //o escopo acabou,só a referência previamente existente ainda pode acessar o objeto
    } //aqui morre t e finalmente o objeto criado por new Teste()
} //note que x não segura uma referência para o objeto, seu resultado é uma cópia
//código para demonstração simples, não faça isto em casa
```

Quem são os argumentos, qual a relação com os parâmetros e a relação entre esses e o escopo?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/91) e [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/91)

Comment: @rray eu já li e reli umas 10 vezes essas resposta, são completas... Mas o que não entendo... Acho que se a 1º , abordasse também a questão, o uso e a relação entre parâmetros e argumentos nesse contexto, poderia ser até duplicada, se juntar as 2 aí duplica, mas ainda assim eu fico a esclarecer a relação dos parâmetros e argumentos, no contexto de funções, bloco e escopo... De verdade ray, eu consigo entender as respostas relacionadas... mas falta um tantinho para eu entender todo esse relacionamento...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
function funcao(parametro) {
    var variavel = 1;
    return parametro + variavel * 2;
}
var x = 4;
console.log(funcao(x + 3));
```

Fiz em JS só porque é o mais fácil de postar aqui. Vale para qualquer linguagem, embora o escopo costume ter algumas variações em casos específicos, não nesse.

## Função

`funcao` é a função :P, este é um identificador que referencia um bloco de código a ser executado. Esse identificador funciona como uma constante onde o seu valor é o endereço de onde está o código dessa função. Então quando o código chamar a função haverá uma instrução para desviar o fluxo de execução do algoritmo para o local onde está esse código.

Essa constante pode ter escopo global (toda a aplicação enxerga esse nome), ou pode estar confinado a um módulo, classe, etc. Então você só pode chamar a função se ela estiver em escopo que aquele trecho de código que faz chamada tem acesso naquele momento.

Há uma forma e declarar funções em linguagens, especialmente em JS, onde [esse identificador é uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101).

É comum, mas não obrigatório (porque não é matemática pura), que a função retorne um valor. Isso costuma ser feito com o comando `return`. Ele é usado para encerrar o fluxo de execução da função, geralmente devolvendo para quem chamou um resultado.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine).

## Parâmetro

Essa função tem declarada entre os parênteses uma variável chamada `parametro`. Sim, ela é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) local à função, só tem o [escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) equivalente ao tempo de execução da função, só existe dentro dela. Mas é uma variável especial, ela é chamada de parâmetro porque receberá um valor no momento da chamada dela.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)).

## Argumento

Quando chama a função, além de desviar o fluxo de execução para o código dela, é passado um valor para ela, esse valor é é um argumento.

Se não existisse escopo, ou seja, se todas variáveis fossem visíveis na aplicação toda, o que seria terrível para lidar com isso, então seria quase como fazer isso:

```
function funcao() {
    var variavel = 1;
    return parametro + variavel * 2;
}
x = 4;
parametro = x + 3;
console.log(funcao());
```

O argumento pode ser uma expressão qualquer, pode ser um valor, pode ser uma variável ou um cálculo que gere algum valor.

[Entenda a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Não podemos dizer que o argumento tenha escopo, afinal ele não tem um identificador, o seu tempo de vida é só o tempo em que ele foi criado. Não confundir argumento com uma variável que está sendo usada como único elemento de uma expressão usada como argumento. Uma variável sendo usada como argumento é algo apenas circunstancial.

Note que no exemplo o argumento é o valor resultado da expressão `x + 3`.

A função `funcao()` retorna um valor que é usado como argumento para a função `log()` do objeto `console`.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function) (no artigo sobre parâmetro tem informações mais específicas para computação).

## Variável

A [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é apenas um identificador, portanto um nome para um endereço da memória onde existe um valor. Para o computador isso não interessa, é só uma forma do programar enxergar melhor o que está fazendo. Variável é uma forma de armazenamento de valores com um nome associado. Podemos dizer que ela é só um padrão de projeto para facilitar o acesso à valores na memória, tão usado que ninguém enxerga como um padrão de projeto.

[Função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) também é um padrão de projeto para segregar um conjunto de códigos e criar uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para sua execução. Na verdade tudo o que você faz são padrões de projeto encrustados na sintaxe da linguagem para facilitar sua vida.

Quando é uma variável e essa guarda uma referência para um objeto há uma semântica própria já que qualquer alteração no objeto referenciando em `parametro` afetará o que está na variável do argumento. Mas não é o caso do exemplo.

No exemplo há uma variável local à `função`, além do parâmetro, chamada `variavel`, Ela não é necessária ali, foi criada só para dar um exemplo. Depois ela é usada na expressão que produzirá o resultado desejado.

Também há uma outra variável chamada `x`, também só criada para dar exemplo, que tem escopo toda a aplicação nesse exemplo simples. Isso vale para JavaScript, não é ideal que seja assim. Se estivesse dentro de uma função, o escopo seria apenas dentro da função. Isso pode ser visto no exemplo um pouco modificado:

```js
function funcao(parametro) {
    var variavel = 1;
    console.log(x); // <========= idealmente não deveria ser acessível aqui
    return parametro + variavel * 2;
}
var x = 4;
console.log(funcao(x + 3));
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)).

[O que acontece quando chamamos uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101).

## Valor

Valor é o que se guarda na variável, o que tem dentro do seu objeto. Variáveis que são tipo por valor tem o valor na própria variável. Quando ela é de um tipo por referência o valor na verdade é a referência (ponteiro) e o valor que interessa mesmo está em um objeto em outro lugar.

Veja mais em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

É comum um valor ser definido por um literal, mas em muitos casos ele é obtido de outras formas através de expressões.

Exemplo usando uma variável por referência onde o objeto é alterado:

```js
function funcao(parametro) {
    parametro.a = 3;
    return parametro.a + parametro.b;
}
var x = { a : 1, b : 2 };
console.log(funcao(x));
console.log(x.a);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/InternalDecomposing.js).

JavaScript passa a referência, mas ela é imutável, você pode apenas mudar objeto, mas não a própria referência. Outras linguagens permitem que o objeto seja trocado por completo. Mas isso é característica específica.

Note que o escopo das variáveis não mudam, mas o tempo de vida do objeto muda e é dependente de como o algoritmo é executado. O tempo de vida das variáveis também não mudam.

No exemplo inicial 1, 2, 3, e 4 são literais com valores. O `return` tem uma expressão que gerará um outro valor (ele não é guardado em variáveis, não precisa, mas ele está na memória e depois pode ser atribuída a uma variável, mas é um passo independente. O argumento é formado por um valor que também é obtido com uma expressão e não está em variável ali, é apenas passado para a função. O resultado da função é um valor que equivale ao que foi calculado na função na linha do `return`.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)).

## Escopo

Já *linkei* onde pode ter detalhes (não vou repetir aqui, se tem dúvidas específicas que não ficaram claras, pode comentar lá ou até colocar uma recompensa pedindo melhorias ou novas respostas), mas é só onde um determinado identificador está visível no código, ou seja, onde ele pode ser usado e será válido.

Dependendo da linguagem o escopo pode ser a função, a classe, um bloco de código específico (comumente o que está entre chaves), módulo (ou *namespace*), até mesmo a aplicação toda. O que é declarado ali dentro não pode ser visto fora dessa área do código.

Escopo é um conceito de codificação. Ele não importa durante a execução, isso é totalmente abstraído. O tempo de vida é o que importa durante a execução.

O escopo tem a ver com identificadores.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

## Identificador

É o nome que se dá para um objeto qualquer (num sentido amplo, não importa o que seja esse objeto). Em geral ele precisa ser único em um escopo (uma região do código). Há regras do que pode ser usado nesse nome. Ele é usado para dar uma identidade para o objeto.

Também chamamos de símbolo.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier).

## Literal

É uma sintaxe que representa de forma explícita e direta um valor. Ele é o valor na sua forma mais "pura". É mais comum ser visto em objetos simples como inteiros e decimais (ex.: `123`, `456.78`), mas também é usado em alguns mais complexos, como *string* (`"texto aqui"`), *array* e objeto - no sentido de estrutura de dados - (`{ 1, 2, 3 }`, sintaxe que serve para os dois, depende da linguagem) e alguns consideram até mesmo outros objetos de forma mais nominal (`DateTime(2016, 11, 03)`), mas isso não é consenso.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)).

## Expressão

É a combinação de um ou mais valores, constantes, variáveis, operadores, e funções que a linguagem interpreta de acordo com certas regras e cria um resultado (é feito um "cálculo") que é um novo valor. O processo que calcula esse valor é chamado de "avaliação".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)).

Comment: O ponteiro seria o atributo do objeto,  ou viajei ?

Comment: @MagicHat em JS você não vê o ponteiro nunca. Para isso teria que fazer em C, C++, ou linguagens assim, de médio nível. Em JS o ponteiro está lá, mas você não o vê ou manipula ele. Veja um exemplo em C onde o ponteiro é manipulado diretamente: http://ideone.com/DVsU51

Comment: Tá vendo, quando eu falo que C é orientado a objetos, todo mundo me zoa..kkk Vlw, man ...Com todo essa informação tenho certeza que se eu der uma estudada e fizer uns testes vou entender... Belo material...

Comment: @MagicHat se tiver dúvidas específicas, poste.

Comment: Muitas vezes dúvidas específicas, rodeiam uma maré de termos e condições, mas sempre que a linguagem ou inspiração me permitem, eu procuro ser específico e objetivo... Vlw a força.

Comment: Seria `$this`, um tipo de ponteiro em JS ?

Comment: O `this` em todas as linguagens costuma ser um ponteiro para o objeto. Uma coisa que eu falo que para aprender direito mesmo é sempre melhor aprender da base pra cima, onde se entende como o computador funciona, porque existe cada coisa, e aí as abstrações que vão sendo construídas em cima disto, mas hoje quase todo mundo aprender decorar uma casa que não tem nem alicerce. Procurando saber essas coisas, abrem portas para saber como usar as coisas da forma correta. Falo um pouco sobre isso em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101.

Answer (score 7):

## Função

Uma função pode ser vista como um contentor de instruções, ela por si só não faz nada. Apenas executa as instruções quando é chamada.

## Parâmetros e argumentos

Como o @rray comentou a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento [já está explicada na outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32448/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-par%C3%A2metro-e-argumento), mas deixo aqui a parte essencial:

Uma função pode ter parâmetros. O chamador da função, chama-a com determinados valores (argumentos) :

```
function foo(a/*parametero a*/){/**/}

foo(1) //chama foo com argumento 1, o parametro a toma o valor 1
```

## Variáveis e valores

Uma variável tem sempre um identificador. As variáveis armazenam um valor. Exemplo:

```
var a = 1; //variável com identificador a
//a variável a tem valor 1
```

## Escopo

Um escopo normalmente é definido entre a abertura de chaveta `{` e fecho de chaveta `}`

```
{
   //este é um escopo
}
```

Com base nesta definição você chega á conclusão que todas as funções tem um escopo também.

```
function foo(){
   //este éo escopo da funcao foo
}
```

Normalmente as variáveis pertencem sempre a um escopo e não podem ser vistas fora dele. Contudo os escopos podem ser aninhados. Os escopos filhos podem ver as variáveis do escopo pai. Exemplo:

```
function foo(){
   var a = 1;
   while(true){
       //este é o escopo do while;
       a++;//o while consegue ver/modificar a
   }
}
```

A ideia de escopo costuma ser um pouco difícil de entender a fundo. Por exemplo a última coisa que eu me apercebi em relação aos escopos é que não há nada que o impeça de definir um escopo por determinado motivo. Exemplo:

```
function foo(){
    {
        //este código tem uma lógica
        var a = 1;
    }
    {
        //este código tem outra lógica um pouco diferente e eu quero definir um escopo para ele
       var a = 2;
       //nao há qualquer conflito de identificadores porque sao escopos diferentes
    }
}
```

Com base nos comentários (e isto é importante):

**Os escopos podem funcionar de forma diferente consoante a linguagem**, o exemplo que acabei de dar nao se aplica a `javascript` por exemplo...

Comment: Bem didático, tá clareando... deixa eu ver a outra resposta... Vou entender isso hoje custe o que custar...

Comment: `var` é escopo por função, não por bloco... está errado o que foi dito ai no último exemplo.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Eu nunca falei de `javascript` na minha resposta, ou falei?

Comment: @BrunoCosta ah, desculpe, supôs isso por costume