# O que acontece quando chamamos uma função?

Tags: c, funções

No nível das instruções de máquina, o que acontecerá na chamada?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Introdução

Não sei se sabe, mas todo código C é compilado para um [código de máquina que vai instruir o processador fazer algo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101). Esse código de máquina é ideal para o computador, mas difícil para o humano entender, por isso temos linguagens de mais alto nível com conceitos que entendemos melhor.

[Função é um conceito matemático](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) que aplicamos na programação. De forma direta ela não existe no código de máquina. As instruções possíveis são:

- operações numéricas simples,
- movimento de dados entre memória e registradores,
- controle de fluxo de execução de forma simples.

## Chamada e retorno

A chamada da função na verdade é uma instrução [`CALL`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) que na verdade é como se fosse um `GOTO` (ou `JMP`, como é conhecido em Assembly), portanto ele apenas desvia a execução da aplicação para o endereço onde está o código que seria a função. A diferença básica do `CALL` é que ele guarda o endereço para onde ele deve voltar em uma pilha, assim quando estiver dentro da função e encontrar uma instrução [`RET`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html), ela pegará o endereço que está no topo da pilha para dar outro `GOTO` para ele e desviar a execução para este endereço. Então de certa forma podemos dizer que a função é só isto.

Na verdade a função, ou seja, o código de máquina gerado precisa de um cabeçalho (prólogo) e rodapé (epílogo) que você programador não se dá conta porque é algo que não importa para seu entendimento do seu código.

Como todas operações são realizadas em registradores e você não pode perder os dados que estão lá porque a execução normal provavelmente ainda precisa deles e conta que eles estarão lá quando há um desvio para uma função é necessário preservar o estado dos registradores.

Então é colocada algumas instruções antes do [código de máquina gerado pela compilação do seu código C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) que faz este trabalho [guardando seus dados em uma pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Ao final da execução do seu código é necessário restaurar o estado dos registradores pegando o que está na pilha, isto ocorre sempre antes de uma instrução `RET`.

Normalmente haverá um símbolo global da aplicação para conter o endereço de onde o código da função está, assim o código que chamar pode usar o que conhecemos como variável (a grosso modo). Isto é importante porque é comum que o endereço real de execução não seja real, mesmo considerando que estamos em memória virtual, então entenda que real não é nem do endereço físico que estou falando, não é sabido até que esse código seja carregado na memória, por isso precisa usar esse símbolo e não um endereço real. Pelo menos em funções que poderão ser chamadas de qualquer parte do código e não podem ser otimizadas para conter o endereço direto.

## Argumentos, parâmetros e retorno

Claro que a função pode ter passagem de [argumentos para parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Se isto ocorrer é necessário transferir os valores deles para sua função, isto costuma se dar na pilha.

Como na verdade o código final gerado não é compartimentado em funções e sim é uma coisa só, na verdade o que está fazendo é copiar os dados de uma variável para outra, ou seja, equivale a uma simples atribuição.

Mas na verdade não existem variáveis em código de máquina. O que você faz é transportar dados da memória para outro ponto da memória, passando pelos registradores, e como otimização ele pode transportar da memória para o registrador, ou até mesmo do registrador para registrador quando é possível.

É comum se tentar fazer apenas movimentos entre registradores por serem muito mais rápidos, mas nem, sempre é possível, até porque se tiver muitos parâmetros não tem registradores suficientes, e nem todos podem ser usados para isso e também tem dados que não cabem no registrador. O que é copiado são dados numéricos simples que cabem no registrador, lembrando que `char` é um dado numérico, ponteiros, lembrando que [*array* é apenas um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101), e dados em `structs` que não costumam ir em registradores.

O mesmo ocorre com o retorno. Em geral é destacado um registrador para que ele seja feito. Assim como ocorre na passagem de parâmetros, há uma [convenção de qual registrador será usado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) para o dado retornado que o código que chamou já terá que usar quando terminar o código da função ([convenção do x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)). Normalmente o retorno da função só não entra em registrador quando é grande demais e pode ser colocado na memória diretamente no local da variável ou local temporário de armazenamento contido na função chamadora.

Os parâmetros podem ser considerados variáveis locais da função, então o que está fazendo é colocar valores nessas variáveis. Então tudo vai pra pilha de execução na memória, se não puder otimizar para registrador.

## Exemplo real

Claro que o que eu acabei de descrever é o mais comum, depende da arquitetura do processador pode funcionar um pouco diferente. Algum compilador C pode fazer algumas coisas um pouco diferentes, desde que cumpra o que está na especificação da linguagem.

Pense em uma função C assim:

```
int add(int i,int j) {
    int p = i + j;
    return p;
}
```

O código compilado ficaria algo assim:

```
.globl add
add:
    pushl %ebp          //cabeçalho salvando em pilha o registrador que será manipulado
    movl %esp, %ebp     //joga o ponteiro da pilha em ebp
    subl $4, %esp       //aloca espaço (4 bytes) na pilha para a variável p
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx  //8(%ebp) é o i, só atribuição do que está na pilha + 8 bytes
    addl 12(%ebp), %edx //12(%ebp) é o j, aqui já faz a adição, edx é o outro operando
    movl %edx, -4(%ebp) //-4(%ebp) é o p, atribuição
    movl -4(%ebp), %eax //eax é o registrador de retorno
    leave               //é o mesmo que dar movl %ebp, %esp; popl %ebp ret, é o rodapé
```

`%esp` é registrador com o ponteiro do local da pilha atual. Quando tem um `12(%ebp)` é o endereço apontado pelo valor que etá no registrador `%ebp` mais 12 bytes. `%ebp` é onde começa o *frame* da pilha desta função.

A chamada a esta função será algo assim:

```
add(1, 2)
```

Em Assembly:

```
pushl $2  //joga o segundo parâmetro na pilha
pushl $1  //joga o primeiro parâmetro na pilha
call add  //desvia para a função
```

Experimente você mesmo, faça códigos simples, compile usando o GCC com opção `-S` e veja o Assembly resultante dele. No Visual C é `/FA`.

O resultado nem sempre será o mesmo, depende um pouco do compilador.

Existe sintaxe do Assembly diferente. Se usar o GCC 7 e usar sintaxe Intel a função gerada será:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
add     eax, edx
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
pop     rbp
ret
```

Veja no [**Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/g/WL8NtK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/LowLevel.c).

## Conclusão

Parece complicado, mas conforme vai aprendendo fica fácil, porque na verdade os conceitos mais simples são os concretos. Por isso que eu costumo dizer que as pessoas deveriam aprender programar de baixo para cima, com Assembly, ou pelo menos C, entendendo tudo o que ocorre no processo de compilação, deixando as abstrações para depois.

Em resumo é isto, obviamente fiz simplificações, se quiser entender mesmo precisa pesquisar algo mais profundo e preciso, se tiver dúvidas específicas, faça novas perguntas.