# Uma propriedade ocupa espaço no objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, memória, propriedade

Estava lendo uma [pergunta sobre propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101) e vi que ela é ao mesmo tempo um ou dois métodos.

Tem algum custo adicional em memória e processamento em usá-la? Se não usar o código pode ficar mais otimizado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A propriedade mesmo é um método, ou um par de métodos `get` e `set`. Então, como todo método, um espaço da memória é ocupado para o código do método um vez na aplicação, não importa quantas vezes seja usado. É algo muito pequeno e praticamente pode ser desconsiderado.

Como todo método, há uma execução de código e há um custo de processamento que depende do que será executado. Mesmo [um método vazio tem algum custo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101), se não for otimizado.

Então se está só atribuindo ou pegando um valor tem um *overhead* se comparado a fazer isso direto no campo.

Se quer saber se ele ocupa um espaço na instância, não, a propriedade em si não ocupa. Mas é muito comum que ela acesse um campo, na verdade até é possível que encapsule esse campo. O espaço do campo cria um custo no objeto, mas se a propriedade não tem um campo vinculado não há custo.

Só note que isto

```
public int prop { get; set; }
```

por definição tem um campo associado a ele mesmo que não apareça no código, então esse campo ocupará espaço. Nesse exemplo como ele é um `int` ocupará 4 bytes.

Já

```
public bool prop { get => status > 0; }
```

não tem um campo direto, então não ocupa nada a mais. Claro que esse campo `status` é um campo que ocupará um espaço, mas ele não está vinculado à propriedade `prop`, esta propriedade não cria *overhead* no objeto.

Note que a propriedade pode facilitar a manutenção e o versionamento, mas ela impõe um custo de processamento por mais simples que seja. Em geral é bom o seu uso, mas se precisar muito da melhor performance possível o acesso ao campo direto pode ser melhor, assim não chama código algum extra. [Tem uma pergunta para entender melhor a vantagem de usar uma propriedade para encapsular um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objeto = new Classe(1);
        WriteLine(objeto.IsFree);
    }
}

public class Classe {
    public Classe(int x) => status = x;
    private int status; //aqui ocupa 4 bytes
    public bool IsFree { get => status > 0; } //aqui nada ocupa na instância
    public int Id { get; } = 0; //aqui ocupará 4 bytes porque tem um campo implícito
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QtuFsD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ncURyX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Memory/PropertyMemory.cs).