# Campo público X propriedade

Tags: c#, variáveis, propriedade, getters-setters, encapsulamento

Tenho uma *string* definida como "nome" inicialmente ela está como `private`.

```
string nome;
```

No caso eu atribuo os métodos *get*/*set*, e para ficar no padrão eu altero a letra inicial para maiúsculo, ficando:

```
string Nome { get; set; };
```

Agora eu consigo acessar sem problemas a variável nome através dos *get*/*set*.

Para fazer isso o que muda eu colocar o código acima da seguinte forma?

```
public string Nome
```

Dessa forma ele irá acessar igualmente como se fosse *get*/*set*, não é mais pratico e "clean" então fazer dessa forma?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293801/112052 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/112052

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15467/m%c3%a9todos-e-propriedades-em-c-vantagens-e-desvantagens)

Comment: Isso chama-se encapsulamento, um conceito de OO, dá uma lida sobre isso e veja os links acima que postaram que você vai entender

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

> No caso eu atribuo os métodos *get*/*set*, e para ficar no padrão eu altero a letra inicial para maiúsculo, ficando:
>
> ```
> string Nome { get; set; };
> ```
>
> Agora eu consigo acessar sem problemas a variável nome através dos *get*/*set*.

Ok, muita gente faz isso, agora você acessará um campo privado (sim, ele será privado automaticamente), e neste caso os métodos de acesso chamados *getter* e *setter* serão `public`.

> Para fazer isso o que muda eu colocar o código acima da seguinte forma:
>
> ```
> public string Nome
> ```
>
> Dessa forma ele irá acessar igualmente como se fosse *get*/*set*, não é mais pratico e "clean" então fazer dessa forma?

A primeira mudança mais óbvia é que finalmente tornou o campo público, e nem desconfiava que as outras não era assim.

Outra questão importante é que está chamando atributo porque [quase todo mundo não sabe o nome disto e te ensinaram errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). O nome disso é campo.

Sua percepção de que isso pode ser melhor é válida e acima da média. Muitas pessoas aprenderam a fórmula que deve usar a propriedade e aceita isto como se fosse verdade absoluta sem questionar. Programador é um engenheiro, ele deve ser questionador. Ele tem que funcionar como um *chef* de cozinha, não um cozinheiro de receitas de bolo. Você está no caminho certo.

De fato em muitos casos essa é a melhor forma. Se nenhuma ação deve ser feita quando você atribui um valor ao campo ou quando pega um valor dele. É mais rápido e mais simples, e costuma ser o que você quer.

Se você quer colocar uma ação, seja uma validação, um cálculo antes de entregar um valor, ou disparar um evento, não importa o que, aí precisa da propriedade.

A parte legal do C# é que campo e propriedade tem sintaxe idêntica para acessar. Então você começa usando o campo e se um dia precisa ter um código extra no acesso, você muda de campo para propriedade sem problemas. Ou quase :)

Mas no seu caso está usando a propriedade simples, então por que fazer assim?

Em aplicações simples onde você compila toda ela junto realmente não faz sentido, é perda de tempo. Mesmo que tenha alguma otimização não tem vantagem usar a propriedade de cara.

Mas se você cria um arquivo *assembly* de forma independe de outras partes da aplicação, se esse *assembly* é parte de uma biblioteca ou *framework* independente que é usado em outras aplicações, aí você está enrascado se precisa mudar de campo para propriedade. Se mudar no seu código e todos os códigos consumidores não forem mudados, vai dar problema.

Dependendo de como fizer dará erro ou acessará o campo diretamente sem passar pelos métodos *getter* e *setter*, e não é mais o que você quer. Antes era acesso direto, agora você quer esse método de *proxy*. Muda tudo. Então se tivesse feito com propriedade desde o início não precisaria modificar nada no consumidor, você teria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e o código interno, se é o acesso básico ou com alguma lógica extra, é detalhe de implementação, em qualquer caso ele vai chamar o método, apenas o que ele vai fazer pode mudar de acordo com o código que está no *assembly* da sua classe onde está esse campo que nunca é acessado diretamente.

Algumas pessoas consideram fazer sempre assim como uma "boa prática". E eu falo sempre que boa prática é seguir receita de bolo sem saber o que está fazendo. Quando sabe o que está fazendo deixa de ser boa prática e passar ser um conhecimento aplicado corretamente, ainda que seja a mesma coisa.

Uma nota importante também é que [a propriedade pode existir independente de um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203908/101), ele pode ser só um método de acesso que faz um cálculo e te entrega. Ou pode dar um valor fixo. E claro, pode envolver vários campos e até outras propriedades.

[image: Algo como um diagrama de Venn com crenças, verdade, e conhecimento que é um subconjunto das crenças verdadeiras]

Veja mais em:

- [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)
- [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101)
- [Como transformar os atributos em propriedades?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149348/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [Deveríamos utilizar todas variáveis como privadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202227/101)
- [Por que é uma má prática ter atributos int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132272/101)
- [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101)
- [Propriedade x Atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101)
- [Exemplo real do uso de encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293801/101)
- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)
- [Padrão de nomenclatura no código para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101)

Eu estou estudando porque apesar de eu mesmo já ter respondido isso, não sei se é exatamente encapsulamento como muitos acham, eu posso ter aprendido errado como todo mundo. Isso é uma abstração, não sei se é encapsulamento. Talvez não seja, e aí entramos em outra questão que não cobri aqui é que alguns dizem que não deve usar métodos *getter/setter* ou propriedades.

[image: Placa enferrujada com Mythbusted]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

O public permite a você acessar essa variável, ou até mesmo outras classes, métodos, etc, através de outras classes. Por exemplo, se você tiver uma variável definida como `private`, você não conseguirá acessá-la de outro lugar, somente na classe em que foi definida. O mesmo serve para os métodos. Outro exemplo é se você criar um objeto, mas a classe estiver definida como private, você não conseguirá instanciá-lo quando precisar, a menos que você o faça na própria classe em que o criou.

É como o próprio nome já diz, public tornará o item "público" e private o tornará "privado".

Comment: Isso eu entendo, a dúvida é, se eu for ter o get/set não é mais facil simplesmente tornar public para não precisar adicionar o get/set ?

Comment: Você está confundindo o que é acesso ao item (variável, método, classe...) definidos como public ou private, com acesso à modificação e visualização do valor. O Set te possibilita alterar o valor da variável, e o Get te possibilita obter esse valor quando precisar. Somente isso.

Comment: sim eu entendo, mas no caso se for fazer uma alteração sem validação,  ou simplesmente pegar um valor, porque fazer ele private se podemos fazer ele public sem precisar adicionar os metodos get/set?

Comment: Agora entendi onde você quer chegar. É uma questão de segurança nesse caso, os getters e setters são adotados como um padrão pra acesso aos atributos de uma classe. Não é bom você ter acesso diretamente ao atributo na maioria dos casos. Um exemplo disso é caso você tenha uma variável inteira mas que não pode ser negativa, um setter resolveria o problema muito facilmente.

Comment: sim, mas no caso estamos falando de tratamento, nesse caso precisa do set, agora apenas setar um valor, não se torna necessário ficar criando vários códigos get/set porque a segurança será a mesma . Acabei de ler, e vou acrescentar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25995/getters-e-setters-s%c3%a3o-uma-ilus%c3%a3o-do-encapsulamento

Comment: Isso, exatamente. Não são todas as propriedades que necessitam, justamente por não precisar disso, deve-se analisar e identificar a necessidade ou não.

Comment: Não é uma questão de segurança. E a explicação no penúltima comentário enrola e diz nada, na verdade diz o oposto do que foi perguntado, porque ele disse que não quer fazer validação e aí diz que é para isso que serve. Leia minha resposta e entenda que quase ninguém sabe porque fazer isso, apenas fazem porque alguém mandou.

Comment: @Maniero Você tem total razão, é o que foi ensinado na faculdade e apenas dito que era o ideal, mas não o porquê. Enfim, sou iniciante ainda e aos poucos pretendo me atentar e mudar a visão de que tudo que foi ensinado é o certo e começar a questionar o porque das coisas mais vezes. Sua resposta esclareceu muito!

Comment: Quando alguém não fala o porquê ignore. Dei uma palestra sobre isto esta semana. Se mudar a visão geral encaminhará bem, mesmo que ainda tenha certos vícios, porque quando nem se sabe o caminho nada resolve, sabendo o resto vai resolvendo sozinho com o tempo. Infelizmente o estado da educação é assim só passam receita de bolo e não produzem pensadores.

Comment: @Maniero, essa frase é muito boa "Infelizmente o estado da educação é assim só passam receita de bolo e não produzem pensadores".

Answer (score -1):

Dentro da classe que você declarou não importa se está `string nome;` ou `string Nome { get; set; }`.
Dá na mesma. No primeiro jeito, o get/set está implicito, mas ainda está lá. Se tirasse o `set`, ela ficaria `readonly`, aí sim mudaria. 
A diferença vai ser pra acessar de outra classe. 
Se declarar do pimeiro ou segundo jeito(`string nome;` ou `string Nome { get; set; }`), não vai ser possível acessar de outra classe, só se colocar o modificador de acesso como público.