# Acessar atributo de objeto passado como parâmetro genérico

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

Na minha aplicação tenho uma classe de lista encadeada que recebe um parâmetro genérico, que será o tipo do valor que a lista guardará. Neste caso, que estou passando como parâmetro a classe `Usuario`, preciso verificar se já existe um `Usuario` cadastrado com o CPF informado. Para isso, criei o método `Procura`, ao qual informo o valor que desejo comparar e o atributo que preciso acessar, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto.'
>
> System.Type.GetProperty(...) retornou null.

Aparentemente, `GetProperty()` está retornando nulo. Como posso resolver esse problema?

```
public class ListaEncadeada<T>{

    ...

    public Boolean Procura(String valor, String atributo)
    {
        var atual = cabeca;
        while (atual != null)
        {
            var obj = atual.Valor;
            String aux = obj.GetType().GetProperty(atributo).GetValue(obj).ToString();
            if (aux == valor)
            {
                return true;
            }
            atual = atual.Proximo;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    //verificar se já existe um usuário com o cpf informado.
    listaUsuario.Procura(valor, "cpf");
}
```

.

```
public class Usuario
{
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String senha;

    ...
 }
```

Comment: A propriedade `cpf` existe, com esse mesmo nome (atenção ao _case sensitive_) no objeto `obj`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, existe na classe Usuario, a qual o objeto pertence.

Comment: Faça `debug` e verifique se a objeto `obj` fica corretamente preenchido, de que tipo é e se tem as propriedades que pretende.

Comment: @JoãoMartins, sim, fiz o debug e o objeto está corretamente preenchido, mas utilizando o método GetProperties() nada é retornado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos combinar usar os termos corretos. [Você está chamando de atributo o que na verdade chama-se campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). E esse pode ter sido o motivo por ter usado o método de reflexão errado. Se você quer pegar um campo, use o [`GetField()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetField?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e não o `GetProperty()`, um campo é diferente de uma propriedade.

Tão pouco acho que deve mudar o campo para uma propriedade só para poder usar o método, cada um tem um motivo para usar. [Não vou questionar qual é o certo para você neste cenário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101), até porque não tem detalhes deste cenário, vou só confiar que [você precisava de campos e por isso os usou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101), e agora só precisa usar a reflexão correta para pegar o que precisa.

Eu só botei `public` abaixo para eu poder inicializar facilmente já que não consta um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (deveria).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var obj = new Usuario();
        obj.nome = "João";
        WriteLine(obj.GetType().GetField("nome").GetValue(obj).ToString());
    }
}

public class Usuario {
    public string nome;
    public string cpf;
    public string senha;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LabWXO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8YuBXW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetField.cs).

Um outro detalhe importante: a chance de algo sair errado aí é grande se o programar cometer um erro. Eu não vou tentar tratar porque não sei a sua necessidade, posso fazer algo que resolva o erro mas dê resultados inesperados, pode acabar engolindo o erro silenciosamente e ser pior ainda, só você sabe o que é adequado.

Uso de reflexão em C# quase sempre é errado, transforma a linguagem em dinâmica e passa carregar todas desvantagens deste tipo de linguagem. Está abrindo mão das vantagens do C#. Quase sempre tem soluções melhores. A reflexão quase sempre é para economizar digitação do programador, que é uma economia boba. Perde a robustez e perde performance. No mínimo isso deveria ser melhor tratado se vier um nome de campo inexistente, o que aumentaria a complexidade do código e diminuiria ainda mais a performance. Ou pode fazer uma ferramenta externa para analisar o código estaticamente, mas aí é mais fácil criar um gerador de código que dá o mesmo resultado sem usar reflexão.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está na forma como declarou as propriedades na classe `Usuario` (ou, neste caso, não declarou!), além do que as colocou todas como `Private`, sendo impossível algo de "fora" lhes aceder.

Se não colocar um *getter* e/ou um *setter*, `{ get; set; }`, as suas variáveis não vão passar disso, variáveis. Para que sejam efetivamente **propriedades**, necessita ter essa definição.

Neste cenário a solução passa por alterar a classe `Usuario` para o seguinte:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
}
```

Ao tentar obter o valor da propriedade, deverá sempre ter em atenção o facto de um dos `Get` poder devolver `null`, por isso recomenda-se essa validação, que pode ser feita da seguinte forma (utilizando o nulo condicional e a conversão para `string`):

```
string aux = Convert.ToString(usuario.GetType().GetProperty("cpf")?.GetValue(usuario));
```

Dessa forma a variável `aux` ou fica com o valor que se pretende ou com `empty string` (`""`).