# Maneira correta de sintaxe na instância de objeto

Tags: c#, sintaxe, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Na instância de um objeto, podemos:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
```

e também podemos:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(){ Nome = "Nome", Id = 0, Situacao = true };
```

Qual a melhor ou a mais correta maneira de se instanciar o objeto?

Comment: É a mesma coisa.

Comment: Augusto Henrique, na segunda você já está preenchendo valores dentro da instância... mas precisa fazer isso neste momento?

Comment: Na segunda versão, os parênteses `()` não são necessários.

Comment: @FabioIn não necessariamente nesse momento.

Comment: Escrevi errado... as chaves não são necessárias, pois passam parâmetros que não são necessários.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O mais importante sobre isto é que os dois fazem coisas completamente diferentes, então eles não são exatamente comparáveis. Este código seria comparável com o segundo da pergunta:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.Nome = "Nome";
pessoa.Id = 0;
pessoa.Situacao = true;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Initialization.cs).

O primeiro código da pergunta cria um objeto `Pessoa` e sem inicialização alguma, ou seja, o objeto existe, mas é inútil, todos seus dados são inválidos, ele é um perigo para sua aplicação. O segundo cria com alguns dados. Não sei se do jeito correto, se há validações nas propriedades (estou considerando que ali [são propriedades e não campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101)), e nada obriga você fazer desta forma.

Mas esse código está todo errado já pela modelagem da classe. Quase sempre um construtor sem parâmetros está errado. Veja [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Nenhum objeto deveria ser criado em estado inválido.

Então sim, ao contrário do que diz outra resposta, existe uma maneira correta para instanciar um objeto. Existem diversas maneiras corretas, e diversas erradas. As duas formas apresentadas são erradas pelo exposto acima. Embora não seja um erro conceitual gravíssimo ou que não possa ser útil em alguma situação, mas em quase todas situações não deveria fazer assim, o correto é ter um construtor que receba argumentos e crie um objeto em estado válido antes dele poder ser manipulado pelo código de forma possivelmente inadequada. Com um construtor adequado não dá a opção do consumidor inicializar errado.

E mesmo que uma outra resposta esteja tecnicamente correta ela valida esta prática ruim de ter um construtor sem parâmetros para objetos de negócios e outros. Claro, precisa saber de muitos mais detalhes sobre o problema para afirmar o que é certo ou errado. Acho um absurdo, mas os requisitos poderiam ser algo como "não importa se o objeto está em estado inválido", aí estaria certo, ainda que isto seria contra intuitivo e provavelmente um erro do requisito.

Answer (score 5):

Isso depende da sua necessidade ou facilidade que deseja ter.

A primeira ele vai instanciar a classe com os valores padrões das propriedades (0 para int, 0.0 para double, false para boolean, etc).

A segunda ele instancia e já passa diretamente o valor entre chaves para a propriedade. Note que os parenteses não são necessários neste caso se não há um construtor padrão ou que não receba nenhum parâmetro.

Você pode mudar o valor posteriormente, independente da forma que você fez, porém a segunda é bastante útil se você deseja instanciar com valores pré definidos diferente do padrão que o C# considera, sendo mais uma facilidade na hora de instanciar.

Answer (score 4):

Não existe necessariamente uma maneira correta para essa instância, as duas maneiras estão corretas, a principal diferença é que a primeira você consegue debugar o código e acessar seus membros separadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como grande parte da programação, não existe a forma **correta**, existe a forma que melhor se encaixa de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Mas qual a diferença entre essas duas formas citadas?

Primeiro temos que considerar que o IL vai transformar isto:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa()
{
   Nome = "Nome", 
   Id = 0, 
   Situacao = true 
};
```

em algo como isto:

```
Pessoa _tempPessoa = new Pessoa();
_tempPessoa.Nome = "Nome";
_tempPessoa.Id = 0.
_tempPessoa.Situacao = true;

Pessoa pessoa = _tempPessoa;
```

Portanto, a performance é a **mesma**! Não há alteração em tempo de execução.

**Vantagens do initializer**

- Atomicidade: o objeto nunca será parcialmente inicializado: ou é null, ou é 100% inicializado (como citado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740682/10577440))
- Melhor visibiliadde
- Menos código (pouco, mas não deixa de ser)

**Desvantagens do initializer**

- Pra debugar é um saco!!! Principalmente em estruturas aninhadas