# Por que existem as auto properties no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, propriedade

Eu tenho uma duvida, Por que no C# tem as *auto properties* que geralmente são usadas assim:

```
public double price {get; private set;}
```

sendo que por ela ser publica ela pode ser acessada diretamente e por cima não consigo diferenciar que estou mudando ela por uma função `Set` ou `Get`, ou muito menos tendo um nome diferente do atributo normal, exemplo:

```
public double Price
{
   get {return _price;}
   set {_price = value}
}
```

Qual a real necessidade delas?

Comment: Poderia ser um pouco mais claro sobre o que está tentando perguntar?

Comment: Eu acho que se está a referir a uns atalhos no visual studio prop + tab

Comment: basicamente eu queria saber o pq de usar o autoproperties invés de usar o padrão das demais linguagens que é fazer o get e set manualmente, eu queria saber oq eu ganharia com isso em respeito ás boas práticas e a manutenção de código !

Comment: Tenho a certeza então que ficou esclarecido com a resposta do @Maniero

Comment: sim sim ! obrigado pela compreensão

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As propriedades automáticas são apenas o que chamamos de *syntax sugar*, ou seja, uma forma para escrever menos código quando aquilo é o normal que você fará na maioria das vezes.

A pergunta está bastante confusa e por isso dá para inferir que deve fazer bastante confusão em muita coisa. O exemplo de cima é bem diferente do exemplo de baixo, afinal o de cima só permite atribuir valores à propriedade de maneira privada, e pode estar só falta parte do código, mas o de baixo não é exatamente igual ao de cima sem a parte faltante, vamos fazer algo mais correto:

```
public decimal price {get; set;}
```

Se transformará em:

```
private decimal price;
public decimal Price {
   get { return price; }
   set { price = value; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Desugar.cs).

Veja que declarei um campo ([não chama atributo como está imaginando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) com o tipo `decimal` que é o [adequado para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). E usei a palavra-chave `value` que é o correto para poder fazer a atribuição em uma propriedade (na pergunta original estava errado).

Obviamente que tem várias outras maneiras de criar uma propriedade, então nem sempre dá para usar as *auto properties*, a linguagem dá a flexibilidade necessária. Qual você prefere escrever?

Percebeu que não segue as boas práticas? Na verdade pesquise sobre o termo aqui no site, especialmente as minhas respostas pra ver o que acho delas. Você pode escapar da maldição das boas práticas (a maioria prefere não, mas você tem a chance).

Eu precisava citar os vários problemas que tem na sua perguntas. Se deseja mais informações já foi respondido em:

- [Propriedade Vs Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101) (teme muitos *links* importantes nela)
- [Uma propriedade ocupa espaço no objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203908/101)
- [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101)
- [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)
- [Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101)

Comment: entendi perfeitamente, muito obrigado !