# Não estou conseguindo fazer a listagem para saber quantos produtos foram vendidos e a quantidade

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo faz a listagem para saber quantos produtos foram vendidos e a quantidade, Fiz uma dupla contagem para armazenar, mas quando eu chamo na outra função ele não printa e da erro

```
produtos = []
contagem = []

def menu():
    print('*****LANCHONETE*****\nDIGITE O NUMERO REFERENTE A SUA OPÇAO:\n'
          '1-ADICIONAR PRODUTOS AO ESTOQUE\n2-VER OS PRODUTOS DISPONIVEIS\n3-VENDER PRODUTOS\n'
          '4-VERIFICAR O TOTAL DE VENDAS POR DIA\n0-SAIR\n')


def adicionar(produtos):
    print('ADICIONAR PRODUTOS:\n')
    nome = input('Qual produto deseja adicionar? ')
    descricao = int(input('Qual a descriçao? '))
    valor = float(input('Qual sera o valor desse produto?'))
    produtos.append((nome, descricao, valor))
    chamar()


def verificar(produtos):
    for produto in produtos:
        nome, descricao, valor = produto
        print(f'Nome: {nome}, descrição: {descricao}, valor: {valor}')
    chamar()

def vender(produtos):
    descricao_desejada = int(input('Descricao do produto? '))
    for produto in produtos:
        nome, descricao, valor = produto
        if descricao_desejada == descricao:
            print(f'Nome: {nome}, descrição: {descricao}, valor: {valor}\nVENDIDO ')
            contagem.append((descricao_desejada, valor))
            chamar()
        else:
            print(f'Produto com descrição {descricao_desejada} não encontrado')
    chamar()

def vendas(contagem):
    for produto in contagem:
        descricao_desejada, valor = produto
        print(f'descrição: {descricao_desejada}, valor: {valor}')


def sair():
    print('Agradecemos a visita!')
    return


def chamar():
    chama = int(input('1-MENU 0-SAIR \n'))
    if chama == 1:
        main()
    else:
        sair()


def main():
    menu()
    opcao = int(input('Opção? '))
    if opcao == 1:
        adicionar(produtos)
    elif opcao == 2:
        verificar(produtos)
    elif opcao == 3:
        vender(produtos)
    elif opcao == 4:
        vendas(produtos)
    elif opcao == 0:
        sair()
    else:
        print('Opção inválida')


main()
```

Comment: Olá, qual o erro que da exatamente? E veja bem "descricao = int(input('Qual a descriçao? ')" Esse trecho de código da entender que o usuário deve entrar com um valor do tipo texto mas no código ele converte para 'int'. Não seria quantidade ao invez de descrição? E dentro da função vender também induz o usuárioa entrar com um texto e no código ele faz uma conversão para inteiro. descricao_desejada = int(input('Descricao do produto? '))

Comment: Ola Paulo Freitas, No uso append é restringida adicionar sequência de valores dentro de uma lista. O que foi adicionado na lista foi uma tuple. Você criou uma lista chamada produto mas ao usar o append foi utilizado uma tuple ao tentar percorrer o resultado é uma tuple dentro de uma lista.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está aqui na chamada da função `vendas`:

```
vendas(produtos)
```

Você está passando a lista `produtos` como parâmetro. Mas como `produtos` possui tuplas com 3 elementos, e na função você só tenta fazer o *unpacking* de 2 elementos (em `descricao_desejada, valor = produto`), ele dá erro de "too many values to unpack".

O que pode confundir é que você está usando os mesmos nomes dentro e fora da função. Quando você define esta função:

```
def vendas(contagem):
    for produto in contagem:
        etc...
```

A variável `contagem` é um parâmetro da função, e é local à ela (só existe dentro da função). Ela **não** é a mesma `contagem` que foi criada fora da função. Um exemplo mais simples pode esclarecer melhor:

```
def vendas(contagem):
    print(contagem)

contagem = 10
produtos = 5
vendas(produtos) # imprime 5
```

Ao fazer `contagem = 10`, criei uma variável que **não** é a mesma que está dentro de `vendas`. Dentro da função, `contagem` é qualquer valor que for passado quando eu chamá-la. Não importa se a variável usada na chamada da função tem outro nome, o que importa é o valor dela (tanto que eu poderia fazer `vendas(5)`, sem nenhuma variável envolvida, que daria na mesma).

Sendo assim, quando você chama `venda(produtos)`, está passando sua lista de produtos, cujos elementos são tuplas com 3 elementos. Ao tentar fazer o *unpacking* para apenas 2 elementos, dá o erro.

Então basta trocar para `vendas(contagem)` que funcionaria.

---

Mas aproveitando, tem outra coisa para mudar. Não precisa fazer uma função ficar chamando outras indefinidamente: `main` chama uma das outras (`vendas`, `adicionar`, etc), e cada uma elas chama `chamar`, que chama `main` de novo, etc). Apesar de "funcionar", isso faz com que todas essas chamadas fiquem "penduradas", já que elas nunca retornam (uma chama outra, que chama outra, que chama outra, etc, e essas chamadas nunca se encerram). E cada chamada de função [ocupa espaço na pilha de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/112052), e se você fizer desta maneira, uma hora a pilha estoura.

Se quer repetir algo várias vezes, use um *loop*:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa
    if condicao_de_saida:
        break # sai do while
```

`while True` repete indefinidamente o que está dentro dele. Se ocorrer uma condição de saída (por exemplo, se digitar zero), o `break` interrompe o *loop*.

Assim é melhor do que fazer uma função chamar outra, que chama outra, que chama outra, etc. Pois agora as funções se encerram e não ficam ocupando espaço na pilha.

Ficaria assim:

```
def menu():
    print('''
*****LANCHONETE*****
DIGITE O NUMERO REFERENTE A SUA OPÇAO:
1-ADICIONAR PRODUTOS AO ESTOQUE
2-VER OS PRODUTOS DISPONIVEIS
3-VENDER PRODUTOS
4-VERIFICAR O TOTAL DE VENDAS POR DIA
0-SAIR''')

def adicionar(produtos):
    print('ADICIONAR PRODUTOS:\n')
    nome = input('Qual produto deseja adicionar? ')
    descricao = int(input('Qual a descriçao? '))
    valor = float(input('Qual sera o valor desse produto?'))
    produtos.append((nome, descricao, valor))

def verificar(produtos):
    for produto in produtos:
        nome, descricao, valor = produto
        print(f'Nome: {nome}, descrição: {descricao}, valor: {valor}')

def vender(produtos, contagem):
    descricao_desejada = int(input('Descricao do produto? '))
    for nome, descricao, valor in produtos:
        if descricao_desejada == descricao:
            print(f'Nome: {nome}, descrição: {descricao}, valor: {valor}\nVENDIDO ')
            contagem.append((descricao_desejada, valor))
        else:
            print(f'Produto com descrição {descricao_desejada} não encontrado')

produtos = []
contagem = []
while True:
    menu()
    opcao = int(input('Opção? '))
    if opcao == 1:
        adicionar(produtos)
    elif opcao == 2:
        verificar(produtos)
    elif opcao == 3:
        vender(produtos, contagem)
    elif opcao == 4:
        vendas(contagem)
    elif opcao == 0:
        sair()
        break # sai do while
    else:
        print('Opção inválida')
```

Veja que eu posso fazer o *unpacking* direto: `for nome, descricao, valor in produtos`.

Repare também que a função `vender` agora recebe 2 parâmetros: `produtos` e `contagem`, já que ambos são necessários lá dentro.

Não arrumei outras coisas, como validar se foi digitado um número de fato, e tenho minhas dúvidas se a descrição deveria mesmo ser um número. Mas enfim, esses detalhes você pode arrumar depois.