# Quando eu sei que preciso usar recursividade?

Tags: c, funções, recursão

boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida em relação a recursividade.

Sendo essas duas funções abaixo, gostaria de saber qual das duas é mais eficiente e porque?

```
//Não recursiva

int potenciaNRec(int x, int n)
{
    int result=1;
    int i;
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        result*=x;
    }
    return result;
}

//Recursiva

int potenciaRec(int x, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return  (x*potenciaRec(x,n-1));
    }
}
```

Fiz a árvore de recursão da função recursiva e não consigo ver muitas diferenças entre essas duas funções, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O link sugerido acima dá uma ideia geral. No seu caso a versão recursiva é pior, porque são feitas N chamadas à função, enquanto que a versão iterativa só faz uma - se N for muito grande, a recursão pode inclusive estourar a pilha. Leitura complementar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/112052

Comment: Muito obrigado, esse link e a sua resposta ajudaram a esclarecer bastante.