# Função e método são a mesma coisa?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, terminologia, método

Quando falamos em métodos e funções, estamos falando a mesma coisa?

Por exemplo:

```
function blablabla blabla
```

Isso é um método?

Comment: [Quais são as definições de método, função e procedimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11848/91)

Comment: "funções: todo procedimento que retorna algo. Métodos: todo procedimento que não retorna nada." Poderia da exemplos disso?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Leia as respostas dadas, não a pergunta.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Não é a mesma coisa, mas quase. A funcionalidade de ambos é a mesma. É uma diferença entre terminologia de paradigma procedural e orientado a objeto.

A função é um algoritmo, um conjunto de instruções que faz algum processamento, mínimo que seja. Em geral funções produzem algum resultado (matematicamente deveria ser obrigado, mas em programação há condescendência). Funções podem receber argumentos.

O método é a mesma coisa com a especialização que ela está dentro de uma classe e costuma automaticamente trabalhar com o estado de um determinado objeto. No fundo esse objeto é passado como argumento para a função para que seus dados possam ser manipulados. O método é considerado um membro que tem um comportamento em cima do estado do objeto.

O mecanismo interno no código é idêntico. É praticamente um açúcar sintático para disponibilizar o `this` no contexto local.

[Métodos estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) no fundo são funções encapsuladas dentro de uma classe, ou seja é só uma organização de escopo de onde a função está.

Algumas linguagens podem usar uma terminologia específica, mas o conceito é igual para todas elas.

Leia mais sobre função: [Quem é quem no uso de funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163079/101).

Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

A resposta pode ser sim e não isso depende do contexto.

**No geral** método e função são termos usados para identificar um bloco de código nomeado que pode ser reutilizado em várias partes do programa.

De maneira mais especifica não são a mesma coisa. **Funções** são utilizadas em linguagens que utilizam o paradigma imperativo e outra caracteristica importante elas (na maioria da vezes) não guardam estados sua execução é atomica ou seja uma vez terminada todas a variáveis locais tem seus valores 'apagados' ou resetados.

**Métodos** esse termo é mais usado com o orientação a objetos. Um objeto/classe nada mais é que uma estrutura que combina dados (propriedades) com comportamentos (métodos) e diferente de uma função pode guardar estado.